# Should a question marked as duplicate be deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

I will start this question with the following valuable guideline at [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

> ### Should duplicates be deleted?
>
> In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of
> the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder,
> because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.
>
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written
> that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient
> privilege.
>
> See also the "Should I downvote?" subsection above.

Let's consider the question, [Merge two one dimensional String arrays to a single array with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101997/merge-two-one-dimensional-string-arrays-to-a-single-array-with-delimiter) as an example which has also been discussed at [Should a question without source code in it be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405053/should-a-question-without-source-code-in-it-be-closed)

With a close look, one can find that none of the questions which have been used to mark it as a duplicate is related to **an array** which is the problem asked in the question. All these questions (which have been used to mark it as a duplicate) **are related to `List` which is different from an array in many ways (and so do their respective solutions)**.

Nevertheless, the answers to these questions (which have been used to mark it as a duplicate) give an idea of how to solve this type of problem. And therefore, in my opinion, it is fine as long as these questions are used as signposts to guide future visitors to this question.

The problem I see is with deleting this question, which is what I started this meta-discussion with. The question was deleted 4 times before it has been finally locked for a week. It would be worth to quote a comment by [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte) on the previous meta-discussion:

> I think the deletion of the Question goes against the guideline in [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). It says "Closed questions that are of **no lasting value whatsoever** should be deleted." and "please check whether there are **any good answers**". Emphasis on the first was mine. The post had a good Answer and it wasn't devoid of value. The page even goes to explicitly say of duplicates "they can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers". Not that I agree it should even have been closed as a duplicate.

So, the question is: should this question ([Merge two one dimensional String arrays to a single array with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101997/merge-two-one-dimensional-string-arrays-to-a-single-array-with-delimiter)) be deleted?

Answer (score 6):

In your previous meta question you said:

> Certainly, the required solution will come out if we combine the questions/answers from all the links listed above. This way (combining multiple questions/answers to mark a question duplicate), most of the questions/answers on SO can be treated duplicate of some questions/answers. This doesn't seem like a good way of marking a question duplicate.

I have to disagree here because it's **indeed** a good way of marking questions as duplicate.  StackOverflow is not a repository for *ready-to-copy-past* codes. It's a high quality question/answer website. By high quality we mean canonical, detailed, well explained answers.

We expect people to use existing questions to understand their issues and find their answers (by doing some effort reading the duplicates).

Do we need a question for each delimiter? NO

Do we need a question for each data type? NO

Do we need a question for every user having the same issue? Certainly NOT

We need a good canonical question having answers detailing how to merge two data structure with any kind of delimiter.

Yes duplicate questions are useful as signposts but only if we have few of them. Having 1000 questions around the same topic won't help anyone. Having 10 or even 15 questions around the same topic is acceptable especially if the questions are using different keywords which will make searching for the topic easy.

So yes we delete questions if we judge that they are not useful. There is nothing wrong doing this even if we disagree with each other (that's why we can also undelete them).

### The question got deleted and you think it doesn't deserve it?

In such case, simply move your answer to the duplicate target. If your solution is *really* that good and provide a different way of tackling the problem then nothing is lost. You move it to the target and you contribute in making the canonical question even better.

Comment: But in this case there's a difference between how to handle an array and how to handle a list. Note that no one found a duplicate of how to handle this with arrays. There is no duplicate target to move the Answer to. Please also note that deleting a post removes it from most users. Only some will be able to see it and very few will keep a link. It's not searchable, even to 10K'ers.

Comment: *in this case there's a difference between how to handle an array and how to handle a lis* --> I am trying to keep my answer generic but if what you say is correct then why the question is closed a duplicate? why not voting to reopen it if we are dealing with different concept?

Comment: I do not agree with the duplicate closure. That it's closed as a duplicate isn't evidence that it *is* a duplicate. But 1. I can't vote to reopen. 2. People seem to just hate the post for being "no effort".

Comment: @Scratte we all hate "no effort" question and especially the duplicate ones. I cannot speak about the accuracy of the duplicate here (even if it's sounds correct to me based on my small Java knowledge and the fact that no one voted to reopen it). In all the case, "no effort" question that are *clear* duplicate are deletable for me (like I explained). "no effort" BUT not duplicate is a different story

Comment: @Scratte I've seen the *statement* that it's not a duplicate because it's about arrays multiple times now. Could you, or someone, actually *quantify* how profound the difference is so that it's not a duplicate? Because I don't understand it. In the one I'm using the `[]`-operator, in the other I call `get` and `set`. The algorithm is absolutely the same.

Comment: You're making some assumptions here. I personally do not hate "no effort" Questions. I prefer those. I search for them when I need to do something.. sometimes I even land on one of your Answers :O Also, people did vote to reopen it. It was re-opened twice and have one reopen vote on it presently. Check out the close reason "Lacks focus".

Comment: I still think it's ridiculous how the same people who make the argument that "Stack Overflow is not a help desk; we don't care about who the asker is" can simultaneously make the argument that we should, for some reason, care about the amount of *effort* exerted by the asker so as to justify their use of our free help desk. If it's a duplicate, it's a duplicate, but that's a completely different thing than a "no effort" question.

Comment: @Scratte But I think you would prefer to get to the duplicate target having good answers than the one with poor answers marked as duplicate (as I said "no effort" isn't an issue if duplicate is not involved) And I see no reopen vote after the duplicate closure (not afte  the "lack of focus")

Comment: @akuzminykh As a seasoned programmer, the difference is just that for accessing. Inserting doesn't use `set()` but `add()`. There's also the need to specify the length of arrays at initialization. Along with other things for the mere fact that they are two different types. As a new developer it can be a source of confusion. I see no reason to have all posts about this on Stack Overflow to only be about `List`. Likewise, we don't limit ourselves to only have one post about how to use libraries. Even if they're all just "1. Create class. 2. Call methods".

Comment: @CodyGray the effort I am talking about here is the one that should be made to dig into the duplicate target, read all the answers, understand them, try them, etc .. It's not about the amout of the effort that a user put in his question. I don't care about that when dealing with question. I answer "no effort" question even if the OP show nothing because I judge that the issue is not trivial and it's not easy to find a solution but I don't like the "no effort" question when we can easily find the answer by googling the title and where people jump to add the same answers again and again

Comment: ^ and we end having such questions as HOT network.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The reopen after the "Needs focus" and the re-open after the duplicate closure are highlighted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pabb6.png). I expect the reopen task was invalidated due to post deletion. My API call is telling me the reopen vote is [still on the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcIvX.png)

Comment: @CodyGray I don't see how judging questions by effort is "ridiculous" and somehow a contradiction of rejecting a help-desk approach. On the one hand, we still get tons of help-desk questions whether we feel this is good or not. On the other, perceived low-effort questions are low-effort *regardless who is asking them* – *any* asker, whether they actually wrote the question or just find it pre-existing, would only ask the question because of lack of basic effort.

Comment: ..and as a topping, it's 'Homework Sunday' tomorrow, when all the deadbeats who cannot use a website will ignore the FAQ and post their giga-dupes:(

Comment: @Scratte I think your "likewise-example" is very exaggerated. The `set` versus `add` is true; I've forgotten about the initial capacity problem. I'm still not sure if the difference is significant enough. Another thing: There is no other question specific to arrays, (probably) right. But how comes that? My assumption: Because it's so trivial and noone ever had a problem solving this task.

Comment: ..together with all those who can use a website, know that there is a FAQ, but post anyway, in an attempt to abuse SO contributors to slavishly disgorge an answer that the other deadbeats have not already copypasta into their assignments:(

Comment: @akuzminykh I'm not sure I understand. If no one asked it before, it should not be asked because that makes it too simple? I expect you know there's no such thing as a "Too simple" reason for closing a post. Also, who determines what is simple? The seasoned developers? Because then we can close most of Stack Overflow as lots of Questions here are really simple for at least some users.

Comment: @Scratte Let me try it differently: I think that *if* someone has a problem solving this task, then it's not because it's hard to understand arrays and how to use them. It's the algorithm itself. My "proof": The question was not asked before specific to arrays. Now isn't that a good argument for closing the question as a duplicate of similar questions that are specific to `List`? Because they address the algorithm or the approach itself.

Comment: @akuzminykh You could argue that. I'd be more inclined to say no. Users searching for this are likely to include "array" in their search. Why not give those a post to land one? Granted that with enough research one could find the information. But that could be found in a `C#` post too. Or found themselves, if they read more tutorials, or if they stopped using the internet and got lots of books (with real paper) and became an expert themselves. I always search a lot when reading tutorials. Every time I think of a "cornercase", I search like mad.. posts like this are just awesome to land on.

Answer (score 1):

There are several general questions to address in the original post and related conversations, the first being

> Should questions that are admittedly low-quality be deleted if they contain answers that *may* be high-quality?

And the answer to this one is, probably not, unless the question is truly egregiously low-quality, but the fly in the ointment is that judgment of quality is subjective, and what one deems high-quality, another may not, and likewise for the determination of low-quality.

---

Another question or concern that appears buried in the original question's comments would be:

> Should the site allow users to target posters when deciding which questions to down-vote, close, or delete

The answer to this one is simple: Certainly not

But a solution is more complex. With down-voting, the solution is easier -- to use algorithms already used by the site to check for voting patterns and then block serial voting of any kind, but with close-votes and delete-votes things get somewhat trickier but not intractable. Since most of these will involve the SOCVR, a room that saves all close-vote and delete-vote requests to a database. I believe that these requests are scrutinized for evidence of targetting already.

Answer (score -1):

I think the question as stated is irrelevant if SO has a consistent model on what 'close as dupe' means. However, SO does not have a consistent model of what 'close as dupe' means (or to be more precise: Many tag communities do not appear to apply the model properly!).

Thus, it boils down to: Well, either [A] we rewrite what 'close as dupe' actually means first, and then we can answer this question properly, or [B] we figure out why so many tag-communities don't apply the model properly and either start a plan to teach these communities to do it correctly (quite an ordeal, to be sure!), or figure out why the intended model isn't working for a tag community and add some tools to alleviate whatever was ailing them.

To explain in more detail:

There are only three options for any given asked question:

1. The question is 99% to 100% in effect equivalent to some earlier-asked question.
2. The question is different but only in effectively irrelevant detail: The *only* crux of the issue is the same as some other question, however, the way the question is stated makes it obvious that the one who asked the question does not understand this. An example: A *very* common (once a day, at least) occurrence on the Java-tag SO is a question that is long and rambling because the asker doesn't quite understand what's going wrong, with all sorts of details included. A glance at the code and what the asker describes makes clear that there is only *one* problem: They are using `==` to compare strings, which in Java does not compare values (it compares reference identity). These questions are **invariably** closed as a duplicate of some 20 year old SO question specifically about it. That question isn't a bad link: It has no irrelevant detail and the accepted answer explains the issue succinctly. Nevertheless, this is for the question asker, not the best experience: Unless someone puts in the effort to add a comment to explain *why* their question was closed-as-dupe of that seemingly completely unrelated one, they have to surmise that the fact their question was marked as a dupe of that other one means they need to read the other one, understand what it implies, and then apply this lesson to their situation, and lo! Their problem disappears as snow in the noon sun.
3. The question is merely quite similar to some earlier-asked question, but not entirely the same. For example, an array is involved.

Mark-as-duplicate is entirely appropriate for option #1, and **really not appropriate anywhere else** - because pragmatically speaking you can't give any context. It's just 'this was closed as duplicate of that', and that's all you get. There isn't even room for a comment as part of a close-as-dupe vote. You can, at best, add a comment to the question and hope that it is read. Thus, there is **no room** to explain how to apply the linked-to-answer to arrays (for case #3 above), or to explain that the only actual problem is using `==` to compare strings, as per case #2.

In other words, *mark as duplicate* does not seem appropriate (to me, at any rate) as some sort of extremist 'link to another batch of answers' setup. It doesn't even link to an answer - it links to a question.

That leaves #1. Now, this is rarely applied. For example, case #2, specifically about string compare? I can show you hundreds of Java questions asked on the Java-tag in the past year that were dealt with by closing as duplicate of 'how to compare strings in Java'. Many of those really could do with some more context.

However, if one goes with the seemingly only correct answer (in that SO's lack of ability to add answers to closed-as-dupe questions strongly suggests 'close as dupe' is appropriate only if the question is almost entirely similar, and in no other case) - then this point is moot: Then by definition the new question doesn't add anything useful, and thus SO should either add more policing options and to clarify that close-as-dupe is appropriate only if the question is 99%+ similar to an earlier one, and then if SO as a whole decides that such questions ought to be deleted, to delete them. Notably, any existing answers should be repatriated in the original - it's more of a 'merge questions' option at that point.

Of course, in practice, that would probably not work, at least, not without a serious change in the community approach: Currently close-as-dupe is used a ton in case #2, and is also used in case #3 - even though I tend not to do this, as I think close-as-dupe is appropriate solely in case #1.

I think the current SO model is not appropriate, **at all**, for most programming tags, and Java in particular:

- Languages evolve. A question can be 100% the same as some 15-year-old question, but that 15-year-old question has an accepted, 800-point answer that is **entirely inappropriate** now, 15 years after the fact. I have no idea how one could go about fixing such a situation. As a rule I strongly prefer to just answer the new question and not mark it as a dupe, because it seems blatantly misleading and incorrect if the suggested action (mark as dupe of the 15 year old one with the 800-point accepted answer that is now outdated and possibly even straight up wrong) leads to the asker being misinformed. Nevertheless, I'm being trained not to bother to do so, as most likely the question will be closed halfway through me trying to answer it in a way that is up to date with modern standards.
- There is no way to attempt to address an old answer: I would prefer it if a sufficient amount of community members can all chip in to mark an answer simply as 'obsoleted', which then opens the door to adding a new answer that can then go through the paces and get upvoted over time. As is, it just isn't feasible to attempt to add an answer with the update: Nobody ever sees it. They scroll down, see the 800+ gorilla, and stop scrolling. I can't even close-as-dupe by linking to an *answer*, I can only close-as-dupe by linking to a question.

There are plenty of questions with the Java tag that go unanswered, so rapid-closing the obvious ones is better than if they just straight up go unanswered. I don't want to create the impression that I think the Java-tag community is messing up by closing-as-dupe so many questions. I'm merely raising the point that the mental model of what 'close-as-dupe' means is nebulous to me. The way the community appears to use it does not mesh with what 'close as dupe' technically ends up doing.

Comment: There *is* a defined model for duplicates on Stack Overflow: the answer to this question can be found here, where "here" is a link to the proposed duplicate. As for the point that languages evolve over time, that's why *new answers* should be posted to questions, regardless of the age of the question. This is why we do not close questions to new answers simply because they've been answered.

Comment: I don't see how this answer relates to *deleting* duplicates at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: It also might well benefit from a "TLDR" section ;)

Comment: _This is why we do not close questions to new answers simply because they've been answered._ Are you seriously claiming that it is a feasible plan to replace an obsolete/now-incorrect, 800-point accepted answer simply by adding one and praying it'll get there, from 0? How do you beat 15 years of upvotes? Delete the 800-point accepted one straight up? edit it to add a note that this answer is now obsolete? I will do that if that's the plan. A bunch of commonly-linked-to-questions have really crap answers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it says so right at the top: _IF_ 'mark as duplicate' means 'this question, itself, matches that question' (note: _question_, not answers. The question itself!) - then this debate on 'should it be deleted' is moot: If it is the same, then the only reasonable answers are 'delete all the duplicates' or 'delete none of them', and there is no point to a 'when should a dupe be deleted' kind of debate. But whilst that feels like what 'closed as duplicate' is supposed to mean, that's _not_ how it is used, thus getting us into hot water. I propose solving the underlying issue instead.

Comment: @rzwitserloot You might want to put that there. Right now, it just says "the question [of deletion?] is irrelevant if SO has a consistent model on what 'close as dupe' means". It doesn't say that said consistent model must mean "this question, itself, matches that question". (FWIW, I now realised the 11th paragraph actually explicitly is about deletion.)