# Add the possibility to post an explanation when closing as dup

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I was thinking that it should be possible to add a short explanation when closing as a duplicate.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69581781/6699433) about strange result from `long long n = pow(10,18) + 1` in C. The core reason for the unexpected behavior is that floats behave differently than integers, which is covered very well in the canonical question [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/6699433)

However, there is one small piece of information that is needed to tie them together, and that is that `pow()` returns a floating number.

My current options are these.

- Close as dup and add a comment about it. It has two main drawbacks. 1) The information will be in the comment section, pretty far from the link to the dup and 2) Comments may disappear at any time
- Find or create a question that explains the return type of `pow()` and close as dup of both of them. This is a good approach sometimes, but in this case, I think it's overkill.
- Answer it with something like this *"The function `pow()` returns a double, which is a floating point number, and not an integer. The rest is explained here [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/6699433) "* and then close as a dup. But this does not feel right.

I would suggest the possibility to add a small comment explaining why the dup is a dup, so that the dup box would look like this, with my addition emphasized:

> This question already has answers here:
>
> Is floating point math broken? (31 answers) **- (The function pow returns a float)**

That way, the explanation is available right where it's needed. And a clarification from comments below. I mean that anyone who can edit the dup list also can edit this comment.

<sup>Note: This is NOT a dup of [Should we add more explanation when closing as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352439/6699433) which covers a different thing</sup>

Comment: Your third bullet point is precisely what you should do... It's not a *duplicate* if it needs the dots to be connected; just *related*. You still avoid the duplication of information by providing a link to the other Q&A.

Comment: @CodyGray Are you sure? From what I have heard it's completely ok to close as duplicate of two other questions if they together gives all the information needed.

Comment: [We've had that discussion before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403010/should-i-hammer-a-question-by-using-multiple-different-canonicals). I'm not super enthusiastic about it, admittedly. Although I admit there are some cases where it is completely sensible, I think in *most* cases you should be doing the dot-connecting explicitly.

Comment: To confirm, this FR makes this comment _optional_? I am a bit on onboard, it makes sense on some questions. But what happens if multiple people put comments, and all those comments are conflicting? Or worse, non-sensical?

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes, I mean that it should be optional. And I also think of it that it should be possible to edit that comment by anyone who already have the power to edit the dup list.

Comment: Can the edge case / related insight not be edited into one of the answers on the dupe target? Should the advice be built into a new answer on the dupe target? These options align with my stance that SO needs better eggs in fewer/better baskets.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sometimes they can, and sometimes not. In my example, it would just bloat the answer.

Comment: I don't see adding a valuable insight as bloat.

Comment: I've seen this happen too often where if the question seems at all distinctly similar to another, it gets closed as a duplicate to a question that might (or more often than not, might not) answer the question. And other times where only after a long discussion in the comments does the answer actually become apparent.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't consider things you easily can find in the documentation as valuable insight ;)

Comment: I like this. Since duplicates are practically never the *exact* same setup, pointing out that "this dot is the same as that dot" is often helpful. Attaching that to the closure seems to be where it belongs.