# Should 'number of lines from Xcode project' really be deleted? Should it be merged instead?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, vote-to-delete

There are six delete votes on [Number of lines from XCode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005871/number-of-lines-from-xcode-project), and I can't figure out why.

It's been rightly marked as a duplicate of [How to find out how many lines of code there are in an Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003534/how-to-find-out-how-many-lines-of-code-there-are-in-an-xcode-project), but that isn't a reason to delete it. [Duplicates are good, they serve as signposts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

From the [10k privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> Before voting to delete, please check that there are no good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, **be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates**; they can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another question.

This question is obviously serving as a signpost. It's been viewed >24,000 times, more than the question it's been marked as a duplicate of. It has helpful answers.

Should this really be deleted? Should the two questions be merged instead?

Comment: After merging it in the one direction, I realized I should have merged it the other direction instead. Especially since the accepted answer had code, whereas the other just has a link and a description of a tool to use (but not how to use it).

Comment: There are a group of 10K users that seem to be going around and deleting content that shouldn't be deleted. They cause more work when they do that; but they can't abide any duplication or upvoted old content that is now off topic.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, how are people supposed to tell what used to be on topic? What are they supposed to do with it, especially if it now belongs on another site?

Comment: @dfeuer "Off topic" is a general categorization of questions that aren't in scope for SO. They include non programming questions, opinion based questions, broad questions, and questions that may or may not belong somewhere else. In the case of this question, deletion was the wrong answer, the right answer would be to flag for merging. Unfortunately for us, they seemingly do not believe valuable content should be kept if it is from a duplicate question, even if the answers are better.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, note that I wrote "used to be on topic", in response to your "old content that is now off topic".

Comment: @dfeuer leave it alone. Or flag it for locking, if it's attracting the wrong kind of attention. Other sites don't take migrations of old/inactive content, so the choice is between deleting good content and leaving it alone. Votes, stars, views, and answers are all clues that you should leave it be.

Comment: @hobbs, that makes some sense. However, it seems pretty clear that there *should* be some way to get such things migrated to more appropriate homes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, duplicates should be merged instead of deleted.

The Merge path should be:

The question with the greatest views, votes, and 'better' answers (a wholly subjective criterion, but normally something with code is better than something without, and something with just a link and a description is worse than anything else) becomes the canonical question.

The other questions should be flagged for merging into that canonical question.

It's OK if some of the questions are not merged -- there may be times when that's the case; but on the whole we'll merge as flagged.

Questions *should not* be deleted if they are duplicates unless:

- the question has a low number of views
- A low number of votes
- Really poor answers that don't merit staying around

We want to keep valuable content, even if the questions are duplicates. So to sum up:

If you hate duplication:

- vote to close
- Flag for merging if the question warrants merging (or has good content)
- Vote to delete if the question meets the criteria I laid out above for deletion.

This is the standard moderators use; and that's the standard we accept/decline flags on.  Again, there may be a difference in 5% of the cases, but this criteria covers the vast majority of duplication.

If a duplicate can't be merged because there are fundamental differences in the question (though the answers are the same), then that's just some duplication that will stay around. If you really, really, really want that duplication gone, then do the following:

- Flag for merging
- Once the posts are merged; suggest edits (or edit) the answers to make them 'more general'
- Or, if the merged answers are then duplicates of other answers, flag them for deletion, explain that the answers were merged, and now these answers are superseded by `<specific answer link>`.
- Or, leave a comment to the OP letting them know that since their answers were merged, they may need to tweak the answer. Of course, if you went through the steps above, you don't need to do this; and if you're doing this step, why not edit?

Comment: If I flag for merging, will I be notified when the merge takes place, or if the merge is declined? That would be a good feedback loop.

Comment: @JohnSaunders We'll 'accept' the flag; you can always check back after the flag is accepted. It would only take a minute or two once we accept the flag for us to merge, so unless you see it immediately, it should appear done after you check out your flags.

Comment: FYI, I'm not going to remember to check. The acceptance of a flag, or at least this flag, should appear in the notifications. It would provide a nice feeling of accomplishment, similar to the feeling of seeing a question be deleted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders There are a number of improvements that could be made to the flagging process; we do want feedback loops and we do want people to take more than one pass at something; so that would probably be a good feature request.

Comment: Like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284688/please-notify-me-when-my-flags-are-accepted-or-rejected)?

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad that [Mr. Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) merged the question, but I can explain why I personally added *my* delete vote.

Yes, duplicates can be a signpost, but to my mind that's true, *only if the titles are sufficiently different*. In that case, they represent another path to find the linked duplicate.

I felt that "Number of lines from XCode project" was sufficiently close to "How to find out how many lines of code there are in an Xcode project?" that it would not be a different way to find the same content. I felt they would both show up in the same search results, confusing the issue.

Now, the questions have been merged, and there should no longer be any confusion.

---

Sorry, I just re-read the [blog post by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), and I'm about as confused now as I was then. I Now remember that I felt then that I did not have clear guidelines about when to delete duplicate content. In lieu of such clear guidelines, I adopted my current standard - don't keep extra duplicates unless they use significantly different search terms.

That's a standard I'm smart enough to follow. If you want me to follow a different standard, then it has to be better than Jeff's standard of "not too much, not too little".

So, get going on making it clear to dumb people like me. I look forward to the result.

Comment: What good does it serve to delete a question like this? If it is closed as a duplicate, pointing to the original, and has shown to be of value over the years, why delete it? Titles aren't the only thing Google searches take into account. I don't see how this helps the site.

Comment: @BradLarson Especially in this case; since the top rated answers differed greatly; the answer to the question they tried to delete had 91 upvotes and actual information, the answer they wanted to keep was simply a link to a tool and a summary (but not how to use it).

Comment: The titles aren't that relevant, the content is. I'd think if you're confused about something, you shouldn't act on it - nothing is forcing you to.

Comment: I was confused about the guidance, so interpreted it to my own liking. I recommend clearing up the guidance sufficiently for those of us who are confused.

Comment: @JohnSaunders You may not like Jeff's standard (and I didn't, when he first posted it -- he and I even had a telephone conversation right before he posted that blog post about that (and other topics)), but that's the standard we've used. It seems pretty clear to me: Duplicates can and should stay around, especially if they have different answers.  They may be closed, but not deleted.  Once you get to the dozens number, then start to help us clean them up by flagging for *merging* (and let the moderator sort it out -- that's what we're there for).

Comment: I didn't say I don't like it. I said I don't understand it. I don't know what I'm meant to do. I don't want some different policy; I want  this policy _explained_ better.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've put my understanding of the policy into an answer. Now all I need is a flowchart...

Comment: IMO, what you say in the first part of your answer [at least coincides with what another moderator said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262863/close-as-dupe-when-there-is-no-effort-shown/262868#comment54933_262868)

Comment: @Braiam In context, Bill is saying the same thing I did in my answer; the missing part is `<when there's no valuable information to keep around>`. Note the 'unhelpful' part.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm not saying that he's right or wrong, just that his motives were not totally off the mark.