# Notify me when my flag has been handled

Tags: feature-request, flags, notifications

I have always been "interrupt-driven" - I'm very bad at polling to see if something has completed. I'd rather fire and forget, and to be notified later.

But that doesn't work with flags. As they are right now, flags are "fire and forget until you happen to remember to check for flag declines".

Please notify me when a flag is accepted or declined.

This especially goes for flags to merge, but any flag that is meant to cause an action should also cause a notification when the action is taken or declined.

---

Here's an example. On August 30, 2014, I flagged [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo/25577496#25577496):

> I'm not really comfortable with "adapting" an answer from a book, even though the book is referenced. That, plus it's a 5 year-old question. – John Saunders Aug 30 '14 at 2:10

The response was:

> declined - I'm not sure this is actionable - it might fall within fair use in some/most jurisdictions short of a DMCA notice or similar I'm not keen on deleting. Maybe this should be **discussed on meta**?

(emphasis is mine)

How was I to know about the suggestion to discuss on Meta? I was meant to click on my profile and remember that the number of helpful flags is a link to the flag history page, and then I was meant to scroll through that page looking for disputed or declined flags, and in fact I was meant to scroll down to at least four months ago?

Better - how about somebody told me about the flag, so I could have looked at it on August 30, 2014?

I'd be fine if there were a *"notify me"* checkbox in the flag dialog.<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284688/notify-me-when-my-flag-has-been-handled?cb=1#comment148590_284740)</sup>

Comment: I support the idea behind this; my concern is that it would turn into another avenue for meta grievances(WHY MODERATOR DECLINE FLAG!??!).  We have enough of those without notifications going on.

Comment: Why do you want a notification for when your flag was handled? What purpose would this serve?

Comment: There have been requests for notifying on flag declines before but I just can't find the one I commented on for some reason. I did find these: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228267/show-declined-flags-in-inbox) [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239738/send-custom-flag-responses-to-messages-inbox) Notifying on flag approvals on the other hand, I don't think so. We want you to focus on the stuff that matters - if we take any positive action on stuff that you flag, then let it be our business.

Comment: A lot of people would also want to checkbox in their prefs to turn this off if implemented. Maybe even break that down by flag type? I know [some people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/1288) aren't going to want a notification on every comment flag.

Comment: Aren't you afraid of a lot of noise in your inbox if you are a frequent flagger. if you are *interrupt-driven* isn't the only interrupt needed the declined ones? Because those might indicate that you are screwing up or need a different approach to get fixed what is broken...

Comment: I definitely want to know when a merge I requested has either taken place or been rejected. In fact, I think I want to know about rejections in general - I want to be able to immediately see the reason for rejection, and either learn from it, or else complain about it. I didn't raise the flags for the purpose of having nothing happen.

Comment: @bluet you're missing the fact that I'm _asking_ for this. Certainly have an opt-in feature for this, but personally, I will opt in.

Comment: @bluet: actually, based on my 35 years experience in software development, and based on my 56 years experience with John Saunders, I am requesting that I at least be reminded that there's a reason to go check the flag history page, which is welcome to evolve sorting and/or filtering features. Possibly one could have a single notification aggregate all flag notifications since "the last time" and possibly the notification text could be a summary, such that I'd see there are no flags I care about and could decide not to click it.

Comment: Possibly, if I _did_ click the notification, it could display a summary of the flag changes, followed by the details of those changes in a "recent flag history" window, sort of like the Favorites tab on the user profile, which even has a number at the top telling you how many favorite changes there have been since "the last time".

Comment: And if I keep this up, I'll be designing the feature instead of simply requesting it, and I always hate it when analysts do that to me, so I won't do it to [so].

Comment: For some arguments against this, see [my previous feature request on this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230877/201907).

Comment: @APerson: None of these are arguments against what _I_ want to do.

Comment: @Carrie: I don't know if the changed title reflects my request. If the flag is handled at the same time it's accepted, declined or disputed, then it's the same thing. But if "handled" can come after accepted, declined or disputed, then I want to be notified for accepted, declined or disputed.

Comment: Feel free to rollback if I changed your intent. Personally, I think that _"handled"_  can represent "when your flag has been resolved" and is better than specifying a few of the resolved types (ie accepted and rejected)

Comment: FWIW, I use "handled" to refer to any resolution - helpful, declined, disputed, aged, etc. Internally, these are referred to as flag results, but that's awkward.

Comment: As long as it's understood that, for instance, I don't want to wait for the actual merge to take place - I just want to wait until my "flag to merge" is determined to be "helpful".

Comment: Maybe more useful would be a decline reason for mods that explicitly includes notifying the user. (So something along the lines of, "Custom (Notify user)".) It seems that in this case, the mod may have wanted to communicate something to you. Such a feature would make that convenient for a mod. If you just want to see what you might be doing wrong, periodically skimming should be sufficient, even if you only do it every few weeks.

Comment: I think we could break this into an opt-in feature with 3 options (i) no notifications by default (ii) notifications for only declined/disputed flags - for the accepted ones, I know what I was doing and the moderator(s) have only vetted my call (iii) notifications for all kind of flags handling.

Comment: I vote we keep it simple. How about keep it exactly like it is now, but let me say, "... and tell me when it's done".

Comment: Agree there isn't any real reason to be notified when a flag is *accepted*. There is *definitely* a reason to be notified when a flag is *rejected*, though.

Comment: @neminem: it amazes and disturbs me how many commenters have answered something like, "there no need for (parts of) your request". That would presume that I didn't actually think through the request before making it. But I actually _did_ think it through, and I actually _do_ have a real reason to be notified when some of my flags are accepted. It's possible that there are no real reasons for _you_ to be notified when any of _your_ flags ae accepted, but that's a different story.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's fair. I suppose the statement should have been less absolute - that there are *more* use cases for notifying on decline than on acceptance, without presuming that there are none. Though to be fair, your post itself only described a use case for the former, as well. :p But fair enough, the extra work in handling both cases would only be in adding an option, and you'd probably want the option to turn it on (defaulting to off) anyway, so might as *well* throw all three in if you were going to do it at all.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [WHY MODERATOR DECLINE FLAG?!](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2973216#2973216)

Comment: @bjb568: please say why that chat is significan

Comment: oh, it was a just a complaint about a declined flag

Comment: Isn't there something like this already. I recently got a notification reading something like: "You got flags declined, go and check them before flagging new". The intention was probably different but surely one can build on this system and enhance it somewhat.

Comment: @Trilarion if I'm not mistaken, that feature appears when you go to flag something and you have a few recently declined flags. I assume this is so that users will think a little longer about the flag before raising what *could be* another unnecessary flag.

Comment: @McAdam331 you are right but it also means that you can easily build something similar adapted to this proposal. That's what I wanted to say.

Comment: This is a bit narrower than your request here in that it _exclusively_ deals with flags that a moderator has _commented_ on, as opposed to _all_ flags, but there's [a related feature request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172262/add-a-notification-on-moderator-comments-on-flags). There's also [another feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226361/can-we-make-new-flag-responses-more-visible) that's a bit more comparable to what you're proposing here. Of course, all of this is seven+ years old, so I'm not anticipating any traction.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I agree with John Saunders' suggestion that, whenever you flag a post, there's an opt-in checkbox to be notified later. This way, users who want to be notified consistently will be, but for most of us, it will be easy to continue to ignore responses to flags, preventing active users from being flooded with noise.

Comment: Even better if it has whatever state it was the last time a flag was submitted.

Comment: Why would we need an option per user *and* flag? To me, it would make more sense just having a single option per user, on the preferences page. Pretty much [what mu 無 commented](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284688/notify-me-when-my-flag-has-been-handled?cb=1#comment148632_284688).

Answer (score 68):

This would be incredibly noisy for some users, and *generate* an incredible amount of noise for moderators.

That said, there's value to be had in notifying folks of *custom responses* to flags, either as a matter of course or as a moderator-controlled option on the dismissal UI.

Until/unless such a thing is implemented though, I strongly recommend not relying on flag responses for this. If you have a significant interest in what happens to a post you've flagged, either plan to deal with it independently of flagging or set a reminder to check back up on it later.

Comment: Bottom line: I need to be reminded to set a reminder, or else I need the reminder to be set all the time. I'd be fine if there were a "notify me" checkbox in the flag dialog.

Comment: So, [meta-tag:status-deferred]?

Comment: No status at present. Let's see how many folks want this.

Comment: @Shog9 "Let's see how many folks want this." How will you determine that?

Comment: Voting on the question here, @matt

Comment: @Shog9 Really? So you can tell the difference between "this is a good question" and "I agree with the feature request and would like to see it implemented"?

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not yanking anyone's chain. But both as someone who has made feature requests here that went nowhere, and as someone who strongly agrees with this feature request, I'm disturbed by the fact that there is no explicit way, on proposals like this one, to vote for or against _the feature_. Perhaps 1000 people read and liked my feature request, perhaps not, but how will we ever know? They have no way to _say_ so.

Comment: Sure there is, @matt - if you like a feature request, then upvote it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @JohnSaunders Surely you could set up a recurring notification in some calendar software? Or maybe even just in your OS.

Comment: @Shog9 Why not have an option for it?...

Comment: @jpmc26: the converse of separation of concerns is "concentration of concerns" (I just made that up). How about we keep everything to do with flags in the flags dialog? How about we place the "notify me" checkbox in the flags dialog?