# Why isn't there a good penalty system to discourage reputation mining?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation, rules

After reviewing the *goals* and *direction* of Stack Overflow [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal), why is it that SO allows people to mine or reap reputation from questions such as this?

I've heard from moderators that there is a backlog of flags they deal with, so this introduces some inconsistency in which these types of questions are dealt with.  I mean, the people of high rep who persistently answer bad questions for reputation and treat SO as if it's a message board should have their reputation taken and they *should* have to start again.

Some examples:

- [Laravel use DB; Where need to placed? In Models or in Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938163/laravel-use-db-where-need-to-placed-in-models-or-in-controllers)
- [PHP Check if specific query is in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954968/php-check-if-specific-query-is-in-url)
- *To be continued...*

In one instance Stack Overflow is a Q&A for programmers to get quality answers for problems.  On the another hand, standards are generally a good principle to know, learn or learn where to find them.  This is somewhat inconsistent because a lot of these are discussion based and violate the rules not to mention perfectly meet the "Primarily opinion based" flag.

My question is why can't these people be penalized so they learn they need to understand the rules and ensure they follow them correctly and not try to reap reputation?

**Edit** *TheLostMind* made a very valid point in the comments regarding good content contributed:

> so you are suggesting that we should ignore their "overall" contribution on SO?

I think that some kind of infraction system or sanctions could be proposed, where accounts that receive too many infractions over a short period of time (3 days) have that reputation seized, while their content is rewarded. This means that if the posts are reported/flagged, they don't get the rep (but also allowing for a more automated approach in the future).

---

The reason for this question is because occasionally I find myself in a bit of a situation where by I need help from other programmers; my first thoughts are "let's Google this problem" and nine times out of ten Stack Overflow hits the first page, usually with multiple posts that all match my question.  When I open them each of them are specific problems to a certain environment which really does not help.  So I go back to Google and reword things.

But now I find there are more useless articles on Stack Overflow as a direct result of answering questions that should not even be answered as opposed to just simply closing them.  I mean, as time goes on, will Stack Overflow become a knowledge base with occasional edits or a collection of differing versions of articles to solve specific problems?  At the minute it feels like a message board; we sort of look up to high-rep members to uphold the rules a bit more.

Comment: related: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)

Comment: "Anyway it's more opinion based." (sigh)

Comment: The good news is is that if the question really does not belong here then we can close and delete it.  Any rep gained as long it is less the 60 days old will be lost when the answer is delete along with the question.

Comment: I agree that answering low quality questions (and dupes) is not a good thing but honestly the "solution" you propose is unacceptable. *have their reputation taken and they should have to start again* - so you are suggesting that we should ignore their "overall" contribution on SO?

Comment: `I guess, my question is why can't these people be penalised so they learn they need to understand the rules and ensure they follow them correctly and not try to reap reputation.`  Because those users *vastly* outnumber the people that care about quality content.

Comment: @NathanOliver If that actually happened a significant percentage of the time it would help a bit, but 1) Even if 75% of a user's help-vampire food is deleted, they're still better off answering those questions than not, as far as their rep is concerned and 2) Approximately 0% of these questions *actually* get deleted when there is any answer.

Comment: @TheLostMind I understand that, I guess i'm a bit heavy handed with my suggestion, but deleting a post losing small rep - they're like repeat offenders? Is not there something that could be done in this case when numerous reports are made and approved by moderators which can calculate *X user has provided more bad content than good* Or perhaps an infraction system which means they can't be rewarded reputation for a short period of time until the question has not been reported for X days?

Comment: Things like these should come from within. It's very difficult to "enforce" such things on SO because they are technically correct but ethically wrong. Also note that many a times its quite "tempting" to answer a simple question instead of "searching for the right dupe" :)

Comment: @TheLostMind hm, see I appreciate the efforts of all people on SO, i find I am personally helped by the community which is why I try to help where I can.  But I find that i'm bouncing from StackOverflow quite often because of these Q&A's being irrelevant and low quality.  They help nobody else, but the OP.

Comment: [Here is another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935520/laravel-mail-service-with-mailgun?noredirect=1#comment61430382_36935520) I've flagged, but Laravel appears to be tagged with a lot of junk from *newbies* so we should be welcoming and friendly, sure.  But it's more of that "programming support" thing

Comment: @ash I had a hard time reading your post, so I changed the wording. I think you have some good points, and I think they come across more clearly now.

Comment: Also related: [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)

Comment: Also related: [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes) That one's a feature request so if you agree with it, up vote it.

Comment: @Laurel your edits are better, thanks :)  I've also upvoted that related question i think it would be good to get quality over quantity.

Comment: Here's an idea, Let's add a button to the left of the post.  It can look like an arrow pointing down, and if you feel like a question or answer isn't very useful, you can click that button, and it will deduct a little bit of reputation from the poster.

Comment: But for serious, I feel like people need to take answer quality a bit more seriously.  If you don't down-vote unhelpful answers, even if they happen to be technically correct, then people treat SO like some sort of trivia game.

Comment: @SamIam Looks like your sarcasm is about as bad as your ability to read, voting down may deduct reputation - it does not prevent people posting bad questions and answers which fill googles results costing lots of time from people who are trying to find a solution to a specific problem.  Also StackOverflow is designed to be quality Q&A over another forum-based support service.

Comment: @ash yes it does.  The reason people keep posting bad answers is because people don't down-vote bad answers enough.  Instead they get rewarded for it with upvotes.  If you want to discourage bad answers, then do your part and participate in community moderation by ruthlessly down-voting them.  And if you want to appeal to the community, ask them to downvote ruthlessly too.  Negatively scored posts feel bad, even if you gained net rep on them.  People will be more afraid to post bad answers if they keep getting negative scores.

Comment: @SamIam one of the reasons why people don't downvote is symptahy votes. Downvote + sympathy upvpote gives positive reputation - so in current state it may be better to ignore such posts...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, then encourage people not to up-vote out of sympathy.  The fundamental problem behind this lies in our current culture.  If you want people to enforce quality, then the culture itself has to value actual usefulness over other things such as technical correctness and effort.  The most fundamental thing you can do to bring about that cultural change is to exemplify it yourself, and the next most fundamental thing is to encourage others to do likewise.

Comment: @SamIam But it's not strictly a matter of culture.  Part of the problem is 1 person who values crap has their votes end up being worth 5 people who value quality.  Next, there's the fact that it takes much less rep to earn the ability to upvote than to downvote, and the fact that downvoting punishes the voter for voicing their opinion.  And that's not even getting into the issues of human nature in which it makes people feel good to compliment others, so lots of people upvote content they know full well isn't good because it makes *them* feel good to cast said upvotes.

Comment: There is actually not any data to support the claim that *The reason people keep posting bad answers is because people don't down-vote bad answers enough*. Sorry. This has been discussed to death and I am not sure why people seem to overlook the fact that aside from it sounding nice to say it is incorrect. Even high reputation users ask junk questions. Asking questions isn't easy. Many very high reputation users have terrible question asking records. Bad questions lead to bad answers. Voting will not change that.

Comment: @TravisJ - Then we should try as a community to understand the actual question, find a solution to it within Stack Exchange before answering it (which is what the OP should do before posting from the list of related questions) and then we can forget about reputation and concentrate on quality articles.  I mean reputation may give you some additional privileges but it is not necessary in order to receive or return help

Comment: [Here is another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954968/php-check-if-specific-query-is-in-url) Which I answered but a < 10 second google search - 14k reputation user comes along and starts mining for rep ...

Comment: Ash I would be careful before you characterize the motivation  of Answerer's activity

Comment: @Drew I'm not certain I understand what you mean?

Comment: Though you commented somewhat nicely/benignly in the reference question, here on meta you are suggesting to me at least that that Answerer is solely mining for rep and not leaving a helpful quality answer. Which he even took the time to link to a manual page.

Comment: @Drew Right, I get your point, In a lot of cases and likely for that answerer they are not mining - but they do post answers to questions that are either VLQ or are against StackOverflows rules (i.e. no attempt to find a solution themselves - which i did in 1 quick google search).  I'll leave it there for people to decide; i guess my point is i would like to see some enforcement of quality of quantity and people should care less about rep and more about a community of decent Q&A

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is in place. You can (and should) delete lazy duplicates that do not improve the wealth of keywords to help people to find the canonical question easily. [This is even said in the blog:](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

> 2. Having dozens and dozens of variations of the same question is clearly bad.

If you find a question that has more than 10 duplicates... it probably needs conscious duplicate pruning. (Which has the nice side effect that it removes the rep that was gained from the duplicated.)

> We can still delete the ones we find to be unhelpful. If a question uses exactly the same keywords as another, i.e., it should have turned up the original question in a search, we can just delete it. -- [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262863/close-as-dupe-when-there-is-no-effort-shown/262868#comment54933_262868)

Comment: FYI it only removes the rep if it is less then 60 days old or less them 3 upvotes and older than 60 days.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266886/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver I know, but if we are doing this right, we should be deleting dupes before the 60 days are up.

Comment: Not to poison your answer which I upvoted. But what are your thoughts on the Title (penalty) system concept. So as to avoid being accused of not answering the question.

Comment: @Drew that we already have the tools to make this happen. If you answer a bad duplicated question, you will lose any rep gain associated with it.