# Can I cancel the accepted answer in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

What if I accepted an answer and I want to change after that?

Can I cancel the accepted answer to choose another one?

Comment: simple click again on the green tick

Comment: @iEmad green "checkmark"

Comment: Will the system give credits to the person who answer the question after I choose the answer? If yes. How about I cancel it in the future? Does the system take the credits from the user?

Comment: @Prix http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Check_mark from wiki 
  "A check mark, checkmark or tick"

Comment: @HangXu if you change the accepted answer the user that had it previously will lose the credits won with it and the new user will get the credits for it, however if you have enough points you can still up vote the other question if you seem fit.

Comment: RTM: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (Although the help topic only indirectly suggests that the accepted answer can be changed)

Comment: @Prix: "check"/"check mark" is an Americanism - "tick" is probably the more widely recognised term internationally.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something clearly covered in the Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @TylerH that may be a reason to vote but not to close. This question is very much on-topic here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You don't think people should read the Help Center before asking a question? What happened to the unspoken rule of "search harder than you've ever searched, then search some more, before you ask a question" mentality of SO?

Comment: @TylerH sure but that is still not a reason to *close* a question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure it is. The question doesn't belong here because following the rules will answer the question before it can be asked.

Comment: @TylerH: there are no such *rules*, and there is no such close reason. Also see [Provide "Not enough effort" as a new close reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253889)

Comment: @MartijnPieters If reading the Help Center is not yet a rule, it should be.

Comment: You didn't even ask a question on any stackexchange site.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can absolutely cancel an accepted answer. Click the green checkmark to take away the "acceptance." Then you can mark any other answer as accepted. The person who's answer was un-accepted will lose the 15 reputation previously awarded, and you will lose the 2 reputation you got for accepting the answer.

Comment: You don't even need to take away the green tick before accepting a different answer. Marking any other will automatically unaccept the current one.