# Can/should we flag easily searchable questions?

Tags: discussion

For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398071/sql-server-how-to-sum) question.

I've seen questions like this quite a lot; questions about the most basic functionality about sql (or any other language for that matter). I would say if you don't understand the most fundamental basics of a language, study it first before asking a question here (or using it professionally).

If the question has a duplicate, or has other issues, we can flag it, but that's not always the case.

Furthermore, questions like this can easily be solved with a quick google. Obviously the OP didn't even bother to invest 5 minutes of his/her own time, but expects us to.

It's becoming a bit frustrating people don't take the time to think and research for themselves.

It's a bit much to have a flag saying "you're stupid and you should do your research", but I think it would be nice to have some kind of flag for this.

Comment: If it is a duplicate, flag it as a duplicate.  If it isn't a duplicate, well that's been discussed a lot, but short version is lack of research is not a close reason, but can be a reason for downvoting.

Comment: You may be interested in this feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253889/provide-not-enough-effort-as-a-new-close-reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can/should we flag easily searchable questions?

No.

Downvote and  flag as duplicate if you feel like it.

I occasionally leave a (polite) comment in the vein of

> This can be easily googled e.g. by searching for `insert keywords here`. If you have a *specific* question about this, please edit to add more detail.

I always make sure the Google query actually yields a useful result in the top 3 results before downvoting .

> It's becoming a bit frustrating people don't take the time to think
>   and research for themselves.

It's not a new phenomenon, and there is nothing we can do to eradicate it.

It is wise to learn not to become frustrated by it, but simply do what needs to be done, and walk away. (Or ignore it altogether.)