# How to incentivize members being fast to close but unwilling to reopen?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I recently posted a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002022/sql-parse-column-string-for-integer-data-and-store-in-separate-columns) which was quickly voted to be put on hold within 10 minutes or so. I thought it was a decent question, but okay fine I fixed it up and made it better. Then I requested for it to be re-opened. Although a couple of users voted to reopen it, 24 hours later it has not garnered enough votes for reopening.

It appears that people are less willing to reopen posts put on hold. Perhaps posts put on hold for reopening are less visible or attracts less attention? Or perhaps this points to something about human nature being negative and trigger happy? In any case, how can we incentivize the community to reopening legitimate posts in as timely a manner as they are willing to close bad posts?

**Edit:** and if you agree that my post should be reopened, please help me vote for it. If not, please kindly share with me why not. Thanks!

Comment: The purpose of the reopen feature is to give users a chance to revise and improve their posts, no? If it's so difficult to reopen, would that not discourage people from improving their posts?

Comment: I doubt that anyone can write the best question/answer on the first try without subsequently revising it. In fact, after posting my question, I was quick to revise it on my own, not knowing that it was also quickly being voted to close. It closed so fast that I couldn't revise it in time.

Comment: Many people's first draft is not clear, so they read and revise and read and revise a number of times, only then do they publish their text. The same should be done on websites like this. Never publish the early drafts of a question, an answer or a comment. Read them careful several times revising them until they are clear. Posting a poor question gives others  chance to close it. Delaying posting until the question has been revised to be as clear as you can make it reduces the likelihood that it will be closed.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest I wouldn't have voted to re-open this question and I don't see that there's any difference between the original question and the "better" one. Your language has become slightly less subjective and you've added some additional, unnecessary, explanation. I probably wouldn't have voted to close it in the first place either.

It's all very meh.

It's also probably a duplicate of [Oracle SQL Find A String & Work Backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116730/oracle-sql-find-a-string-work-backwards), which I answered last week save that that questioner was under the mistaken impression they needed a positive look-behind and you're not really sure what you want. The answers are almost identical anyways.

**See also: [Should "Give me a regex that does X" questions be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed)**

Minor point for potential closers of Oracle regex questions in support of the above question; though Oracle supports both Perl and BRE style regexes it doesn't support negative/positive look-aheads/behinds , non-capturing groups etc. This can make what would seem simple in other regex flavours rather more complex.

<sub>Source: I'm on the all time top answerers for Oracle.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful input. I understand what you mean and will consider it going forward.