# What should I flag questions asking for regex patterns as?

Tags: discussion, flags

I was rolling through the triage review, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677625/regexp-in-express-get-request) question:

All this is doing is asking for someone to give him a regex pattern. I could understand if, say he has tried several patterns, tested them and they did not work so he came here for help, but his question shows a lack of effort on his part. I figured this would be unsalvageable, but was not sure what to flag it as. Should I have gone with "Asking for an off site resource" or something else?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Comment: All of these get a "Too broad" from me. If the question is a bland "send me ur regexx" then the OP gets a downvote as well.