# Are text editor regex questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148519/why-in-notepad-alpha-also-matches-chinese-words/34150819), which asked about the behavior of a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex) in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), was recently closed as off topic as a question about "general computing hardware and software".

This doesn't seem right to me: regexes are a programming language*, so shouldn't a question about regexes in any domain be on topic (assuming it otherwise meets the site requirements)? I could not imagine the same question being closed if it were about the exact same issue in, say, a C# regex.

**Has the community made a judgement about this?** I have seen plenty of other editor regex questions in the past that were not closed, but looking around I see others that have been closed or migrated to [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

*As for the debate in the comments about whether they are a programming language: I think they are, but even if not everyone agrees, they are definitely a "tool commonly used by programmers".

Comment: One problem is that so many regex questions are utter garbage or have been duped millions of times.  Nobody wants them now even if they do happen to be undupped, reasonable questions.

Comment: It is never very hard to find 5 SO users that dislike regex questions, Martin is their spokesman.  Or 5 SO users that only ever answer regex questions.  You avoid the first set and find the second set by *only* tagging your question with [regex].

Comment: Regular expressions are not a programming language.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Technically that's true -- it's a language that programmers use to do programming, but it's not a *programming language* programming language.

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's text script that is interpreted, just like, say, PHP.  Nobody doubts that PHP is a program.....  oh, never mind.

Comment: @MartinJames PHP *is* Turing complete, though, unlike regexes. That's a valid distinction among languages, though it's a little bit of a tangent in a discussion about things being on topic at SO. You might say it's... off topic.

Comment: Topic: Are discussions of whether discussions of discussions are off topic are on topic off topic, or on topic?

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I suggest you ask that on Meta Meta Stackoverflow.

Comment: Aside from the community's feelings about regex, a lot of folks seem to think questions about software tools are off topic despite the Help Center explicitly saying they're OK, as ken2k pointed out below. I've seen questions about Visual Studio and Xcode get closed as being "general computing hardware and software" too.

Comment: If by "programming language" is meant "is Turing complete" then regex is not a programming language.  But then, neither is SQL which happens to be a very popular topic area on StackOverflow [Note: Extended SQL implementations such as TSQL or SQL supporting recursive CTE's are Turing complete, but pure SQL without these features are not].  So, in the more general sense of the phrase, by which is meant "used in the practice of programming computers", everyone should hopefully be able accede that both regular expressions and SQL are in that sense, programming languages.  My $0.02.

Comment: Perl's regex are Turing complete.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Perl's regex are also not normal regex but improved and significantly enhanced.

Comment: @Magisch: Has anyone actually used a regex dialect that was *not* of similar power to PCRE in the last, say, decade? There's this whole *thing* about regexes being regular languages "by definition" that gets really annoying when that definition stopped being relevant to just about anything commonly called regexes a long time ago.

Comment: @BSMP remember that the thing is `(x|y|z)^a` where a is: a practical, answerable problem that is *unique* to software development. Which means that you can't ask about "changing the fonts size on Emacs", but "Attaching python debugger to a new window using emacslisp" is.

Comment: @HansPassant  Let's be honest - a *lot* of regex questions are just mechanical turk requests.  They're not specific, focused questions about a conceptual or subtle aspect of regex - they're from people who don't know regex, don't want to know regex, but have decided they *need* one to do *foo* and could someone please make them one -- as though regexes are magical spells that are dispensed by wizardly regex oracles who inexplicably hold the impenetrable secrets to their construction.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285739/327083

Comment: @NathanTuggy Actually, almost all regex dialects are, in fact, regular languages that have the computational power of DFAs.  I state this without proof for now, but if you need one, shoot me an email or something. Perl's regex are a totally different beast.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: .NET's regexen are [explicitly not DFAs for the precise reason that DFAs do not have enough expressiveness to support back-references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And what do you know, PHP, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Java, and doubtless others **also** support back-references. See, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: This is one of the more useful questions in the sea of garbage that is [tag:regex] tag.

Comment: Anyway, Notepad++ regex == boost regex. You can often turn a question about a regex in an editor to a question about a regex flavor of a particular library the editor happens to use.

Comment: @Braiam - I know, but it never seems to matter. People think **any** question about the use of a program is off topic, even when it's specific to programming.

Comment: @nhahtdh and others, come on, the regex tag isn't so bad!  Sure there are lots of "do my work" requests, but that is hardly unique to this tag.  And there are plenty of good, interesting questions (for those who find regexes interesting, of course...).

Comment: @BSMP blame the terrible questions about using a program in a non-programing specific context...

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'll stop posting in this chat after this one.  Turns out you are right (although I take a small amount of issue with the .NET docs' choice of wording.)  I once did a little *proof* of how I could represent anything in python's regex with a DFA/NFA and just discovered I was entirely wrong.  Thank you for correcting me.  Who knows how long I would've perpetuated my lies. :)

Comment: @dan1111: It's bad because the questions are either 1) duplicated gazillion of times before 2) with ambiguous spec, leading to answers with subtle caveats, which make them terrible as reference answer 3) too localized problem, where no specific technique is demonstrated 4) using wrong tool for the job (XY problem).

Answer (score 56):

From the [official help page about what questions are allowed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them, 
>   but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Notepad++ is definitely **a software tool commonly used by programmers**, plus it's specifically about regexes. While I dislike regexes, it's definitely **an answerable problem that is unique to software development**.

I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: By that logic questions about bug trackers should also be also on topic.

Comment: @ArtB Sure, there even is a [JIRA tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira) with a nice (sponsored) icon...

Comment: Wow, that that is appropriate is beyond me. JIRA is about business and management and not programming. On Programmers, sure, but SO? I'd rather see CS questions. *shrug*

Comment: for cs, there is cs.stackexchange.com :P JIRA is a tool commonly used by programmers, so sounds clearly on-topic to me.

Comment: Use quote formatting, not code formatting, for quoted content.

Comment: All: remember that the condition is ***unique* to software development**, changing JIRA's or whatever icon on the desktop is definitively off topic. Same about X software installation, etc.

Comment: @ken2k Hi, ken2k. When you say "I dislike regexes". Do you mean you don't like regex question on SO or you just don't like to use regex? If you don't like regex, is there any better tool than regex to deal with text?

Comment: @user15964 I meant I don't like to use regular expressions. At all. Most of the time they introduce more problems than they solve. Most of the time you end up with unmaintainable code and awful expressions. I prefer simple, readable, maintainable code: 90% of cases I could use regexp, I can solve the problem with some basic parse/split calls, or use a parsing lib (when input text is HTML, XML...). That said, I've really nothing against regexps on SO.

Comment: @ken2k I understand. Most of time, I use regex not for code cleaning but for daily text manipulate or data format correction, I found it handy in these area.

Answer (score 8):

I think this question was wrongly closed. While I do not have the power to cast a reopen vote, I edited the question a little bit to remove spelling errors and make the problem statement more concise. Here's hoping it will be reopened.

Comment: The question is currently (2015-12-08 18:29 UTC) reopened.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thats nice to know, thanks