# Should this question have been reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[React.js app - warning - 0.chunk.js:45744 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676488/react-js-app-warning-0-chunk-js45744-warning-received-true-for-a-non-boo)

The question was originally closed because it was a dump of a stack trace with no code.

It was then edited by the asker to include a link to a GitHub repo, one arbitrary file from said repo, and the comment "I think the problem is contained in it..."

That edit bumped it into the Review queue, where the question was voted to remain closed. Then 3 users (one of who reviewed this question in the queue and voted to reopen it) apparently came across it and voted to reopen it.

To me, this question is a "gimme teh codez" question - except instead of requesting us to write code for the asker, it's requesting that we do their debugging for them. In my eyes, such questions should be closed (and remain closed) whenever they're encountered, because they are zero effort; they are extremely specific, therefore unlikely to offer value to any future users; do not have all details encapsulated in the question; and/or show lack of basic understanding.

Therefore, were the people who voted to reopen this question right or wrong?

(FWIW, the same asker then re-posted the exact same question: [react - warning appears caliming "Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `inline`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694052/react-warning-appears-caliming-received-true-for-a-non-boolean-attribute-i))

Comment: It was reopened outside of the queue. The [re-open review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/27550217) was invalidated. See the timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64676488/timeline

Comment: The question lacks a question to start with; how can we be expected to answer a question if there isn't one.

Comment: Since questions need to be self-contained a link to some repository is never necessary and if relevant code can only be found there, the question needs debugging details (or maybe details or clarity).

Comment: @rene I *thought* that is what I was reading, but then I asked myself "what are the odds that 3 random people stumbled across this terrible question and voted to reopen it?", and the answer to that was "not high". So I assumed I was just reading the history incorrectly. I see now that one of the reviewers came back after the fact and voted to reopen the question, which strikes me as problematic.

Comment: @JeanneDark - you are correct and I've edited that in. Thanks!

Comment: The supplied code seems relevant, `inline` there is used as a boolean attribute. It's not clear to me what purpose it serves or why it was added there, so it _might_ be closed as a typo or unclear, but I'll leave that judgement for someone with domain knowledge. That it is a ["gimme teh codez"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253137/what-close-reason-should-i-use-for-give-me-teh-codez) or [zero effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions) question should be irrelevant.

Comment: it has two close votes already because it is missing detail and clarification

Comment: I agree with Ivar, IMO the question looks fine now. I'd have voted to close it as typo though, as I don't believe that it will help future readers; or at least as a duplicate, as there are lots of very similar questions, too. Also, as noted above, the OP posted a self-duplicate, which already got an answer - so _if_ we choose to keep one of them, then rather the newer one.

Comment: The first link leads to "removed for reasons of moderation" for those of us with less than 10k reputation. Did it get removed because it was re-posted, does anyone know?

Comment: @WilliamMiller it was deleted by three 20K users.

Comment: I'd say that bugs obtained at GitHub should reported at GitHub.