# Enhance moderation ability by encouraging excellent content

Tags: discussion

I have a proposal, I've been upholding it for quite a while now, and I'd like to share my efforts with the rest of the high (30k+) reputation users. I found a way to both encourage great content and potentially enhance the number of users contributing to the moderation effort we have.

### Some of the problem

Many people complain that there are very little to no good questions to answer these days. That answering any question would seem like repwhoring and so they get stuck at 2-3k (at best), and are able to edit, sometimes close but not delete or protect or see deleted posts.

### My solution

Bounties. Yes, it sounds simple, but hear me out.

For a while now, I've been offering large (500) bounties for people who write excellent canonical answers on subjects where low quality knowledge is at a huge majority. We identify a question that is suitable, together we fix the question and the title, they write an answer and I place and award the bounty on the question.

Some examples:

- [PDO Login Script Always Re-Directing To Header Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178943/pdo-login-script-always-returning-false/23185728#23185728)
- [How do some web services recognize I'm logging in from a new location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011337/how-do-some-web-services-recognize-im-logging-in-from-a-new-location/17017377#17017377)
- [DateTime using incorrect timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612772/datetime-using-incorrect-timezone/19613798#19613798)
- [How to properly set up a PDO connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection)
- [How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc)

These questions and answers promote great content that is used by reference, which is generally locked behind rapid closing and lack of motivation.

It also had a nice bonus of giving the right people more reputation, thus helping in the collaborative effort to keep the site clean.

---

## Call for arms

I urge all high reputation users to do the same. **Reputation is just a number for you, there's no difference between 20501, to 100k to Jon Skeet**, there are users out there who just need the motivation.

We cannot always fight the tide of low quality content, so the best we can do is to encourage some high quality content of our own!

## This is not a feature request!

There are a hundred different things I can suggest by changing the system. But that's not entirely feasible all of the time, so let's make the best of the current situation!

If you have a feature request concerning bounties and/or encouraging great content, please ask a new question, tag it [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and provide a link to this question as reference. Answering this answer with feature requests will make them less visible and less likely to be implemented.

Comment: I like how "Jon Skeet" is now used as a quantity of reputation `:)` "OMG, that guy is ***totally*** almost at 0.5 Jon Skeet reps!"

Comment: @Cupcake: Yeah, there are more stages between 100k and Jon Skeet, like "googol" and "googolplex" but I decided to leave those out.

Comment: This would encourage great answers (which is a more than worthy goal!), but would it address the common complaints about question quality? And it seems to me the percentage increase in the number of high-rep moderators would be small even from a very large bounty effort (nor do I think the number of users with moderation privileges is necessarily problematically low)

Comment: @DavidRobinson: It's something. Better than doing nothing. And like you said, it's encouraging excellent answers. Not to mention that I alone managed to push 2 or 3 people to the 10k and 20k zone. What would happen if all of those with more than 30k rep managed to do that?

Comment: How about a simple tax ? Say %5 of each user's Rep. User initiated bounties are tax deductible. Users above a certain Rep threshold forms the 'government' which allocates these bounties.

Comment: But, but, I'm so close to 100k.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Well then, I may award you some bounties if you make some good answers :)

Comment: The one thing I don't like with the bounty system is its expiration date. Why should I have to be coerced into rewarding an answer I do not find satisfactory ? I must admit that offering the bounty after identifying a satisfying answer is much more attractive.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That's why I don't actually put up the bounty until the answer is written. It's a matter of trust.

Comment: Encouraging writing good, canonical answers is not going to change anything if questions are never being closed as duplicates.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I have another feature request on that over on [meta.se]

Comment: What about creating a new "review queue", awarding supplement rep to good explained and canonical answers? A queue, in which, I don't know, prize would be 100 rep, where only people with 30k, can approve/reject? And, people with 5k can suggest the question to this queue? That's just a suggestion with "random" numbers I gave, that could be debated.

Comment: It's really nice to see people with high reputation being so generous. I like this high bounties movement. However it's difficult to find the high bounties. They do not turn up on top of the [featured questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) list or this list is not sortable by bounty height. Is there a way to sort it by bounty?

Comment: That is great thing to know about you so when you will stand for moderator my vote will be for you. and sorry for my English I am the other "Hamza" from php chat room.

Comment: @Cupcake a more convenient unit is the "milliskeet".

Comment: Damn, that is one of my posts. lol

Comment: _Encouraging excellent content_ sounds great, but don't you think you send the completely wrong signals to the users when you award answers which is not technical correct and as such doesn't solve the question? Is such an answer _excellent content_?

Comment: @Ian I can be reached in chat pretty easily most of the day.

Comment: Can you confirm the flow for this? I'm confused about the 'chicken or the egg' part of it. Do you await somebody to improve title, question and add a high quality answer *then* add a bounty? Or do you add a bounty with the expectation that somebody takes the three steps to earn it?

Comment: @HarryB When I wrote this I wasn't a moderator, so couldn't refund bounties. To that effect, I didn't want to risk placing an non refundable bounty on a question, and then have the answerer abandon their efforts and I'm left without anything to award the bounty to. If the answer is already in place, and all it takes is a few small modifications, I'll offer the bounty up, if there's no answer at all or the answer needs extensive work, I wouldn't.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Inspired by this post, I created a chrome extension to replace all reputations on StackOverflow website into Jon Skeet unit, for fun :D https://github.com/novalagung/skeetoverflow

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow but I learned a lot of things from here. And  I really enjoy answering and getting answered by other users... It also helps me out in project... I am working on...
@the question I asked is it good?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255966/angularjs-object-sorting

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I am new and I have literally no rep at all and I have a answer with a score of 2+ and I have 111 rep right now

Comment: And there is a difference between 20501 to 100,000: there is still one more privilege between, but there is pretty much no difference between 100,000  and 1,118,930,

Comment: how can you be reached most of the day?!? [according to this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254137/enhance-moderation-ability-by-encouraging-excellent-content#comment316362_254137)

Comment: @Song That comment is still true. Most days, I'm in chat.

Comment: Can you schedule a meeting (bounty)?

Comment: @Song Just ping me in chat whenever you're free, I'll try to answer.

Comment: I created a new room, if you care to talk in it, and for your most recent comment on this post, I do not know when I go to chat.

Comment: I'm stuck in the hundreds, and I will quit doing anything on this site if I don't get to 1000 rep in a year.

Comment: I hope people can reconsider this, it's true honestly, but sadly it's just forgotten.

Answer (score 124):

You've got this problem backwards.  The issue is not that users [like BalusC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252799/17034) are discouraged from posting answers because answerable questions are not there, the issue is that they can't be found anymore.  They are simply buried under a huge pile of help-desk questions that take excessive time to moderate and leave no valuable artifact that's worth anything to anybody other than the questioner.  The "please google this for me" and "please debug my code" questions.  Crowd-sourcing simple programming tasks, the volume has grown dramatically in the past 9 months since the close-reason reform.

So if you want to hand out bounties, do so on questions you think should be answered.  The rest is automatic, BalusC promised he'll look at it.

Comment: I feel honoured you've personally answered some of my questions :) And I agree with you on the help-desk questions it becomes much harder and harder to find good questions...that's why my rep has just stopped growing as Im tired of answering "how to use for loop" and alike questions

Comment: @Hans Passant, to me is difficult to know which are help desk questions, I think that is relative to the answerer and OP expertise. I problem I do see in some questions is that the OP is absolutely new in the topic, and when someone too expert tries to solve the question, the answerer does not know where to start. There are actually more problems than this one, but in questions about question/answer quality not all these problems have been enumerated, instead treated like generalizations.

Comment: this kind of sums up the last 5 years of SO in a nutshell

Answer (score 35):

Being a mere ~0.001058 Jon Skeet myself, I have recently opened a bounty at the minimal +50 that I could afford not to lose any capabilities on SO. I have received feedback and while it is not exactly the answer I was looking for, it did provide insight. Bounties are obviously a beautiful instrument to attract attention. Bad voices would whisper that it attracts the repwhores, others (usually the ones going for it) would argue that bounties are typically associated with meritable questions and one is assured an audience.

But really, all you 30K+ rep users with your laudable intentions, how did you get to that high station that you are in (from my perspective at least)? Apparently you are the knowledgeable lot so why don't you do this high-quality work yourself? The way I see it, the bounty is there for bounty-seekers, low-lifes like myself interested in upward mobility, but it is in essence no more than a way to buy attention. Put 10K on a bounty and you will receive a lot of answers, but will they contain the high quality answer you are looking for, or will the repwhores take this as a lottery?

A better way to approach this might be co-optation: Recently established users that show excellence (e.g. through a substantial number of answers to questions, each of the answers with a substantial number of upvotes) are invited to draft a wiki lemma or some other contribution on some issue that high rep users identify and donate rep to, upon acceptance of said work by the contributors of rep. Make that a public thing, with the author posting intermediate results (e.g. issues, approach, sample code) open for public scrutiny and comment. Could be a nice high profile section of SO to demonstrate what SO is all about: high quality Q&A for computer engineers.

Comment: Note that this is not a [meta-tag:feature-request]. It's a discussion. For a reason. What I am suggesting can be implemented today, should the community agree upon it. What you're suggesting will take 6-8 weeks at best. Second of all, not all of us high reputation users have the motivation to take the time and invest in such high quality posts. So the idea is to trigger motivation in those who do. If a high reputation user is willing to accept a 500 bounty and do it, I will be the first to offer it. But I am not seeking to change the system for this. If a [se] employee wants to push it...

Comment: All I am saying is that your discussion may not lead to the effect you are looking for. Perhaps my feature-request is a better way to achieve what you are after, which, I think, is quite worthwhile. The ratio of flotsam to good questions is very high and finding a way to pick out the good and highlight it would merit 6-8 weeks IMHO.

Comment: @Patrick Here's a hint: **you** can be a highrep user if you want to. It's simple, repfarm: instead of closing, downvoting bad questions you go and answer them. So being a highrep user doesn't really imply to have more knowledge than a low rep user. On that note, maybe I should stop [giving bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza?tab=bounties&sort=offered) until I reach 10K :P

Comment: I think one of the reasons the OP wants to do this is to give users more reputation without forcing them to rep-farm (and lower the site's quality by giving answers to questions that don't deserve one), and that will give more users access to moderation privileges to better deal with the constant flow of low-quality questions.

Answer (score 22):

The problem with posting canonical answers to non-canonical questions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178943/pdo-login-script-always-returning-false/23185728#23185728) is that they don't make good reference posts.

- **They're not good duplicate candidates.**

  SE staff has time and time again said we shouldn't close one post as a duplicate of another if it's not the same question, even if the answer to the 'duplicate' answers this question. Canonical questions are presumed a bit different.

  If someone sees this, they may just say "but this isn't the same issue" and not really bother to read the answer - this could be the question asker, or a potential duplicate voter.
- **They're unlikely to show up in search results.**

  A good reference question/answer contains many of the search terms one can reasonably search for when having this issue.

  I don't have enough domain knowledge to know whether "PDO Login Script always returning false" is the only issue that answer is meant to solve - assuming it isn't, will anyone ever come across this question while searching for their specific issue? Probably not.
- **There are often other issues in the question.**

  Ideally the code in a reference question should be 100% perfect apart from this specific issue.

  An answer avoiding these issues isn't ideal, as that doesn't help the asker as much.

  It's worse yet if the answer deals with all these issues.

  Again, I don't have a lot of domain knowledge, but the above chosen post seems like a bad canonical post as it appears to cover **a wide variety of issues** rather than **a single issue in immense detail** (which also makes this a particularly bad duplicate candidate). A wide variety of issues should be covered in a wide variety of Q&A's. This isn't a site for tutorials.
- **The questions are often much longer than required.**

  Ideally we want the shortest code possible to demonstrate the issue (or for each issue), while there's often a lot more code in non-canonical questions.

And editing the question into a canonical question wouldn't be smiled upon (although I'm personally not against that).

So, screw canonical answers to non-canonical questions.

If you feel like writing a canonical answer, post a canonical question for it.

Comment: You know, [you can always *edit* questions to make them more broadly applicable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Most of the [SE FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq) questions originally looked much different from how they do today.

Comment: @Shog9 I tried that once and the OP reverted. Oh well... :(

Comment: @Shog9 That advice is somewhat different for what **everyone**'s been preaching since I've started here, and even [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: Yeah, folks are cowards when it comes to editing. BE BOLD!

Comment: I full heartedly agree with Shog. What's the absolute worse case that's gonna happen? OP complain on meta that someone edited his post? **Boohoo**, somewhere in the middle is OP rollbacking, and best case is he does nothing/accepts the change realizing it will only bring him more upvotes. Bottom line: **Edit the question if it doesn't apply to all cases**.

Comment: @Shog9: With the whole "don't change the original meaning" thing going on it's not exactly a surprise people don't make big content edits.

Comment: @SecondRikudo `"What's the absolute worse case that's gonna happen?"` An edit war with OP? A moderator intervening but agreeing with OP? A post that's now locked to stop the edit war, but can really do with more information? In any way, one's own canonical question seems like a better option.

Comment: @Dukeling: An edit war will not happen if you let it go. If the OP doesn't want his question to become canonical, make a new one and answer it better. Or take another question and make that canonical. No need to battle it over with the OP. A moderator can even merge questions if the answers are worth it.

Comment: There's always the option of actually writing up the canonical question and self-answering. [I did that for one pervasive Spring issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1189885), and we've managed to close a good list of questions stemming from these circumstances as duplicates--not always downvoting or deleting, since sometimes they're reasonably written, but directing to a thorough discussion of the issue.

Comment: @Shog9 as somebody who takes some measure of pride in [bold](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18759577/revisions) [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/956867/revisions) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3524388/revisions) [various](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1395954/revisions) [kinds](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18427966/revisions), I'm quite cheered to hear a mod advocating it. :) I've always worried that some day my actions would be the topic of an angry Meta post by somebody.

Comment: Nice work, @Mark

Comment: @MarkAmery IMO, you should've posted new answers in all those cases, not simply editing an existing one. The blog post (similarly to Shog's comment) says "It is OK to edit a **question** to make it more general". (Vaguely curious to get confirmation from the community on that, but not enough so to post a question about it)

Comment: @Dukeling I strongly suspect that the community would agree with you... but I don't. Adding a new answer when there's already one that doesn't totally suck is often leaves you with the no-win choice of either repeating information in the existing answer (decreasing signal to noise ratio as future visitors are forced to reread the same content multiple times) or writing your answer as a kind of extension to the present one (which is *also* frowned upon and likely to provoke "should've been a comment or edit" comments). Editing is frequently the only way I see to sidestep this.

Comment: @Dukeling However, I do appreciate that people own their posts to a significant degree, and when making a radical change I usually leave a deferential comment inviting the post owner to rollback or tweak my edit if they don't think it's helpful. In this way my edits are kind of like suggestions that only the post owner gets to accept or reject. Nobody has rolled back an edit of mine yet, and I'm often thanked for edits like the ones I linked to, so for now I feel alright about making them.