# Encouraging bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounty

This post was sparked by [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254137/2846923) question, which encouraged high-rep users to award more bounties. The problem is that many users are quite attached to their reputation, and don't want to give it away.

This idea was [mostly made by Dukeling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254617/semiobligatory-bounties?noredirect=1#comment19908_254617):

A certain percentage of all the reputation users earn will be added to a "bounty pool". (The reputation will not be subtracted from the user, it just appears out of nowhere). When a user places a bounty, the reputation comes from the bounty pool, not their own reputation.

Possible tweaks:

1. Do away with the bounty pool entirely, and have the rep appear out of the æther.
2. Bounties placed on your own question will not come from the bounty pool, but rather your reputation (so *self*-promotion is not free).
3. Only users above a certain reputation can place bounties using the bounty pool.
4. Make badges for 25 and 100 bounties placed/awarded on someone else's question.
5. Limit users to one bounty from the bounty pool every 7 days/10 days/6–8 weeks.

---

Old idea:

`<stupideridea>`Therefore, users that have more than 20,000 reputation (the last point at which rep does anything significant other than impress people) should be *very* highly encouraged to award bounties. A certain amount (e.g. 3%, but not any faster than bounties can get placed) of the reputation 20k+ users earn will go to a "bounty queue" where it doesn't do anything—not even increase the user's visible reputation. When a user awards a bounty, the reputation comes from their bounty queue. To encourage the spreading of the bounty queue, a certain amount of reputation will be transferred from the bounty queue to the normal reputation count (e.g. 10% of the bounty amount).
`</stupideridea>`

<sup><sub>Sort of a stupid idea, but I'm throwing it out here in case it *is* actually good, or it inspires a similar—but better—idea.</sub></sup>

Comment: Are you a communist? (Joking)
`Sort of a stupid idea, but I'm throwing it out here in case it is actually good, or it inspires a similar—but better—idea.` So which is it, this ***is*** a good idea, a stupid idea or a you hope it inspires a solution? I think the point of bounties is *I* need to see a question that truly inspires me to donate rep, even if I have plenty. Rep is an imaginary currency, it doesn't need to come from anyone's pockets if we are to make more odd rules to spread it around carelessly.

Comment: @AustinFrench I don't know what type of idea it is, that's why I posted it! It's interesting to note that when I posted this idea as an answer on the link question, it got +5/-4, but this has +0/-4.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I don't think it is an outright stupid idea... But I see more issues with it when I try to work through the process than I see real positives. Somewhere there is an interesting concept, just too many new questions and problems seem to be created.

Comment: Rather than stealing our (or anyone's) reputation, just send some % of **everyone**'s reputation to a bounty pool, which is **free** (not subtracted from their rep), e.g. every 30 reputation gives you 1 bounty point, or something like that.

Comment: @Dukeling - ding ding ding. I like this. On a site like SO where I have limited rep, I would love to get a little side rep to help the site without further delaying my own goals of reaching at least 2-3k for the extra powers...

Comment: @AustinFrench: Maybe displaying the percentage of bounties offered in a prominent place is sufficient encouragement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly some of these suggestions are pretty terrible, but I think there's a nugget of something useful here.

> Make badges for 25 and 100 bounties placed/awarded on someone else's
>   question.

We already have the bronze [Investor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor):

> First bounty you offer on another person's question.

I think it might be worth while to add silver and gold versions at higher thresholds. While 25 and 100 may be too high, something more like 5 and 15 may encourage users to continue investing in other peoples questions.

Comment: We definitely need those silver and gold badges for  `Investor` and `Benefactor`. That's a low hanging fruit/ We need names too, what about `selfless` and `karmic force` for silver and golden `Investor` (bounties to others' questions) and  `Humanist`, and `Philantropist`  for silver and golden `Benefactor` (bounties to own questions) . I'd stick with 25 and 100, it'd be still a reasonably easy gold badge to get for high rep members so they'll want it and award bounties to well chosen questions/answers.

Answer (score 7):

Given the values from SO's top users it seems realistic to take 1% of rep for bounties.

```
                     rep      offered
22656/jon-skeet      679,661    100
29407/darin-dimitrov 519,984      0
157882/balusc        484,352      0
23354/marc-gravell   471,405  2,350
17034/hans-passant   459,461      0
6309/vonc            397,771    100
34397/slaks          383,288    100
115145/commonsware   380,701  4,200
893/greg-hewgill     348,899  1,400
```

Comment: wow! what a list.

Answer (score -1):

I have a simpler suggestion:

**give a free bounty coupon with every yearling badge**

- They can't be cumulated, so use it or waste it.
- I believe once a year is fair, though giving it only with the first yearling badge would be a possibility too.
- Possible to limit it to users above a threshold in rep or who have a bronze badge for one of the question's tags, if we're afraid to get too many low quality questions.
- This will walk users through the process a first time, they will notice that with a good question you easily get half or all of your rep spending back, so they'll use it again.
- A reminder 2 weeks before the new yearling badge arrives will incite user to use it, or give it away to a nice underrated answer (user might be linked to page of upvoted answers by date).

And a bonus idea: bounty promotions (bounties for 25 reps) during periods when activity on website is low. I'm assuming (maybe wrongly) that activity follows approximately the same trend between tags.