# "Question Badge" suggestion: Philanthropist

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

So I've decided to start a personal SO version of "The Giving Pledge", i.e. 90% of my rep is going back to the contributors , 2-3K rep is enough for me.

Now obviously I'll contribute to the subset of questions that I could personally appreciate that belong to my skill set tags. So I'm going to give something like 14K rep points using the bounty system (not too many compared to many of you, but I was only active in a relatively small volume tag).

I saw that there are several bounty related badges (Altruist,  Benefactor,  Investor) all of them bronze. I'm curious for the reason why there isn't an extended level for the "Investor" badge (*"First bounty you offered on another person's question"*).

How about a *Philanthropist* badge (or whatever you want to call it)? 
It can be defined as:

- Offered N bounties on another person's questions (N>10,50,100?)

or

- Given N rep points in bounties on another person's questions (N>10K,50K,100K?)

Your thoughts and feedback are appreciated.

Comment: By extended you mean silver badge?

Comment: whatever, I just edited some examples. It's the idea that I'm interested discussing, not the color of the badge.

Comment: `the reason why there isn't an extended level for the "Investor" badge` What positive behavior do you think it will encourage? For one, I don't want people to throw in random bounty to a meh answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh I think the intent of this badge is to encourage bounties for good questions asked by low rep users who can't afford a bounty like me (hint, hint).

Comment: @jakekimds, You could afford 13 bounties, and still have some rep left..

Comment: Philanthropists generally don't request recognition for their philanthropy.

Comment: so that's why I keep hearing in NPR that programs thank the "Bill and Melinda Gates foundation, that believe that each person is entitled to have a healthy and productive life"? (or something like that)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254137/enhance-moderation-ability-by-encouraging-excellent-content

Comment: Exactly ! thanks for finding this

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: that would be the behavior of a true _altruist_. Examples of philanthropists include Andrew Carnegie, known from Carnegie Mellon Universities. Bill Gates is a pseudo-altruist who still makes big noise about his charity, rendering his attempt as unethical (per altruist theory by August Comté).

Comment: If you go 500 by 500 you'll run out of rep pretty soon! :p

Comment: you're right, but these are imaginary points anyway...  Also I didn't say I quickly I'd distribute all of them.

Comment: I can't see you as part of any Communities on your Meta profile. Just saying.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit A lot of the behaviors encouraged by badges would be altruistic if people didn't expect a reward. I suppose we could call the silver philanthropy badge something different, but by that logic, the "Altruism" badge should also be renamed.

Answer (score 80):

We have badges that lead folks to discover the various ways they can use the bounty system, and I think they're sufficient. I don't want to provide *too* much incentive for bounties because I want people to be able to hang onto privileges that they earned and hopefully *use* them.

At the core of the design, rep is a measurement of how much the system trusts you, which means it controls what the system will allow you to do. You mentioned that you plan to hang on to just enough to keep the privileges you want, and that's great - but I don't know if others would have the same presence of mind.

It could also lead folks to use the system less discriminately than they currently do, as there'd be incentive to go *looking* for stuff to bounty rather than doing so as you happen upon things opportunistically.

It's not a bad idea in concept, but I'd want to reward *more* than just offering a bunch of bounties. "Giving back" to the site has always been about *time and contributions*, not about the incidental rep you gain doing it.

I'd like something more along the lines of 'prospector' where:

- You find a question that needs more attention
- You *edit* it so it will fare better once it gets additional attention
- You place and award a bounty
- The receiving answer also gets a score of +10 or more.

... turns out there was some gold in those hills.

Yeah, that's a heck of a lot harder, but it encourages the kind of thing we want people using bounties to accomplish. They're a tool, a *means* to an end, not an end in themselves.

Comment: Completely concur. We don't need a permanent Winter Bash situation.

Comment: I like your idea too Tim, but I feel like this part of your answer misses the mark. `I want people to be able to hang onto privileges that they earned and hopefully use them.` I think that's the whole point. Encouraging higher rep users to part with some rep that won't cost them privileges. Lower rep users can't part with it without losing those privileges.

Comment: @RubberDuck I didn't forget to consider that, the idea of making badges available only to those that pass a certain rep threshold is .. odd. I'm not ruling it out, but we kind of depend on that premise being discussed first. I would _not_ want to put more bounty badges in-scope for sub-15k users.

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: @TimPost: We already have badges that require lower rep thresholds, e.g. [Custodian] and friends.  15k is admittedly... large, but this is a difference of degree.

Comment: @Kevin: Technically, it's possible to get **a** Custodian badge, or even all the way up to **a** Steward, just by being quick on the draw when someone suggests edits to your posts. The badge itself has no requirements; it's an implied but fairly obvious prerequisite enforced by the usual nature of the site. Here, though, it's something that is not enforced by the site at all, and can't be, except by doing weird shenaniganry with the badge. (To whom is the badge visible? What if you drop below 15k for a bit while bountying but then go back up? Do early bounties count?)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Fine, but what about [Sheriff]?  In the recent election, we had a minimum rep requirement for nominees.  And if you don't like StackOverflow-specific things, try [Taxonomist], which can't be had without 1.5k to create tags.

Comment: @Kevin: Taxonomist is a better example, yes, although the second part of my comment still applies. In particular, it's not a semi-arbitrary restriction that's part of the badge in order to accidentally avoid encouraging unwise/unproductive behavior: it's just how things work anyway.

Answer (score 53):

I think you're looking at this all the wrong way, I'm afraid. You're seeing rep as "money", something to gift people as a kindness. But it's not "money". It's an indicator of trust (as Tim says) so what you're doing here is openly planning to artificially make the system trust you less and artificially make it trust some other people more. *It's like kindly donating your driving licence to somebody.*

**If you just wanted to go ahead and cast some bounties on questions that you came across and found genuinely worthy of bounties, you'd go ahead and do that**; no, you're looking for a reward in turn for actively *seeking out* questions on which to cast bounties, and you've implied with your naming suggestion that you see this as "philanthropy". Well, I don't agree. I'm sure the eventual benefactor of your rep will be happy to receive it, but it seems to me that whether they actually earnt any of it would have been something of a secondary concern to you.

Besides, offering rewards (e.g. badges) for dishing out bounties will only encourage unscrupulous individuals to spam any old Q&A with them. Just to, you know, get the badge. Badges are for encouraging and rewarding active and proper use of the site, not going about its mechanisms in a wonky manner.

Comment: This is the correct answer, unfortunately. (And I'm speaking out of experience - I've tried for years to find a productive and philanthropic way to dump my rep... it simply doesn't work that way.)

Comment: I actually came to Meta a few days ago to suggest more or less the same thing as this question, but then reading related badge suggestions found arguments similar to this and was convinced. Much as I'd like some kind of recognition for rep used in bounties - especially if the bounty didn't actually draw an answer - badges are for encouraging behavior, and I couldn't figure out what bounty behavior we would want to encourage that can be codified as a badge.

Comment: "It's an indicator of trust" -> it certainly is intended that way, but on high traffic tags, you can easily find dozens of 2k+ users who provide a lot of low quality answers to low quality questions, just to take advantage of the high visibility of the tag, but would be incapable of explaining their own answer. I see rep on SO as a mean for the site to protect itself against malicious users, though, because you need *some* rep to cause damage to posts and those users don't take the time to get that rep up just to mess with poeple... So, it's an indicator of trust that you can't really trust :)

Comment: @2Dee: That is true. Still, we shouldn't make it _worse_, eh? :)

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit that would be quite shame indeed :) I considered for a moment what would happen if we could lend our driving license to others, and concluded it would be a great experiment on artificially created chaos ...

Answer (score -8):

I just so happened to come across this and wanted to offer a non-SO point of view, as I believe this rightfully belongs on MSE as badges affect the entire Stack Exchange network.

I think this is a wonderful idea and have wondered myself why there isn't a silver and bronze level badge for this. On the site I'm most active on, we take pride in keeping out unanswered question percentage as low as possible. People come looking for help, and it's nice if they actually get that help. On lower traffic sites, getting good (and often *hard*) questions in front of the right people can be difficult. Offering bounties on other people's questions is a great way to do this. Often a newer ("low rep") user doesn't want to give up privileges they've worked hard to earn in order to get their Q an A. In my opinion, this badge would give people a reason to stop hoarding their rep and give back to newer users a bit more. That's something we should encourage. Let's face it, once you're beyond a certain threshold the points don't matter anymore (and they're made up anyway). Let's foster an environment where generosity is the norm.

Comment: I giggled at "get their Q an A".

Comment: See my answer for why this is not the correct way to engage in "generosity". It's like kindly donating somebody else your driving licence.

Comment: I disagree with your answer @LightningRacisinObrit. I think you've spent too much time on SO and become jaded. But I don't want to argue. I've said my piece.

Comment: Top tip: try not to launch into character assassinations and personal judgements on people just because they disagree with you on something. Besides, did I not make a _logical_ argument for my standpoint? I don't see how you can pass it off as "jaded" or a simple consequence of "spending too much time on SO". I mean, honestly, wtf.

Comment: Just calling it like I see it @LightningRacisinObrit.

Comment: To say that a user is "jaded" because they've spent a lot of time here is as lame an argument as the opposite - to say that you're naive and have spent too *little.* @LightningRacisinObrit's argument isn't that philantrophy is bad, but that rep points are fundamentally different from money and that the entire philanthrophy metaphor doesn't really work for that reason.

Comment: I've come to agree with him, philanthrophy through bounties doesn't really work. [And I have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-%EC%9B%83?tab=bounties) ([Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137693)). Bounties are not a great instrument to get quality answers to *all* questions - only to those very specific, complex, advanced questions where a bounty can maybe incentivize deep research. If there were a systematic way (like some kind of a marketplace) to find those, perhaps spending a lot on bounties could be useful. Without it, it isn't.