# Can I add bounty to existing answer of question that's not mine?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I don't understand the bounty system 100%.

On a 4 year old question, that's not mine, I have found extremely helpful answer that has only 1 upvote (now 2, with mine). However, I somehow want to "thank" the answerer more, even with my own reputation.

Is this somehow possible with the bounty system? And how to do it?

Comment: Add a bounty on the question, select "Reward existing answer" for the reason.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a bounty to other answers. This is a great way to [highlight great answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254137/enhance-moderation-ability-by-encouraging-excellent-content).

To do this, you need to start a Bounty on the *question*. Select the option to reward an existing answer.

Now you need to wait for the bounty time limit to expire. Unfortunately, the amount isn't rewarded immediately, even for this particular bounty reason. The question will end up on the Featured page for a week. As a side effect, you may find others provide another helpful answer.

Before the bounty grace period expires, you are able to select the answer you wish to reward.

Comment: This is really complicated and anti-intuitive. But thanks!

Comment: I would add that you have to wait 24h to award the bounty.