# How about making a new sort of bounty specifically to reward excellent answers and encourage new users?

Tags: feature-request

Right now the only way to give reputation to someone who you think wrote an amazing answer is to award a bounty to the question, wait 24 hours, and then after the waiting period award the bounty.

It can be very discouraging for low reputation people when they write great answers which barely get upvoted. Wouldn't it be great to facilitate the call to action of Madara Uchina ( [Enhance moderation ability by encouraging excellent content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254137/enhance-moderation-ability-by-encouraging-excellent-content) ) by have a feature which facilitates rewarding the great answers you find.

In the last days I've stumbled upon two great answers which I would like to reward and I find the process of having to award a bounty then wait for a day then choose the answer to be very cumbersome.

Comment: Do you have evidence that great answers from low-reputation users are not  awarded bounties, because of their low reputation count? It doesn't match my experience. Why would we create a bounty that excludes the existing community?

Comment: No. It could be awarded to anyone with a great answer. Just that it would be particularly useful for encouraging people with low reputation. I'm not suggesting to exclude anyone.

Comment: So you mean like an immediate bounty for answers? That's different, I'd edit to make that clearer. (but I'm sure it has a duplicate, hold on....)

Comment: @Pekka웃 ^^^^ there you go :)

Answer (score 7):

No.

Adding something like that would make it way too easy to mess with rep.

The bounty system has those delays to offer other users a fair chance at providing a *better* answer.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What type of "messing with rep" do you forsee happening?

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse we already have voting rings and sock puppets..... this will just make it easier to pass reputation around.... "Hey I got 2K rep? Lemme create 3 sockpuppets, give them enough rep to upvote by giving them a bounty, then let them vote for me".

Comment: Hmmmm I see ....