# Is it right for someone to ask a question for the sole purpose of answering and getting reputation at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

The question here was asked and answered at the same time, at 6:55.

There was even a bounty on it of 500 reputation.

*[What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)*

Is it that bounties are given of someone else raising a bounty on the question? That I could read up anyway.

Does it add to any value on Stack Overflow? Or does it reduce the culture of asking genuine questions occurring to people? I mean, there is documentation on Stack Overflow for it anyway, and it's a trivial question which a person should easily get all about anywhere else.

I don't know if this is a duplicate question; I don't see anything related though. It was just that I thought some practices just make it a bit weird whether we want people to work their ass off to get a little reputation.

I think there should at least be a buffer of time to self answer your own question. It's my perspective, and you are free to judge, but I don't think it should be a sole purpose to collect as much reputation as possible. It kind of feels like a weird mentality to me. I'm not against anyone. It's just my perspective that things here could be better being genuine.

A discussion could go anyway, where there are different perspectives. Thanks for throwing a light on this duplicate question. For me I didn't know why it was encouraged, even though pointed out in the original questions. Thank you for being generous in taking your valuable time in explaining. It would help someone making it clear in not asking a similar question.

Comment: Why do you feel sorry for cdlane when they chose to answer an already-answered question days after the fact?

Comment: Are you asking if self answered questions are ok? [They are](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @ModusTollens I know there's even a badge on it. But it feels stupid to make the setup seem anything like a points collecting game, that was where I was getting at.

Comment: May be it does add value to SO. But to the numerous people using it in that way it's just a waste of time, that is my personal perspective. Its ok . Anyway.

Comment: Why souldn't someone gain points for good questions and answers? The example you posted is clear and helpful.

Comment: @ModusTollens Why should they just assume this as a game and start collecting whatever they can, however possible.

Comment: Why do you assume they see it as a game? Sharing knowledge can be satisfying in itself, and a lot of people are enjoying it. We want to create a repository of questions and answers helpful to us and others, it shouldn't matter if we manage do that by answering our own questions. It's the quality that matters. I have seen bad self-answers and they are rightfully downvoted.

Comment: @ModusTollens What about the bounty thing doesn't it seem fishy. It seems lots of votes are also for the same reason. Something like illegal black money. You can trade it off a bounty or something. I don't know , its ok I don't want to go on to discuss anymore. Its fine however it is.

Comment: As for the bounty, you can see on the tooltip (hover over the bounty badge) that it was awarded by [Madara Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha). Notice that he has in his profile: [*"I offer a 500 point bounty for every good canonical you post."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254137/enhance-moderation-ability-by-encouraging-excellent-content). No surprise how that one got a bounty, then.

Comment: This is about shoveling rep from one user to another in order to give him enough voting power to participate in a chat room.  No, it is not right of course.  But they made it look legit so there isn't much that anybody can do about it.

Comment: Akshay since you @HansPassant find this particular answer completely inadequate and in no way close to canonical explanation of the "list comprehension" why did not you post good answer there? Or you find "list comprehension" absolutely not useful for anyone - maybe good comment on question explaining that would be nice...? (I see that enough people find it useless with 40/-9 votes - unfortunately I don't know Python to have my own opinion on that particular question).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It might have received a lot many upvotes yesterday I guess, with people just voting for it, based on this question, feeling may be it gives justice. If you say votes shows how many people found it useful, it doesn't entirely go with that notion.  I find this rather strange, like creating a reason to cause people to engage in spending more time just creating reputation, than to do more good by sharing something. Does it take much time to find something on list comprehensions. Being an addict to reputation, doesn't feel like something worth it for some.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Does it add to any value in SO.

You don't find any value from Kevin Guan's answer to their question? I know just a bit of Python and their answer looks pretty compelling to me. I'm sure Kevin knows what they're talking about. And at least 60 others found it useful, judging by the upvotes. And that's not even counting the +500 bounty you mentioned.

> Or does it reduce the culture of asking genuine questions occurring to people.

You don't think that question is genuine? Have you never wondered what "list comprehension" means or how it works?

> I mean there is documentation in SO for it anyway and its a trivial question which a person should easily get all about anywhere else.

That question pre-dates the public beta of Documentation by almost *half a year*. In other words, Documentation didn't *exist* publicly at the time that question was posted (and answered).

> It was just that I thought some practices just make it a bit weird whether we want people to work their ass off to get a little reputation.

I don't understand what you mean by this. I'd imagine Kevin had to work much harder on this self-answered Q&A for their reputation than cdlane did — and cdlane posted their answer several days, not minutes, after the fact. And while cdlane's answer is shorter, it does still add *some* value by exploring a slightly different aspect of the topic. I'm not them, but I'm not sure they feel they are disadvantaged here.

In fact, I'd go out on a limb and say that reputation is at best a secondary goal here. I think Kevin's primary goal was to educate others on the subject matter. And I'd say they did a good job of it. Now someone else doesn't have to ask a duplicate question, because there is a great, existing Q&A that they can refer to. And *that* is why we are happy to award users reputation for their high-effort, self-answered Q&As.

> I think there should at least be a buffer of time to self answer your own question. Its my perspective, you are free to judge but I don't think it should be a sole purpose to collect as much reputation as possible. Its kind of feels like a weird mentality to me. I'm not against anyone. Its just my perspective that things here could be better being genuine.

I agree, posting low-effort self-answered Q&As just for a cheap grab at reputation — and not in the spirit of sharing your knowledge — is not OK. **That's not the case with the question you linked to.** That you would trivially dismiss that question just because it was self-answered, to me, is unfortunate. I can't think of any other reason you would use that question to support your perspective on what constitutes rep-grab questions.

The buffer time only serves as a hindrance to those who already have their answer ready to go. It does not benefit anyone. If someone else comes along and answers your question, unless you are confident your answer adds a lot more value you just wasted your time writing up your own answer. If you do end up posting your own answer, then the other user just wasted *their* time writing *their* answer not knowing you had one all along!