# Add the ability to mark questions as "answered here" (a.k.a. duplicates of answers)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, welcoming

> TL;DR - Make the dupe dialog accept links to answers, and when that happens, have the dupe banner added by the system to link to that specific answer, not the question.

---

Consider the following scenario.

A user asks a question. The question has already been answered by some another user on another, sufficiently similar question, but not 100% exact. The *accepted* answer does **not** answer the newer question sufficiently well, but the third answer down the line, does. It is, in fact, that answer which I had in mind when I marked the newer question as a duplicate of this one.

Historically, marking a question as a duplicate was meant to send the following message: "This question you've just asked, someone had already asked it. Here it is". This was changed a few years ago (along with the wording of the dupe banner) and now it sends the message: "This question you've just asked, someone had already *answered* it. Here is is"

#### The problems with the current way the system communicates

- There is no indication anywhere that I'm thinking of a specific answer for the question I linked. The UI doesn't say it.
- It's very easy for users (especially new ones, who are the users whose questions get closed the most), to not understand why the hell this guy who didn't even deign to comment (because the dupe comment gets deleted), tells me to go and look at this question, with a 20k word answer that doesn't really help me right now!

  This is the important one. Friendly, welcoming, we can throw the buzzwords around all day long. At the end of the day, it's about how these newer contributors *feel*, and if they feel they were run over by The System without anyone looking at them or caring (even if friendly comments were in fact involved), we've lost.
- I *want* to give that extra bit of information. I *want* to help both users and future visitors. As much as [I love canonicals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254137/871050), I realize that when you have a simple problem, with a simple solution, a 4 page wall of text that explains every aspect of the wide subject of the problem is not what you're looking for.

#### My suggested solution

Allow the duplicate UI to accept a link to an answer (this is currently the case, but the result is the same as if you've linked to a question).

When an answer is given to the duplicate dialog, only the answer appears in the preview.

In the case of normal users (i.e. no gold badge Mjolnir and no diamond Gungnir), the generated duplicate comment should indicate that the dupe target is an answer. Perhaps something along the lines of

> Possible existing answer: {link}

TBD.

When the the votes are approved (either by 5 users, or some Norse weapon), the UI banner will look the same, but obviously would link directly to the answer, instead of the question.

---

> Disclaimer: Following this line are my own thoughts and opinions. I do not represent Stack Overflow the site, or the company, in any way, shape or form.

Stack Overflow (the company). You've made a pledge of sorts to become friendlier, more welcoming. This is a chance to make a rather frustrating system less so, and at relatively minimal dev cost, in my humble, uninformed, opinion.

I hope that you would realize that the system, more so than the people, needs to modernize and become less threatening.

---

If you've made it this far, thank you for reading!

This is, as always, an open discussion! Please share your thoughts/ideas/agreements/disagreements on this subject in the comments and answers below!

Comment: "**This question** has been asked before and already has an answer."

Comment: @Braiam You're assuming people (especially new users, a large portion of which barely speak English), actually read this text. That assumption is wrong, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes! it would avoid each time to tell the user *please read all the answer/comments/related links and you will find all what you need* because sometimes the needed answer is in the second page or there is an upvoted comment giving half the information

Comment: That assumption has nothing to do with how the system *should* work. I have no sympathy for people that are willingly unable to read. Also, no sympathy for people that believe that because two questions share one solution they are immediately duplicates.

Comment: @Braiam But this is exactly correct. The banner indicates that "This question already has an answer here:" that is, there's at least one answer in the following thread that answers your question. Moreover. Do you prefer the current system of either leaving OP frustrated, or starting to argue in comments on why they should look at all the answers?

Comment: Am I right that this request wouldn't change when questions get closed as duplicates, it would only give close voters the *option* to add additional information to make the duplicate notice more useful?

Comment: afaik yes @divibisan https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43929840#43929840

Comment: @divibisan You are correct. This is a feature request about adding a new ability, not altering the existing one in any way, neither retroactively nor from now on.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Comments are a mess and I think it should be a priority to minimize their role in conveying important information. If you know that one specific answer answers the duplicated question, I think an authoritative and official link in the banner is much better than arguing with the asker in the comments section

Comment: Wait, why do people think that this should be reopened? I don't get it.

Comment: @StephenLeppik A similar request was posted before, but never got a definite answer. The top answer supports the request with 26 upvotes, but there was never any real discussion or decisions made.

Comment: @divibisan then the discussion should happen over there. It's not like it's *that* old.

Comment: Reading both, I think mine was better presented. But bright minds do think alike :)

Comment: @Will Indeed! I couldn't find it though (too many questions about flagging duplicate answers). It's why I haven't made a claim against the dupe close on this question ;)