# What should be done with one-time questions by one-rep users?

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users, users

I've recently started encountering questions such as this: [phonegap run android fails with "...\classes.dex does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891688/phonegap-run-android-fails-with-classes-dex-does-not-exist)

Now, the question is valid, on-topic, etc. and I would like to contribute to its solution. However, it seems that OP has *abandoned* the question and sometimes I'd like to post a question only to find out that a one-rep user has already asked it and then *abandoned* it.

By *abandon* I mean that it seems to be the case that one-rep user created an account to ask for help, didn't get any help immediately, and then just upped and left. So now we're left with answers which will never be confirmed/accepted or comments which will never be read by OP.

If I had the same question, should I ask it with my own words and then go to the older question by the one-rep user and then mark that question as duplicate? Should I flag the one-rep users question for moderator attention for closing (as it *may* serve as noise)? If I had an answer for it, should I still answer that question?

**EDIT:**

I did some checking and I noticed that the asker of the linked question was last seen eight hours ago and had answered two questions (both answers received no upvotes). The linked question is still hanging, though.

Comment: Personally I hate something like "ask and go" or "drop down something" to describe newbies asking only one question(given the question is valid) because the newbies are also contributing to the community.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's OK to leave an abandoned question open even if the asker is no longer around to validate any answers as they may still potentially benefit others. If the situation can *only* be reproduced and verified by the asker and will not help any future readers, then it should be closed with the following reason, regardless of whether the asker has been around:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

It wouldn't be remiss for someone else to edit the question into something more broadly applicable, provided they don't change or remove any crucial information given in the question by the asker. But if you're more comfortable writing up your own question based on your own situation, you're free to do so.

If you have an answer that is applicable to this question, I would encourage you to answer it since the asker appears to be around. The asker will always be notified of any new answers to any of their questions.

If you feel that it is valid and on-topic, then it doesn't really constitute noise so there is no need to flag it for removal. If you're feeling particularly charitable, then besides answering it yourself, you could also choose to place a bounty to buy it some extra views and, hopefully, an answer from someone else.

Comment: But what of cases where the asker doesn't appear to be around? I've encountered quite a few of those around. There's a chance that the answers won't be accepted. And what if I myself would like to ask that question (so that I can accept an answer and reward the answerer with rep)?

Comment: I forgot to address that - edited my answer.

Comment: @brain56: giving someone an extra 15 rep isn't a good reason to ask a duplicate question. Who cares if it's not accepted? A good answer will get the answerer plenty of rep from upvotes.

Comment: *A good answer will get the answerer plenty of rep from upvotes.* [If only this were true...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253066/1768232)

Comment: @Wooble, see durron597's comment. My thoughts go there, too. And of course I'm not only looking at rewarding someone with 15 rep. I'm wanted to ask the question again so that I can accept an answer (and because it is my concern too). And I want to accept the answer so that when someone else looks at the question, they can see a verified, correct answer they can put there trust on. Sometimes, there's more credibility to a checkmark than there is in a lot of upvotes.

Comment: _"Generally, if an unanswered question doesn't meet any criteria for closure, it's OK to leave it open..."_ - lol, wat? If this is the case then it isn't just 'OK' to leave it open, it is the ONLY OPTION to leave it open. Why would you close a question that doesn't meet any criteria for closure?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: That does sound very silly when taken out of context. The "it's OK" bit was intended to address the OP's concerns about leaving abandoned questions open. In any case, edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Just answer the question.

Maybe other SO users are seeing more to this than I am but your entire premise seems *insane* to me! (Please feel free to clarify it to me in the comments)

> "If I had the same question, should I ask it with my own words and then
> go to the older question by the one-rep user and then mark that
> question as duplicate?"

You want to re-ask the same questions because you have an answer to it and then flag the **original** as a dupe? That makes *no* sense. **You** are creating the dupe so create your question and then flag your own as a dupe, or even better, don't dupe the question in the first place.

> "By abandon I mean that it seems to be the case that one-rep user
> created an account to ask for help, didn't get any help immediately,
> and then just upped and left."

How do you know it's abandoned? Perhaps the user is sitting by his/her email account just waiting for an answer to come in! Sure you can use the SO metrics to see if they've been back since then (as you have) but I still don't think you can say for sure a question is 'abandoned' until you've interacted with it in some way such as adding a comment or, even better, adding your answer.

> So now we're left with answers which will never be confirmed/accepted
> or comments which will never be read by OP.
>
> There's a chance that the answers won't be accepted. And what if I
> myself would like to ask that question (so that I can accept an answer
> and reward the answerer with rep)?
>
> I'm wanted to ask the question again so that I can accept an answer
> (and because it is my concern too). And I want to accept the answer so
> that when someone else looks at the question, they can see a verified,
> correct answer they can put there trust on.

Well not in the example you've given which has no answers and, if everyone follows the example you are giving, never will. Sure there is a chance answers won't be accepted but how is OP meant to accept an answer if people like yourself aren't willing to post one?

And I think you are over valuing the value of a green tick. All this (often)means is **this** answer solved the problem **for the OP** it won't necessary work for you. A highly upvoted answer however has more value as it indicates that it was helpful to a wider range of people and you can get this whether the question is 'abandoned' or not.

And I don' know how to fit it in nicely with the rest of my answer so I'll just plug it on in the end here but there is a very bad smell of rep-whoring in this question. ;-)

**EDIT** - After a few re-reads it kinda looks like there are 2 questions going on in this question:

1. What should I do if I want to ask a question that has already been
   asked but has no answers?
2. What should I do if I have an answer to a question but I think the asker is no longer monitoring the question?

   My answer addresses question 2.

Comment: Yes, the "green tick" can be meaningless. Sometimes the accepted answer doesn't work, isn't the best solution, or is not written clearly (but is technically correct). It is up to the reader to read the answers and select the one that makes the most sense.