# What should be done with old, useless questions?

Tags: discussion

I have been looking through questions under the [neural-network] tag and came across a bunch of very old and IMHO useless questions (usually asking for help with their code and without any answers) like these:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724661/predicting-next-values-in-time-series-using-nonlinear-autoregressive-neural-netw

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943876/how-use-a-closed-loop-to-predict-future-values-fro-narx-neuronal-network

What I'm struggling with is the following:

- Their quality is not way too bad to be answered (though they're not very good either) -> no low quality flag
- They don't qualify as exact duplicates -> no duplicate flag
- They **are not** helpful in any way since there are no answers, no comments, and the OP himself is probably not even interested in getting an answer any more because they already moved on and presumably solved their problem somehow
- They **never will be** helpful because users with similar questions will find answers in other questions here on SO (like myself when I started getting into neural networks)

I read an answer to a similar question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255622/what-should-be-done-with-one-time-questions-by-one-rep-users) where it said that questions could also be closed if the problem "**can no longer be reproduced**", which is not really the case here since they are still valid.

So, my question is: What are appropriate steps when dealing with questions like those? Or should they simply be left alone, are they part of SO's [Long Tail](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)?

Comment: Old, 0 score questions are autodeleted after a while anyway (under certain conditions), so no, they don't stick around forever.

Comment: Oh, so that's part of the "aging process" I read about somewhere. So, how long is "a while" and which conditions have to be met, other than the question having zero score?

Comment: [The complete guide to deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/289005), under the "By the system" header.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Still reading my way through the community wiki, haven't made it to this one so far. :)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/ sums this up nicely.

Comment: If they are not duplicates, maybe you can answer some yourself? It would make them a lot more useful.

Comment: What about all the **new** useless questions? I'm not just talking about the ones confined to your chosen tag, of course ...

Comment: @TheBlueDog We wait for them to become old... :D

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you haven't even been a member for a month, and somehow you seem to feel that such questions have to be "dealt with" (which is a behaviour more commonly seen in people who have been members for a long time and who have lost their initial patience). I'm not sure why you'd have a problem with these questions to the extent that you consider closure or even deletion might even be required, or that they need to have an existential meaning in the SO big picture (the long tail).

Comment: _"They never will be helpful because users with similar questions will find answers in other questions here on SO"_ -- if that were actually true, wouldn't that make the "useless" question a duplicate of the question where the answer is found? Why not just vote to close as a duplicate in that case?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288432/whats-the-best-of-dealing-with-seemingly-useless-questions

Comment: @Bruno It's true, I haven't been an active member until recently, but I have been using SO as a passive user for quite a while. Anyway, the point is not that I have _"lost my initial patience"_, I was simply wondering what people do with these questions. And since I was not aware of auto-deletion (which is because I'm quite new on the active side of SO) my conclusion was that it would end up in the tail...

Comment: @PeterDuniho Because I wouldn't consider them exact duplicates. I do believe that one can find the answer here, but not in the form of a duplicate-worthy question. At the same time I don't believe that the OPs still want their answers while new users would find them elsewhere. That's why I was asking. But anyway, I got my answer and I'm happy with it.

Comment: _"I wouldn't consider them exact duplicates"_ -- seems to me, if it's not worth answering, it's a duplicate. If it's not a duplicate, it's worth answering. Sorry...I just don't buy the premise that any question on SO should just sit without _any_ action. And frankly, what the OPs want is irrelevant. The primary purpose of SO is to build up a repository of questions and answers; that individuals get solutions to their specific problems is really in some ways just a happy side-effect.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Saying the primary purpose of SO is to build up a knowledge repository is a rather simplified view of the SO mechanism. The primary purpose of SO is to make money for those who run it. It does so by encouraging users to provide interesting content so that other users will come and have a look. After that, there's a grey area between users answering questions to gain rep (because it still is the main individual indicator) or simply to try to help the asker, and that goal of building a curated knowledge base. People helping people is not a side effect, it's the driving mechanism.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Leave them up.  If nothing else, someone searching for a similar issue might stumble upon them and gain something from the question itself.  Who knows, they might post the answer (this has saved me on various HP printer driver forums in the past).

Comment: Their helpfulness is what I'm not fully convinced of; esp. the first question simply uses one of MATLAB's automatically produced scripts, so everybody who ever made it this far will have this code and find nothing new in there.

Comment: sometimes the very bad wording of a question is what helps a newbie.  If it contains a link to better wording alone, then it is worth it.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

This image shows exactly the issue, I had got some clues and some answers from posts like this. So best thing to do is leave it as it is.

Answer (score 14):

It's best to leave the questions as they are. There will be people facing the same/similar issue. They may find the question and they won't see any answers. They may somehow be able to solve the issue on their own. Someone might think of coming back to **Stack Overflow** and posting the answer so that others who are facing the same/similar issue will not have to go through the pain he/she did.

Comment: I've done this once or twice... found unanswered questions, said "Damn you, Internet!" and shaken my fist.  Then solved the problem, and in a fit of altruism gone and put in an answer to the questions I found.