# Why am I not getting answers? (and is that trend getting worse?)

Tags: discussion, questions

In the last two months, I've posted 7 questions (6 plus one just now), and got two answers: one of those only after I posted a bounty.  The rest of the questions have no answer.  I think they are pretty decent questions, not too general, and I kinda remember it being much better.  Mid-last year I was getting really fast answers (within an hour sometimes).

Is this a sitewide trend or is it just me?  If sitewide, why is this happening?  If just me, what should I do?

Comment: No it is not just in your head, it is getting worse. The noise volume has been turned up to 11, it is getting hard for people to find questions to answer. If you've been following Meta over the past few weeks, you already know the history ([1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252756), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758), [3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254770), etc.). The team tells us that they're working on solving this. If you haven't already, you might want to [listen to the recent podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists).

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks!  I wasn't following all that, thanks for catching me up.  Amusing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/1828289  Ah well.  I'll stick around and see how things evolve.

Comment: And we witness the transition from #1 to #4 :-)

Comment: @AlexI the better you get - the more specific your questions get, and the more likely it is you need to get people to your questions rather then them arriving "organically". See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223771/as-a-highly-experienced-professional-software-developer-i-have-difficulty-getti/223773#223773