# Why don't people carefully read my question, even after placing a bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounty, answer-quality

I am not a person who chases ranking or reputation. And I can google.

I have posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016442/how-to-distinguish-is-a-file-or-a-folder-dragged-while-drag-not-drop), researched the problem, and even wrote about that (as Jon Skeet advised). But people just replicate my research, or their answers do not fit my question. When I point out their oversight, they just removed the answer, in the worst case.

I spent half of my reputation on a bounty, but it didn't help.

What can I do to improve comprehensibility of my question?

Comment: The bounty is exactly why people post half-assed answers. They don't really know the answer but give it a go anyway, who knows they might get some rep from the bounty.

Comment: Nothing at all you can do increase the chances of getting a useful answer to your question. People who really can answer a non-trivial question don't care about SO reputation.

Comment: Consider the possibility it *is not possible*. (A casual Google pointed me to the underlying mechanism which uses `kFilePromiseMime` -- "used to indicate that the file referred to isn't yet available but will be when the drop occurs".)

Comment: @user246408: that's not really true. BalusC for a while would [only pay attention if a question had a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252799); he has since removed that text from his profile though. For me personally, I use a RSS feed to track bountied questions in tags I care about, because I cannot ever see every question ever posted. The ones with a bounty at least have people care just that bit extra about.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason to answer for a reputation. Sometimes I answer a question which I myself do not fully understand and want to dig into the details. Sometimes I just want to help a questioner. Never for bounties or reps.

Comment: Edited your question a bit on SO to improve the clarity, please feel free to revert it.

Comment: I don't think you did anything wrong. The system (partially) failed for this question.

Comment: I'm sorry @Jongware, but you are talking abou my question directly? There is a two years old bug in chrome bug tracker   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534677/html5-drag-and-drop-getdata-only-works-on-drop-event-in-chrome?rq=1

Comment: @Infinite Recursion thanks! But how can I emphasize my "research"? Because people replicate and do not read it, but use even the same links as in my research.

Comment: Check now, edited. Is it OK?

Comment: @Infinite Recursion, yes!

Comment: The best ways is to tag the question properly, include some code or image if one is available and make it clear that the question is related to something in first sentence. Bounty is way to get answers quickly but you need to wait and ignore those who do not respond properly

Comment: It looks like someone has _thoroughly_ answered your question. Maybe that answer doesn't solve your problem because the problem cannot be solved. A bounty isn't going to magically make unsolvable problems solvable.

Comment: The title of your Stack Overflow question is nearly incomprehensible. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @usr How did the system fail?  Bounties are designed to attract *attention*, not (necessarily) good answers.  I OP is getting more answers, then it sounds like the bounty was successful, just not all that *useful*.

Comment: In my opinion (and not addressing the above identified question specifically) bounties are virtually worthless.  They attract bounty hunters who will give you a supposed answer that usually misses the point of your question, but few others.

Comment: @user246408: I don't care for the reputation gain of bounties, but bounties usually are *interesting questions*. Since most questions get answered quickly, a bounty usually indicates a tough cookie... unfortunately it also attracts a certain kind of users...

Comment: There are various reasons why you don't get an answer even after _spending_ a bounty.  It is possible that one might not have an answer to your question.  There are also instances when one doesn't _want_ to answer -- for example, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237062/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-policy-on-honoring-do-not-track-browser-s

Comment: Your question in general is a valid one; However, for your example I don't see this at all. In fact, you have one valid, well-researched and correct answer, what more could you wish for? Even more, I wonder why you complain about people not reading your question, when you yourself seem to not read the provided answers. The answer you gave yourself to the question is identical to the well-researched one. It is not the fault of people answering questions if something can simply not be done.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've had a question where people thought I said Html.ActionLink when in fact I said Url.ActionLink, and thus the answers they supplied were wrong.

"Why people do not carefully read my question?"

Because they lack reading comprehension skills.  There is also a sense of charity in providing an answer, and often times people don't feel an obligation to read your question beyond skimming over it, and instead just take a shot in the dark at an answer.  Is their mentality justified?  That's hard to say.  If you go to websites dedicated to connecting with charity/volunteer positions they always emphasize that even though you are volunteering, you should always conduct yourself in a professional manner and additionally keep to any commitments you make.  If we took this mentality on SO, then you would be expected to read someone's question thoroughly(assuming the question is well defined) and respond professionally.  If you are not willing to do that, then don't answer at all.  I think that might be too much to expect of SO though.

Sometimes "shots in the dark" can solve some people's problems.  These however are a completely different class of answers.  The answerers understand and read the question, but their answer simply may not work for you, while they are good answers because they work for others with the same question.  There are questions regarding troubleshooting some random Visual Studio problem, and between 5 different answers, one thing solves the issue for some while other answers solve it for others.  So sometimes an answer is useless to one person but very useful to others with the same problem.

My personal frustration with unrelated answers is they take the question in the wrong direction, and create conflict when you point out their error.  Some people can't accept that they misread something and get upset when their irrelevant answer gets downvoted.  Such poorly thought out answers should expect that they might not apply to the question being asked, and thus might get downvoted.  In the case I cited, I downvoted and pointed out their mistake, for which they could have responded by either correcting their answer or deleting it. Instead they decided it was more appropriate to personally insult me.

I certainly have provided an answer before that I believed had a chance to solve the user's problem, but was not in a position to setup a complete test case to validate that my solution applied to their question.  If they comment that my answer doesn't apply for some reason, I either revise or delete it so that it doesn't detract from the question at hand.

"What can I do to improve comprehensibility of my question?"

When you've had this experience many times, you begin to anticipate the different directions people will try to take your question.  Commonly I include things like "I am not asking for anyone to write code for me, just a general concept and what pieces of the API I should be leveraging to get started?" or "Approaches using Html.ActionLink do not apply here, because the result of that is HTML, where as I need a URL which can be passed to APIs that take a URL." Unfortunately by the time I've considered all the stupid things people will try to do to misinterpret the question, I decide it's not worth even asking.

Comment: *even though you are volunteering, you should always conduct yourself in a professional manner and additionally keep to any commitments you make.* But then the world would be a better place :)

Answer (score 40):

As the author of the only real answer to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25016442/3889449) (which caused this Meta question to be asked), I can say that **I actually answered the question**. If you spend two minutes of your time to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095250/3889449), on which I actually spent *hours*, you'll see that I gave all the possible information about the feature you're looking for. I stated (more than once) that **what you're asking for is impossible**, and I also gave valid motivations.

Given that, I'm a bit disappointed, and I also find this Meta post a little offensive. Not because my answer hasn't ever been accepted, but because you look like some sort of recidivist who doesn't want to accept the truth that the answer to the question is "no", and you are blaming me for not reading your question carefully, which is completely wrong, as you should see from the effort I put into writing my answer to help you.

---

I'm also quoting some of your comments on my answer along with my replies:

> As I write in my question, I need that info while dragging (dragover and dragenter events), not drop. – [kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615620/kris)

> Answer edited. This is the best I can do. Im sorry, but it looks like you **can't** read files on drag events. – [Marco Bonelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli)

> Thanks, but also as I write `event.dataTransfer.types[i] == "Files"` is true for folder and file. – [kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615620/kris)

> I know. My answer to your question is that you really **can't** check if a file is a folder on a drag event. I'm sorry. – [Marco Bonelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli)

Reading these few comments I can see that not only you don't seem to care about my answer being "no", but you almost don't seem to understand it at all. Who's the one who is not "carefully reading" here?

Other comments on this Meta question also point this out:

- This comment, which explains the situation very well in a few sentences (thank you dirkk for posting it):

  > Your question in general is a valid one; However, for your example I don't see this at all. In fact, you have one valid, well-researched and correct answer, what more could you wish for? Even more, I wonder why you complain about people not reading your question, when you yourself seem to not read the provided answers. The answer you gave yourself to the question is identical to the well-researched one. It is not the fault of people answering questions if something can simply not be done. — [dirkk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1451599/dirkk)

  *"It is not the fault of people answering questions if something can simply not be done"*: this is the truth above all the truths.
- This second one, which should also make you realize *«maybe the answer is just "no"?»*:

  > It looks like someone has thoroughly answered your question. Maybe that answer doesn't solve your problem because the problem cannot be solved. A bounty isn't going to magically make unsolvable problems solvable. — [Shoe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1950321/shoe)

  *"A bounty isn't going to magically make unsolvable problems solvable"*: this is pure gold.

---

At this point I don't know what else to say, because the facts speak for themselves. I hope you'll change your mind on the topic.

Comment: And thank you for the careful workout of your answer, and making my question more clear for people. I really appreciate that.

Comment: So now, after more than two years, you comment on my post trying to explain your reasons. Why not stating your reasons two years ago in the beginning, before starting to rant about people who "don't carefully read my question"? *I did* carefully read your question, and *I did* provide you a complete answer. I understand that you are interested in knowing if any future developments will cause the answer to your question to change, and that's the reason why you can *change* the accepted answer at any moment, but this doesn't mean the current answer isn't valid.

Comment: The fact that my answer may not be what you *think* is right doesn't mean that it actually isn't objectively right for the rest of the SO community. If, from the very beginning, you had told me "Look, thanks for the answer, but I'll leave the question open because I want to know if there are any further developments which may solve my problem" I could've respected that, after all it's your question. It wouldn't have made much sense to me, since that SO is not the place for things like this and there are plenty of sites to track requests and bugs for browsers, but I could've lived with it.

Comment: However, what you were complaining about here two years ago just didn't make sense, and that's why I wrote this post: to try and explain what was going on to other users. Now you come out of nowhere with this comment... well, sorry, but I don't really care about you or your question anymore. Oh, and P.S: "You can't" *is* an answer to the question "How".

Comment: (no, I'm not talking alone, apparently OP decided to remove their comments, that's unfortunate)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It seems the OP no longer participates on SO, so they will never be able to accept that answer, especially if they also no longer participate in life. Correct-but-never-accepted answers are a feature of SO.

Comment: @AndrewMorton well, thanks for the reminder I guess, I already acknowledged the fact that OP's question would have never had an accepted answer ~5 years ago. I don't care if it's accepted or not, I know that answers don't necessarily *need* to be accepted. I do care if the reason the answer is not accepted is that OP thinks that I "don't carefully read the question" or that I provided a wrong/poor quality answer (which is what this meta post implies, and it's definitely not true).

Answer (score 19):

People don't read questions carefully because *most of the questions are not written to be read*.

Check out 10-20 latest questions at any time and you'll find how carefully most of them are written:

- title unrelated to body,
- sample's code unrelated to anything else or 10 times longer than needed or looking like result of decompiling obfuscated code,
- research demonstrated with "searched https://disney.com for 5 days and can't find alot".

Picking one part of the question and answering it in many cases is the best chance to create an answer somewhat related to the question. So why to read the whole post?

Posters also rarely do care about the post. I would also expect questions to have *edits by original poster* if any comments are present on the post or if there are answers that don't look on topic. If post was only edited by community members it is *sign* that original poster does not care enough about the question. Again lack of edits by owner happens way too often training readers to mostly ignore the post and go by assumptions.

---

If you really want me to read your answer completely (or at very least get related answers)

- have post with concrete title
- Have super short and correctly spelled summary of what you are looking for *and* what you already know.
- have sample that is written to be *readable* and at least on first glance related to your post
- have sample that *does not lead* to undesired answers. Most common sample of the issue is "Find something with regex in my text" and showing reading of HTML/XML - even if you need to read HTML with regular expression don't make it easy for reader to skip reading and downvote/close as known issue.
- the rest of the post *looks* readable
- have links/samples of what you've tried/found with half sentence explaining why it did not work.
- if you have any particular restrictions which would reject obvious answers they are clearly spelled out. I.e. "I know I can use XXXXX, but I need to use previous version that does not support it".

I.e. if your post would start with something like following it will get much better chance to not attract bad answers (or at least save you time on commenting bad ones).

> I need to distinguish whether a folder or a file is dragged in events `dragover` or `dragenter` (before item is dropped). According to information below it was not possible in any browser in 2012.
>
> Question: can I do it now (any browser) or why it should not be possible.

Comment: Many are not written very well, but if your reading comprehension is somewhat above average you can figure out the question, in most cases. (I know most people aren't above average, by definition, but plenty are). I wouldn't tend to blame posters for that, some guidance usually clears things up.

Answer (score 3):

You have **38** up-votes on that question, what makes you assume your answer is not comprehensible? If there are not many good answers that doesn't mean your question is bad. If it was bad almost everyone on SO would know by now seeing a ton of down-votes and close-votes.

There are some answers there, whether they are up to the mark you are looking for is another story but your question does not seem to have any issues, Those 38 votes are only 62 votes short of a Gold badge. Even if you don't care about reputation that is still one of the measures of quality of your question.

Comment: When OP had posted on Meta, the question quality was not the same as today. It  "needed improvement" and OP had approx 50 rep. The community members edited the question to it's current form. And it's nice to see it stand on it's own today, a week after the original post was written.

Comment: Yes! When I asked the question, it has only 2 rep. and several NOT "carefully reader" answers. I spent half of my reputation on bounty,  and I couldn't downvote them. But when I wrote there, guys upvote my question and downvote "bad" answers, so they was removed. It happens for two days!