# Users' 'growth' and 'decline' in their Stack Overflow life

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

Is there or can we create a graph/statistic showing the lifetime, in terms of access and contribution, of a user in Stack Overflow, highlighting also significant events and comparing with the average of *all* users?

In more detail:

I came across some reports of a partner's website. They run an experiment aiming to show how changes in users real life can affect a user's browsing pattern on their website. What at the end this did is combine user life events (e.g. change of job or age), general info and demographics (e.g. economic crisis or summer) with the users' actions in theirs several websites.

Will be useful to do something similar in Stack Overflow? Will it add any value?

Taking myself as an example, I was more active (asking questions and answering) when I was a student and I had no Job. While I was less active when I found a job, my questions were more interesting (e.g. the where gathering more traffic and votes). Now I am in a decline face, my job requires fewer hands on and my hobbies are not challenging enough. I can see I am contributing less to none in Stack Overflow and I am mostly here to read answers whenever needed. In addition, I see that nowadays I am not accessing Stack Overflow every day, as I did some years ago.

Comment: Though I would find it interesting, what would be the real value of this? Also, how would you gather those real-life events? For me, the amount of time I spend on SO highly correlates in which project I'm currently working and if there any deadlines upcoming. I don't think I would be allowed to share internal deadlines on SO.

Comment: @BDL I was thinking that we may gather them from JOBs profile (assuming that it is updated) or somehow from Developers Survey (even if it is anonymous). But yes, I am not sure if the idea can be implemented and if the output will be of any value.

Comment: Account only active in november never touched after it's first year.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think it would add any value, but usually, when someone is very active on StackOverflow and stops being active it is probably because they changed jobs and don't have time any more to answer questions.

Some people become inactive and others become active, it's just how the cycle is currently. Sometimes high reputation users just get bored of answering the same questions over and over again so they become inactive.

You can see a graph here:

[Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252757/7015400)

Comment: *Sometimes high reputation users just get bored of answering the same questions over and over again so they become inactive.* This, exactly. Some people get bored at some point, or struggle to find good questions that interest them. Worth noting there are also high-rep users who happily continue answering duplicates.

Comment: not related but congrats on 100k @jpp

Comment: @jpp and it seems you get bored after reaching 100k? You stopped answering since then :p

Comment: I got bored because it seems impossible to find how-to style questions to answer that don't get trampled on by well meaning users who think the site only allows useless debugging questions that have zero chance of ever helping anyone other than the OP in their very specific situation with their very specific code. The idea of sharing generally applicable information seems almost offensive to some users nowadays.

Comment: @PeterHaddad "it's just how the cycle is".. Hakuna matata brother ;)

Comment: If SO doesn't want duplicates answered, they need to provide tools to make it easier to track duplicates.  I don't think it is in their interest, particularly, to prevent duplicates from being answered — new questions with new answers are the life of the system.  So, there's been nothing done over the last 10 years to provide tools for making it easier to track duplicates.