# Favorites got lost in migration back to meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, migration, mso-mse-split, bookmarks

I am certain that I (and many others) had marked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) as favorite, but the marks seem to have gotten lost when the question was migrated back to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Is it still possible to recover the information who had marked the migrated questions as favorites? If yes, could this be fixed?