# Links to answers broken in questions migrated back to MSO

Tags: discussion, migration, mso-mse-split

E.g. in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) which was migrated back to meta.stackoverflow.com, the links to answers in the same question don't work. Instead of jumping to the answer, I'm redirected twice and end up back at the top of the page.

I fixed one of the links in that question, but there are others which are still broken. The fix doesn't seem to be trivial - apparently the id of the answer changed - so I am not sure I could all fix all links in the post correctly.

Ideas what to do in such a case?