# Are we losing the battle against the close vote queue?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Until about two weeks ago, the dreaded [close vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) was shrinking steadily, until it bottomed out at about 7000 (I once observed 6.7k just after midnight). But ever since it has been on the rise again, or at least not made any further downward progress.

I don't fully understand the current system (explanations welcome, I think I heard something about auto expirations, but I'm also seeing questions in the queue that have *no* close votes at all). However, I'd like to make an appeal to allow us to continue to reduce the queue size until it is actually zero. *Then* we can trickle more review items back into it.

My reasoning is the same as ever: there is a significant psychological factor involved in motivating people to participate. If you feel that you're making a change, you'll participate gladly, but if you make no impact, you're probably not going to bother.

Just me personally, I started exhausting my 40 vote limit (and have been every day since) when I saw the queue was shrinking a few weeks ago. But now I'm going to stop doing that, since it just makes me feel bad to spend that time. I'll still gladly review edits and low-quality posts, but even though I know that it's The Right Thing, I just feel a bit silly sisyphusing away at the close vote queue.

Comment: The close vote queue will never be empty.  Assuming it can be is probably not realistic.

Comment: @Joe: It looked like pretty realistic assumption two weeks ago! (I know it can't be genuinely empty - the whole point of this discussion is to come up with some kind of preselection method that makes the *visible* workload motivating.)

Comment: Yes, close votes expire (eventually), but the large Close Vote review queue on [so] has IIRC led to the implementation of a "flexible" entry mechanism for inclusion of questions in the queue. That is, not all questions with a closed vote is entered into the queue, but only those with highest number of votes (say 4 or more)... until that queue is "too small", at which point the highest number of votes is decreased (to say 3 or more). No votes but in the Closed Vote queue could stem from low-rep users *flagging* for closure.

Comment: @Werner: Oh, were the flags recently merged into the queues?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not 100% sure, but that's the only route low-rep users have of initiating a closure. That is, through flagging.

Comment: @Werner That's changed now: [Shog's idea has been implemented](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions?rq=1). To sum it up, no more fuzzying, everything enters the queue but if it doesn't get much activity, it gets dequeued.

Comment: @hichris123: Thanks for the link - hm, I fear that "remaining stable at that level [7000+ items]" is a dangerous state of being. After all, you should try to maximise the review activity of the members, and motivation seems to be important.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The psychological take on a review queue that is too large was the original intent of making it fuzzy. I would think the same goes for dequeuing due to low activity. Otherwise the task may just seem insurmountable... always.

Comment: @Werner: I fully agree. I just think that "stable at 7000" won't be as good a motivator as "stable at 0"!

Comment: @Joe I don't see any reason why it can't intermittently reach zero (even if just for a few seconds) and rarely / never go above 500 (100? 50?) or so.

Comment: There is dedicated [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for users that regularly handle close votes and we have weekly close vote events to prevent that people get lost in that queue. Feel free to join...

Comment: is there a downside to making pointless vote closes/flags, or are people free to spam the queue as much as they can?

Comment: @puser iirc there is a flag weight system. The more flags you get approved the more weight they have and the more flags you are given.

Comment: @Amicable here's a (semi related) post about someone complaining about running out of flags and wanting to flag something that he should not be flagging. Now, he thinks he's doing the right thing and helping the site, this is a problem that should probably be addressed and would likely help with the flood of close votes. (but may not help much, after all I don't know how many close votes are actually wrong or not)

Comment: The new wielders of the [dupehammer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers) should *carefully* review dupes in the queue to help expedite the process.

Comment: @JohnConde: Hm, yes, though it doesn't seem to be making much of a dent...

Comment: So just a few weeks after this question was asked, the close vote queue has grown to over 10.5k and growing. Any movement on this, or do just accept that the close queue will always be this massive?

Comment: I constantly see my flags age away... It gives very little motivation to do spring cleanup on certain tumbleweed tags.

Answer (score 25):

I generally have  a few goes at it each week, often get to the maximum (which is irritating by the way)

Thing is reading and voting to close say 40 questions takes a good stick of time if you are being diligent, where as it seems to take no time at all for 40 people to ask one question which is almost certainly going to be closed. It's like decorating your house, by the time you've just done the spare bedroom, the missus has got bored with the wall-paper in the front room.

Losing no, pyrrhic victory, definitely

Comment: It takes me about 45 minutes to burn thru my 40 reviews, it's a lot of work.

Comment: I got a bit burned out. I've done my 40 reviews each day until recently but now I have a break. It started to feel more like a burden.

Comment: @bjb568 it takes me 15-20 min when I don't [additionally flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252852/839601). [Do you use filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994/165773)?

Comment: @gnat I do filter, `[dns] [web]`, and when there's none, `[javascript] duplicate`.

Comment: @gnat: Ah! I had not seen that *filter* thing :X I kept skipping questions about VB scripts and the like that I did not feel qualified to handle...

Comment: I fully agree about reaching the plateau. I just started reviewing recently, and it's annoying to see the queue at 7k but be told that you are not allowed to close any longer; it just seems that the system is conspiring against you.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I sometimes think SE team [intentionally hides it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220922/165773 "see for example this ignored request to promote use of filters with badge") from CV reviewers, as if they are scared to imagine what will happen if they become more productive :)

Answer (score 15):

We could lower the reputation requirement for people to participate in the close review queue. This would certainly add some more fresh, perhaps less-embittered, reviewers to the mix. If this isn't entirely acceptable, why not combine that lowered rep requirement with an additional requirement for reviewing such as longevity/participation on the site? The basic idea here is to increase the total number of quality reviewers to tackle the close review queue.

I myself wouldn't mind helping out and I think I've been around long enough, and consistently participated long enough, to actually contribute. I'm sure there are others of my profile (low rep, high participation, generally quality participation) who would be willing to jump into the ruckus and help sort things out.

Try knocking the rep requirement down to 2k, and see what happens.

**Edit**: I'm adding Farid's suggestion into this answer. We could have the first 20 questions (or some very high percentage of the first forty or so, randomly placed) for low-rep users be test questions to see if the reviewer is actually voting properly and usefully.

Comment: I have see many times people on the close queue voting wrongly. Specially goes for duplicates, someone marks the question as duplicate, but the suggested question is not the same problem, but I see people voting on the same duplicate even though it's wrong. I think there are actually people who just vote to get their badges. I fear it'd be worse with lowering rep requirement.

Comment: If I understand your reply correctly, then you are saying that people with low reputation are more likely to vote incorrectly in the close queue. Hence my qualified suggestion that the user also have a longevity or participation requirement attached to the lowered rep requirement. Presumably that would imply that you would get someone who's been around a while, already done some reviewing within the realm of what they were already allowed, and would more likely know what they are doing with a close review and why.

Comment: The problem with duplicate is that just because the question is different, sometimes the response is the same. But there is no "already answered" clause, only a "duplicate question: already answered" :/

Comment: Maybe we can instead test the low rep user first on 20 questions with faked history(like the ones that happens from time to time), if they closed it properly, then they are allowed to close real questions. That should be a better requirement.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Actually I've seen people marking duplicates on almost same questions, but entirely different answers.

Comment: It sound like these are issues you are already having with the current rep requirements. I like your suggestion with the fake 20 questions. That's the kind of idea that can really help ensure quality. If you don't mind, I will edit my answer with your idea.

Comment: @Farid, of course the occasional bad closure gets through, but I really think you're exaggerating the problem. Closing as duplicate is hard, and I very rarely see an incorrect closure compared to the number of [definitely duplicate, but still needs 3 more votes] questions. If there were that many bad closures the reopen queue wouldn't be sat at 0 for 98% of the day.

Comment: @OGHaza Luckily I rarely have seen wrongly closed question, but I do see more than 1 user voting wrongly on a duplicate question. Luckily because of the fact that 5 votes are needed for the question to be closed, majority of the people will vote on the correct duplicate question or `leave open`, so right now the current system is fine. You are correct, we can judge based on the reopen queue. but what I'm saying is that lowering the rep requirement might result in more wrong votes.

Comment: @Farid, I agree with you there. Given the states of the other queues I don't think lowering rep requirements would be a good thing either (I think I forgot that was what you were arguing against when I replied before ;) )

Comment: @OGHaza, Well, if you are already having problems with quality voting, and you think you think lowering the rep would make that worse, why not atleast Farid's suggestion of quality control test questions? It might provide a nice injection of quality reviewers, as well as get more people genuinely participating in the moderation of the site overall.

Comment: @Ouflak, I have no issue with the current quality of voting in the CVQ. But if you made suggested edit reviewers take a 20 question test to start, I still think you'd find them auto-approving the remaining 980 for the badge. In my experience, the vast majority of questions in the CVQ should be closed, by far the easiest action to perform in the CVQ is "leave open", so I definitely don't want all the auto-approvers from the edit queue coming and anto-leaveopening in the CVQ.

Comment: You might see that. It's just an idea at this point. Also, 20 is a number thrown out by Farid. It could be some high percentage mix of the first forty or fifty questions. And tests are always happening aren't they? (I was under that impression.) If there are continuous test questions, I would have to believe that an auto-approver would eventually flip enough flags to get a ban. If not, then there is another problem right there.

Comment: just give me a chance, I'll happily review and close 20 per day to prove myself, spending up to 30-40 minutes on it in the evening...

Comment: @MatthieuM. This is an example of some reviewers, just clicking on the selected close without even thinking: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256096/774086 Although it was a bad question, it was the wrong feedback. The OP could have edited the question to fix it, if he knew what was wrong. This why I think we should make sure we don't have irresponsible people reviewing stuff in the queue.

Comment: I think everybody agrees that the only people doing reviews, no matter which queue it is, should be doing quality reviews. Perhaps though we should question whether having 3,000 rep is a special marker that signifies such a reviewer. It would seem from these comments and examples like yours, that this is clearly not the case. Thus my suggestion (and yours) that quality reviewers of perhaps lower rep could be allowed to participate in reducing the close vote queue.

Comment: I suggest a very simple formula whereby the higher the voters rep. - the more votes they may have. You mighht be able to lower the rep. requirement then. Basically they will have more influence. Maybe also look at other stats. Like history of participation in these kinds of activities.

Answer (score 14):

The queue has been shrinking steadily primarily because the huge backlog has been aging content out faster than new items have been added.  With such a long backlog to go with the new aging process, this was to be expected.

Now that we've gotten to the point where the items in the backlog either ended up being handled or (as was primarily the case) aging out, the queue isn't shrinking anymore.

Now we're back to the equilibrium that we were at before the aging changes.  New items are coming in at about the same rate that they were before, and without a huge number of items leaving the queue due to aging, we're once again being able to see, through the stats, the fact that the items in the queue aren't processed as quickly as they come in.

The aging will of course make sure that the backlog caps out a a certain point, it'll take a bit of time to see where it settles down to (and whether or not SE changes the numbers a bit to affect how big that backlog is) but because items are coming in faster than they're coming out, there will still be *a* backlog, it just won't be as big.

Comment: It would be nice to get some current numbers of the flux of incoming items, processed items and expired items, especially whether the latter is non-zero.

Comment: I get the feeling that the aging timeouts and other values are still being tweaked, so you'd expect the number of items present in the new queue to vary a bit in the interim. The point of the latest changes was to focus closing towards new questions, not older ones. From the stats I see, this has worked as intended. The developers have to gather a little data on his this is performing before adjusting things further.

Comment: @BradLarson: Do you see any stats on the absolute numbers of review actions that have been taken over time?

Comment: @KerrekSB - Beyond the immediate numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats , no I don't. I can only see charts for actions taken (closed posts, etc.), which is why I can say that we're seeing a lot more relatively new questions being closed since this change. When the sorting of the queue was changed before, question closures shot up, but that was happening mostly with older questions. The rate appears to have remained the same or increased, but the questions being closed are newer ones, not older.

Answer (score 8):

How about a cheeky GreaseMonkey script solution?

```javascript
window.addEventListener ("load", feelGoodify, false);

function feelGoodify() {
    var nums = document.getElementsByClassName("dashboard-num");
    for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        var queueCount = parseInt(nums[i].innerHtml);
        if (queueCount > 200) {
            nums[i].innerHtml = (queueCount % 100) + 100;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to fake the numbers why not save the workflow headache and just throw in any old number?

I don't think fudging the numbers or "juking the stats" is much of a solution. What needs to be done is encourage more people to get involved without hiding the reality.

- Perhaps offer a one-time badge (could be reused if history repeats) for participation in a (week long?) intensive push to clear?
- Maybe increase the max daily votes per user (possibly scaled by rep or queue activity) to allow those helping to help more.

Comment: I don't know... you can be cynical all you like, but I think the very real experiment we had with burning down the queue showed that people will participate more if it looks like they're making progress. Would you discount that?

Comment: Not at all, but I don't think fudging the numbers is much of a solution. What needs to be done is encourage more people to get involved without hiding the reality. Perhaps offer a one-time badge (could be reused if history repeats) for participation in a (week long?) intensive push to clear? Maybe increase the max daily votes per user (possibly scaled by rep or queue activity) to allow those helping to help more.

Comment: Displaying a meaningful number that shows progress **is** a way to encourage people. It has patently already worked. If you prefer, think of this question as being about maintaining sustainable motivation. We haven't tried badges yet, but I think that simply having some suitable selection that allows us to keep it around zero would be a good, *sustainable* measure.

Comment: Was it the number or the attention brought to the issue? Was it the number or the organised events? Can you say with certainty that is was the number that got people involved?

Comment: The number of closed questions? They've been posted occasionally, and I think you can get them out of SEDE...

Comment: No, my point was that you seem to attribute the recent activity on the close queue to a change in how the queue length count is displayed without taking other things into account such as recent events and much discussion here about the issue on the whole. "`It has patently already worked`" seems like a `[citation-needed]` situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you look at the [graph of reviewers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251501/538247) you'll see there was a brief spike when the queue was initially fuzzied and everyone got all excited, but within a couple of weeks review activity was back to normal (despite the queue still being fuzzied).  April isn't shown, but was more of the same.

Comment: So that seems to side with my view that it was more to do with the promotion than the number fudging.

Answer (score 7):

I personally do not care about how long the review queue is. It's more important to close recent bad-quality questions quickly, before they have received an answer and given positive reinforcement to a help vampire.

The only reason the backlog is bad is that the review queue is not sorted by most recent question first. Instead, it gives stale questions, where "closing" them is kind of pointless - they've already received an answer.

So this is a problem only because the site's owners insist on closing old and stale questions in preference to recently asked questions, and especially questions without an answer.

Prioritize the closing queue by number of answers and by how recent they are, so we can close recent/unanswered questions before they've received an answer, and the backlog ceases to be a problem.

Comment: This is simply not the case.  Recent questions *are* prioritized.  That is in fact one big reason for the backlog.  Only the newer questions ever get looked at, nobody ever touches the older questions, so they just sit there in the queue.

Comment: It's still not strict ordering. I often get a 5-6 months old question, followed by a question asked a few days ago.

Comment: Correct, however it does prioritize newer questions.  Of higher priority is a measurement of "how close is the question to being closed".  A question with 4 close votes has higher priority that a question with one flag and zero votes.  Question age is however used when prioritizing items.

Comment: They should also prioritize unanswered questions, so we avoid positive reinforcement.

Comment: Meh, the majority of the LMGTFY questions are going to be answered long before the close queue is ever going to have a shot at stopping the answers, even if its given priority.  The number of questions that would have answer prevented due to this change is not likely to be high.  I'm not opposed to that consideration, but I wouldn't expect it to do a ton of good either.  Closing answered questions is still important in preventing new answers, enabling deletion, affecting the post ban algorithm, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As users with Gold Badge in a tag can close questions as duplicate with that tag as a duplicate, perhaps we could implement something similar for access to the close votes queue.

For example, give users who have the Marshal Badge access as that should be good indicator they know what needs to be closed.
([This would give 181 additional users access](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/195489/users-3k-rep-with-marshal-badge))

Comment: Historical evidence has shown that people with a review badge are the most likely to be *problematic* users, not effective users.  They're the people that don't take the time to review properly and just zoom through the queues as fast as they can.

Comment: I can see how that claim could well be justified. Can the same be said as clearly for the Marshal badge?

Comment: Plenty of the people with that badge don't even have close vote privileges.  And many of them didn't get their badges for close-related activities, so there is no reason to believe that they are particularly knowledgeable at closing questions.  Finally, that stat has no indication of how many declined flags they might have, how many of the helpful flags were automatic, etc.  I'd that there isn't strong evidence that they're going to be good closers, even though there isn't evidence that they'll be bad closers.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't see how 3000 reputation is a better indicator. At least with helpful flags you can tell they have participated in some form of community moderation.

Comment: There's a difference between having one single *vote* to close, requiring five other votes, and giving people unilateral close votes.

Comment: @Servy Its true that that particular stat has no indication of how many declined flags they might have but there is a flag weight stat that does.

Comment: @Jack No there is no such thing.  Flag weight was removed a long time ago.

Comment: @Servy I'm pretty sure it still exists and just isn't displayed to the user.

Comment: @Jack And I'm 100% sure that all of the data was actually hard deleted in the actual database, as this was confirmed by a dev.  It is not hidden, it in fact doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Servy Seems like your right, I did a search and came across this [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188379/please-revisit-the-decision-not-to-let-people-remove-moderator-flags#comment580092_188379) from [Nick Craver](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) that while it was hidden for a while it has now been removed (I'm guessing that's the confirmation you were referring to).

Comment: @Jack I wasn't referring to that specific comment, but that does indeed confirm it.