# How does this ask for an off-site resource?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128311/consuming-restful-api-using-java) was closed because

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Reproduced (for those who can't see deleted questions):

> How to call a put method in rest with following request body
>
> ```
> {
>    "salutation":"Mr.",
>    "firstName":"Tim",
>    "lastName":"Cook",
>    "title":"Chief Executive Officer",
>    "level":"C-Level",
>    "department":"Executive Office",
>    "account":{
>      "id":2
>    }
> }
> ```

This is not a great question, but the reason given to the OP for closing it seems wrong.

They were not asking for a "tool, library, or favorite off-site resource" (or at least not more than the hundreds of legit questions asking "How can I do X?")

There seems to be a growing trend to close questions that could be answered with a five-second search for this reason. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeesh.  What the hell happened there?  It's not a good enough question to reopen though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Initial wrong close vote gets cast. Others think "all I know is that it needs to be closed" and just select whatever has the convenient blue thingy next to it .... I'm guessing.

Comment: Yep.  Honestly, that question didn't really require any more thought than that, though it would have been nice to get the close reason right.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes, particularly because the close reason is *feedback to the OP*. It helps him (potentially) modify his question and have it reopened. Now he has incorrect feedback. (Though I don't think I'm going to cry any tears over this one.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the OP deserves at least a comment explaining it's the wrong reason. As mod you can leave comments on deleted posts, right? This, or it's also possible for a mod to undelete, reopen, close right away with proper reason and delete again.

Comment: And, [**again**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216677/213957), it boils down to the disappearance of the "`not enough effort`" reason for closing.

Comment: The title was "Consuming RESTful api using java".  The question doesn't really provide enough context of what's being asked, but given that title, it seems like the question was most likely "what Java API can I used contact a RESTful service and use this a request body?"  That's a non-trivial extrapolation, but it'd certainly be a library request.   I think that "unclear what you're asking" would be *more* appropriate, but if we already admit that it's unclear (susceptible to multiple interpretations), then it's conceivable that one of those interpretations was a library request.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, but you could say that about almost any question "How can I do X?". "Oh, you can use a library for that, but then that means this question in off-topic...FLAG"

Comment: How do I create and consume a RESTful api in Java? That's a request for a howto (or a library - e.g. Jackson or GSON) to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, though Jackson and GSON would be actually be answers to "How to I parse JSON in Java?"

Comment: @PaulDraper It depends; in this case it would answer - "with following request body".... Also, presumably the response is also in "JSON"... so then it's how do I generate JSON requests (and consume responses). Then HTTPClient to do the GET/POST, and now we're looking at two or three off-site tools.

Comment: @PaulDraper I agree, when a question's unclear to begin with, I think there's probably more variety in the close reasons that actually get used.  (I don't know if that's true or not, but it wouldn't surprise me.)  Also (and this is more general than your reply to my comment), just because the question got closed with that reason, we don't know that all five close voters picked that reason.  Which reason gets used as the close reason?  The most popular one?  The first one?

Comment: @PaulDraper: *There was never a "not enough effort" close reason.*

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I certainly think the closure deserves at least the same amount of effort that the OP put into his question.  Oh, wait.

Comment: @Robert OP probably have no idea he needs to put more effort, so now all he got is a wrong and misleading close reason. And we've all put here x100 more efforts than him already. There's always the (small) chance that with proper comment/close reason and nudge in the right direction, such users might learn how to ask and actually become productive.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor unless I'm mistaken, it's whichever close reason(s) has the most votes. Those who voted the exact reason are listed after the description.

Comment: I suspect that the close reason was picked at random, since there was no "lazy question" close code.  (There used to be a couple of such codes, thinly veiled, but they went away a few months back.)  (I wouldn't have voted to close (not immediately), but would have asked the OP to "clarify" his question by explaining what specifically he had difficulty with.  But of course, before he did that several others would have jumped in with answers to his homework, so maybe it's all for the best that it ended as it did.)

Comment: The OP needs a clairvoyant to answer his question.  Clearly that's an off-site resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at the initial edit:

> **Title:** consuming RESTful api using java
>
> **Content**: how to call a put method in rest with following request body { "salutation": "Mr.", "firstName": "Tim", "lastName": "Cook", "title": "Chief Executive Officer", "level": "C-Level", "department": "Executive Office", "account": { "id": 2 }}

This looks like a bad question even at first sight, however, now it's a lot harder to read too. Suddenly, the fact it's "unclear what you're asking" is a lot less clear (although still plenty clear).

I'm siding with Bart here, probably the first guy saw it was a formatting mess and just clicked the first reason they found without giving it too much thought, then the 4 others came along and just thought it has to be closed and didn't bother reading it.

By all standards, it should have been deleted and closed, although "Unclear what you're asking" was the correct reason.

All in all, closing it and deleting it was the right course of action. The close reason is a mistake, where wood is chopped, splinters must fall.

Comment: "Where wood is chopped, splinters must fall". I like it. German origin?

Comment: @PaulDraper to be sure, I'm not sure - I've only heard it in the English form.

Comment: @PaulDraper Possible: Wo [gehobelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(tool)) wird müssen Späne fallen.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" is not the correct close reason either.

Comment: Of some interest, the first closer also wrote an answer, AND formatted the question.

Comment: @Bergi To be exact, in German the idiom is "Wo gehobelt wird, fallen Späne".

Comment: @RobertHarvey What is (if there is) the correct close reason in this case? (apologies if you stated it somewhere else on this page)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: The question looks on-topic to me.  We ask and answer icanhazregex questions every day that are more specific than this.  If it turns out that there's not enough information to answer it, then use "Not enough information to diagnose problem."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree it may be on-topic, but I cannot tell what exactly is being asked, due to it being unclear or not enough info. But you are suggesting an off-topic reason for the close ("not enough information to diagnose problem"), instead of the on-topic reason ("unclear what you're asking"). Perhaps those 2 close reasons are unclear, or I have not enough info to understand them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I've opened a question about that last comment, so as not to hijack this guy's post. So feel free to discontinue this comment-discussion. If interested, here's the question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256216/what-is-the-difference-between-close-reasons-off-topic-lacks-sufficient-inform

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: Nice question and good answers.  Thanks for asking it.  FWIW, I use "Unclear what you are asking" for "I don't understand your question," and "lacks sufficient information" for clear questions missing crucial details like error messages or problem statements.