# What is the difference between close reasons "off topic: lacks sufficient information to diagnose problem" and "unclear what you're asking"?

Tags: discussion

This surely must be a duplicate question that I can't find with the search box...

The title is the question:

- What is the difference between close reasons "off topic: lacks sufficient information to diagnose problem" and "unclear what you're asking" ?

**unclear what you're asking**

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help
>   clarifying this question.

**off topic: lacks sufficient information to diagnose problem**

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more
>   detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

In certain circumstances, the difference could be quite marked - "What is that thingy in my car?" vs "My car has stopped. How can I fix it?"

The first example is quite unclear, the second is clear, but cannot be diagnosed.

However, I often find myself confused in real life posts - it seems a lot of them can go either way.

Comment: If a post can go either way, toss a coin and pick one. It doesn't matter if all close votes are exactly consistent. The close reason posted is there to give feedback as to why the post is on hold, pick the one you feel gives the best feedback for the specific situation.

Comment: Are any of our reasons clear to the OP?  Unless someone has already done so, I do not vote to close a question without leaving a comment saying why in plain English.

Comment: This has been asked on Meta Stack Exchange - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221699/closing-unclear-questions-which-close-reason-to-use-and-when Considering that it involves a close reason that is specific to Stack Overflow I wonder if it should be moved here.

Comment: @BoltClock yes, I see. It almost felt like I was reading my own question again. Definitely a duplicate, but also a nice explanation.

Answer (score 18):

I talked about this briefly in [Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow):

> #### Debugging question missing crucial information
>
> ...
>
> This addresses a specific subset of "unclear what you're asking" questions, so I originally omitted it to see how often its absence made things difficult for either closers or askers. It didn't take long; this is a very common problem, so calling it out directly and offering specific guidance is well-worth chewing up an extra slot in the list. Note that this is very similar to one of the removed off-topic reasons.

You *could* just use "unclear" for all of these questions, and in most cases you probably should. However, "Unclear" - like the "Not a Real Question" close reason that it replaced - is quite broad, and there are situations where you may wish to be more specific (a reasonable question asked in good faith that is simply missing some critical bit of information - for instance, a CSS issue that [relies on a link to a live, production website in order to identify or diagnose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)).

As a general rule, any question where you might refrain from answering and instead link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve could be closed using this reason.

Comment: This helps and I see what you are saying. Nice to have input from the author himself. The sad part is that the critical (to me) part of your answer is exactly what has been left out of the close reason explanation itself. Consider a feature suggestion to add something about "Debugging question missing crucial info" to the close reason?

Comment: If these two are so closely related, why is one a top-level close reason and one nested within off-topic? Especially as these MCVE-needy questions likely are on-topic. Shouldn't rather _unclear what you're asking_ be the one who it is associated to?

Answer (score 12):

I agree: there are many bad questions that could be closed under either reason.  This is not, in itself, a problem — it's perfectly fine for several closing reasons to overlap — but it does suggest that, perhaps, one of the reasons (presumably, the more specific "lacks sufficient information" one) could be eliminated as redundant.

However, "lacks sufficient information" is *not* really a subset of "unclear what you're asking".  Rather, AIUI, it was created specifically to address a specific set of bad questions that *don't* fall under "unclear what you're asking"; namely, those where:

> **It's quite clear what you're asking, but only a psychic could possibly know the answer.**

Typically, these kinds of questions either:

- ask why some code doesn't work as intended, but don't provide any code, or
- do provide code, but the cause of the problem is clearly not in the provided code.

There are a few other variations on the theme, too, such as asking why a program misbehaves on some input, but not providing the input.  The common thread in all these cases is that, while it's quite clear what the OP wants answered, the information needed to provide that answer is just not there.  Basically, we know where the OP wants to go, but not where he *is*.

Anyway, those are the specific kinds of questions that I usually use the "lacks sufficient information" close reason for.  If the question is generally vague in other ways too, such that "unclear what you're asking" could also apply, I generally prefer to use that reason instead, if only because it's a genuine top-level close reason, rather than just a subset of "off topic".

Answer (score 8):

They are very similar close reasons, but they do have some distinctions.  Usually, this is how I draw the distinction:

**off topic: lacks sufficient information to diagnose problem**:

- It includes no or not enough code *in the question itself*
- It does not state any actual error
- It does not explain the desired solution

**unclear what you're asking**:

- It is written in another language (which people usually use a custom close reason for anyway)
- It has severe grammar problems

The only scenario that I can think of where these two might end up being interchangeable is if the poster does not actually ask a question.  This could be marked as unclear because people don't know what the problem is or lacking information because it does not state the question.

The *unclear what you're asking* does not seem to be a very useful close reason, but I guess that is just personal preference.

Answer (score 8):

The interpretations that I use:

"Unclear what you are asking" == I have no idea what you are talking about and I don't think that's my problem.

"Lacks sufficient information" == I understand the question well enough to know that you didn't give me enough information to post an answer.

I actually use these close reasons rarely.  I absolutely hate the weasel-words they use.  I always have *some* idea what they are asking, been doing it long enough to know.  These close reasons were formulated to make me look stoopid, intentionally, to discourage me from using them.  I can of course always post a comment to ask for clarification.  I do, it rarely goes anywhere.

Oh Lord, do I miss "Not a real question" and "Not constructive", they put the burden on the person that ought to fix it instead of me.  So I hover, think no, few options left but downvote the damn thing.

Comment: Yes, a lot of the time (at least in my Android tag) I know I can offer some sort of help. So I find myself DV, voting to close, and then answering anyway. Sometimes leaving the close vote there even after I've tried to help. Not so constructive perhaps.

Comment: Same here, a problem induced by not being able to get rid of the question.  They tend to get re-activated, drawing a bad answer and moving back onto my front page.  Now what do you do?  Only thing I know to do about it is to try to post a better answer.  Sigh.