# Where have all the close votes gone?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, data-explorer

Following [my contention that review motivation is waning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255270/are-we-losing-the-battle-against-the-close-vote-queue), I wanted to get some hard data from the data exchange to see how many close votes are being cast every day. I tried [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201029/close-votes-per-day). However, the data seems to stop mid-2013.

How do I get the number of daily close votes for current dates?

Comment: Would Jon's charts help with this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258264/19679 ? They show a sharp increase in number of questions being closed recently, which correlates with what I've seen. That's not votes cast, but it is about actual rates of question closures.

Comment: @BradLarson: Thanks -- more interesting than the charts is the actual [result table](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/198593/closes-per-week#resultSets). And indeed, after a significant lull in April-May, after the March burndown, the close numbers seem to be pretty high at the moment. That's reassuring.

Comment: Beware the bias, you can't see deleted questions.  Recent data always looks good because those questions didn't get deleted yet.

Comment: @HansPassant - True, that will skew things as bad questions get deleted by the system, but I saw a similar graph a month or so ago and it did not have the same near-term spike. The shift in the close queue weightings does appear to have caused more questions to be closed faster.

Comment: About the first query in the post: The numbers from before mid-2013 don't give what you wanted either (they are much too small). Close votes that either took effect or expired are marked "deleted" and are not included in SEDE, as any other deleted stuff.

Comment: ♪"long time passing?"

Comment: @HansPassant: Very interesting, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Close votes moved out of the `Votes` table and into the `PendingFlags` table around the time you mentioned, and are now

```
SELECT * FROM PendingFlags WHERE FlagTypeId = 14
```

I believe that successful close votes are also still removed from that data, so the above query returns only non-expired close votes from non-deleted questions.

Comment: So no way to reconstruct the raw amount of close voting? Even if you combined the pending votes with the closed questions, you wouldn't necessarily know how the questions got closed. And you'd still have to add the votes from closed-and-deleted questions... hmmm...

Comment: Not with 100% accuracy I don't think, no. The close itself is recorded as a `PostHistory` entry, so you can determine the ultimate close reason (and with a little string parsing the number of voters), but that still leaves out the closed-and-deleted questions as well as votes which were cast but subsequently expired before the question was actually closed.