# Why is there a limit on close votes in a day?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This is related to [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes). The post discusses what the limits are, but it does not explain the reasoning behind the limit on close votes.

**Question**: Why is there a limit on close votes?

---

Some related observations:

- Bad incoming questions cannot be throttled.
- A bad question is a bad question, and a limit cannot change it.
- Close votes are [silently discarded on some questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255270/are-we-losing-the-battle-against-the-close-vote-queue), so some close votes are wasted.
- Its frustrating when we are not allowed to move to close a bad question.
- It might not be a good policy to hinder those [who are willing to work the queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255270/are-we-losing-the-battle-against-the-close-vote-queue).

Comment: There are rate limits on *everything* to prevent abuse, and to prevent a small group of people dominating.

Comment: And badness is in the eye of the beholder. Limit or no limit, sometimes close votes are *subjective*.

Comment: Thanks Martjin - wouldn't the abuse concerns and badness factor speak to removing the super close hammer from gold badgers? In the absence of super close hammer, its a democratic/community process.

Comment: @jww - The gold badge duplicate closing is being watched closely, and is considered an experiment. There have been cases of abuse related to that, and moderators have had to step in for certain cases. SE is watching to see if experienced users can be trusted with that kind of power, and may expand these capabilities if this experiment succeeds.

Comment: @Brad - related.... I don't think super close hammer is a good idea. Its too much power for one person (I've observed some of the questionable closes, too). Perhpas the policy should be 1 super close hammer + 1 concurring vote. That distributes the power and efficiently dispatches duplicate questions.

Comment: @Brad regarding the super close hammer, I wonder if there could be an option on whether or not you want to use it. I know that there have been sometimes that I wanted to close something as a duplicate but wasn't 100% sure of my decision and was in a quandary of what to do. I wanted the option to be able to cast a *non-hammer* close vote in those situations.

Comment: @Hovercraft - +1. If I were in that position, I would not feel comfortable using it. So I would opt out. A concurring vote is minimal/no discomfort, and helps keep the potential misuse in check.

Comment: @jww: exactly. What I've done a few times is to post a comment that sort of mimics a non-hammer close vote, as a possible suggestion to others, to see if they agree with the close as duplicate action.

Comment: I think I cast about 30 or maybe 40 _thousands_ close votes across SE network and I believe that limit makes good sense. What I really miss is [Refund close votes for questions deleted on the same day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237386/165773) - draining my limit on a garbage that requires immediate deletion just doesn't feel fair

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Shog9's comment here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer/231942#comment761352_231634 expresses an argument against allowing non-binding votes, and I've heard the same argument be made around non-binding votes for moderators. Not saying I agree with all the reasoning here, but this discussion has been had before.

Comment: @jww: recommended reading: [If trust cannot be had, then perhaps it should not be offered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239364)

Comment: I have yet to run out of close votes... not even on days when I've been working a lot with the various review queues, where you always find lots of crap. So it would seem this is a non-issue. Or perhaps the number of close votes you get increase with reputation?

Comment: @Lundin - that's interesting. I run out regularly, but I only have 40 of them. I can usually run out in under 15 or 30 minutes. I also skip a lot of questions where I have little to no domain expertise. So my work flow might look like : `SKIP <repeat 10 times>, CLOSE, SKIP <repeats 8 times>, CLOSE, SKIP <repeats 15 times>, ...`. On the upside, I rarely fail an audit (anymore) because I'm usually sure of the decision.

Comment: @jww Turns out I've got 50 close votes, so it seems you get more with rep(?). And each review queue caps at 20 reviews per day anyhow.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's a limit on close votes because we've found that any kind of action without rate limiting will eventually be abused by someone on this site. I say this from experience, because [at one time delete votes were unrestricted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes) and I'm ashamed to say that I was one of the people who got carried away and voted to delete a pile of questions during that period. What started as a cleanup effort quickly spiraled into a handful of people going around and teaming up to delete anything they disapproved of from the site.

If close votes were unlimited, you'd have groups of people teaming up to close anything they disagreed with. I see many, many terrible close votes being cast each day on high-quality and valuable questions. Certain chat rooms are notorious for their vigilante justice on questions they dislike, and it would be disastrous to hand them unlimited close votes.

We absolutely do need a limit on the number of close votes people can cast, in order to make people think about each question they are closing. Again, every single time something on this site has been unlimited (comment voting, up and downvotes, delete votes, etc.), someone has found a way to abuse it. We can argue about the size of that limit, but a limit is needed.

Comment: Good thing you had your spree (and repentance) before getting the diamond...

Comment: seen it elsewhere, moderator abuse can kill sites very rapidly. And there's a lot of it in places where there are no limits on moderators.

Comment: Good answer, although I still think raising it to 75 or 100 is the right thing to do.