# Mark as duplicate without close vote?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm trying to mark a question as a duplicate. I don't have any close votes at the moment, so I'm just trying to mark the question with the cited duplicate and submit it to the review queue.

How does one mark a duplicate and submit it for review *without* voting to close?

Comment: You can't. The only thing you can do is leave a comment and come-back later or find a chatroom that accepts cv-pls, like [The SO Close Vote Reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: Can't you flag it as a dupe?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - flagging eventually results in the same message about close vote limits. I might be wrong, but I don't think the mods want it flagged for them in this instance. (Is that what you were suggesting?).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Flagging to close, when you have the privilege to vote to close, just tries to cast a close vote; you can never flag for closure once you have the privilege.

Comment: @Servy Good to know, thanks. I went as far as bringing up the flag dialog but didn't have a suitable question to close so didn't actually pull the trigger.

Comment: @jww I'm pretty sure that flagging as a duplicate normally (i.e. for users lacking the rep to VtC) sends the question to the close votes review queue, not to the mods.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you must be on one of the high-quality tags if you can't find a question to close ;)

Comment: @rene ...as a duplicate. Don't worry, there are still plenty of questions to close in my tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does one mark a duplicate and submit it for review without voting to close?

That's not possible. Putting questions in the review queue is done by casting votes, and those are [limited for a reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271795/1048572).

When you're out of votes, you still can add a comment such as "*Exact duplicate of [XY](…)*", and other users that are coming by will pick it up and vote if they agree.

If you're personally interested in getting the question closed, come back tomorrow (you can find the question via your comments log) and cast the vote. If you think it's urgent, you can ask for help in [a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), or even flag it for mod attention - although it hardly will be *that* important.

Answer (score 4):

According [to Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271890/mark-as-duplicate-without-close-vote/271892#comment96624_271890),

> Flagging to close, when you have the privilege to vote to close, just tries to cast a close vote; you can never flag for closure once you have the privilege.

Therefore, if you have under 3k reputation, you can flag for closure, which is your only means of "voting."

If you have the close vote privilege, you can only vote to close and cannot flag to usher a post into the queue.

You could, as rene mentioned, ask for votes from certain chat rooms, like the [CV Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room or [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), but I know that you [may not like that idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239745/remove-cv-pls-tag-from-chat-rooms).

If you wanted a way to simply throw something into the queue without voting on or flagging it, you might have a nice [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) up your sleeve.

Comment: Thanks AstroCB. *"Just flag it as a duplicate"* - I tried to take the flag route also, but it eventually resulted in the "close vote limit" message. (I think the site is wise to the suggested end-around :).

Comment: So I can flag up to 100 (via consistent helpful flagging) posts a day for closure, but once I reach 3k rep, I can only vote 40 times?  And votes age away while flags don't?  It seems I get less powerful, not more.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Only closure flags count as votes. That is, duplicates and everything under "it should be closed for another reason." Close votes have more of an impact because it only takes 5 votes to close a question, whereas the flags only bring it in front of others to take that action.

Comment: @AstroCB: That makes sense, thanks.