# How someone can mark as duplicate with only one vote?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428294/how-could-you-query-a-mysql-database-to-determine-if-a-user-has-logged-in-for-30) being *marked as duplicate* by only one voter.

The voter is 18k and not over 20k (trusted user).

How is that possible provided that [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271890/mark-as-duplicate-without-close-vote) says "closing votes" are necessary?

Comment: Ironically, the actions I've taken to answer your question by marking it as a duplicate have also answered your question.  If you're still mixed up, hover over the badge for more context.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer with humor and all :-) Gold badges are the key to the Universe!

Comment: i have also same questions