# How to improve "daily vote limit reached" situation?

Tags: discussion, voting

I don't expect everyone to have the issue. Many people mostly upvote because they are free and barely downvote because they don't want to lose points. Once someone passes through the psychological barrier of "losing points", the need for votes nearly triples.

I regularly run out of votes. Most of them get used when closing off-topic when first visiting Stack Overflow in the morning. The votes are usually downvotes. Later in the day I don't have upvotes for good questions. Yesterday I passed out three IOU's for upvotes; cf., [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309904/conditionally-include-source-file-based-on-compiler-version/45311628?noredirect=1#comment77590682_45311628).

I think I've had the same number of votes for the last four or five years. While both the number of questions and the subset of off-topic questions have grown every year (seemingly exponentially), the number of votes has not been adjusted to keep up with the growth rate of questions.

Here's the broad, open ended question: Is there anything that can done to improve the situation for those who use both upvotes and downvotes?

Here are some things that seem like they could help.

1. Increase the number of votes unconditionally
2. Increase the number of votes that follows the growth rate of questions
3. Allocate votes based on a user's *Favorite Tags*
4. Split upvotes and downvotes allocations
5. If an answer is posted, don't charge an upvote for the question
6. Apply different criteria for experienced users

Item (1) is a general increase, similar to the way a legislature passes a "minimum wage increase" every decade or so.

Item (2) is an increase based on site statistics, similar to the way a "cost of living adjustment" is applied every year.

Item (3) is an allotment based on a user's tags. Users who follow more popular tags often need more than someone following less popular or no tags. For example, I follow *Linux*, *C* or *C++* and most of my allotment is used for them. I also follow *Crypto++*, and I can't remember the last time I used a downvote because nearly all questions are programming related.

Item (4) is a separation of duties. Upvoting good questions and moving against bad questions are two separate actions and serve different purposes, so they should not share a pool. For example, a first visit to Stack Overflow is often a "clean the cruft" pass where bad questions are moved against.

There is actually more to Item (4) because the site lumps all "post votes" together into a pool. The site does not recognize or separate duties. This item's suggestion matches mental models where users see them as separate duties and separate actions.

Item (5) follows from the fact that questions which are worthy of an answer meet the criteria for an upvote (shows research, useful and clear). The contrapositive also tells us we should not answer if the questions is not upvote worthy.

Item (6) is due to "one size does not fit all". Experienced users can be more effective at identifying issues in some questions and leading by example when moving against them. If fraud is a concern, then experienced user can be moved back to the inexperienced user category for vote allotment much like privileges are suspended.

When considering an allotment of votes, please consider we need votes for answers, too. Sometimes answers have to be addressed at three to five times the rate of questions.

Its probably worth mentioning we can't budget votes because we don't control the supply of questions flowing through the site.

For those interested, here is the Meta discussion that provides the formula for the number of post votes (that seems to be inadequate): [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/173448)

---

Here are the numbers I've been able to find or the breadth of the issue. The numbers are from July 2017.

- 7451692 total Stack Overflow users
- 26136 experienced Stack Overflow users (reputation 5K or more)
- 24877 users with with [Vox Populi badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) (vote limit reached)

<strike>If I am parsing the query results correctly, then nearly every experienced user has encountered the issue. What I am not sure about is, the intersection of experienced users and Vox Populi awards. They are probably disjoint sets, so the correlation is probably not that strong.  I suspect only percentage of experienced users have the badge, and not *"nearly every experienced user"*.</strike>

According to Bluefeet below in the comments, only about 20% of experienced uses have hit the voting limit. Bluefeet ran the query.

---

Here are some related topics on the subject:

- [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/173448)
- [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)
- [Why is there a limit on close votes in a day?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271795/608639) (related)

Comment: While the number of posts received every day has increased, so has the number of users viewing posts (not as much probably, but it has increased) The daily vote limit is a pain at times, but very few users actullay hit the vote limits at all, let alone every day. I agree that there probably should be a change, but doubt that a change is likely due to the low effect it would have in relation to the amount of work necessary to come up with a viable chanhe and implement it.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I hope I don't sound argumentative... *"While the number of posts received every day has increased, so has the number of users viewing posts"* sounds a lot like "more eyes are better" in free and open software. That's been shown to be a myth (for example Heartbleed). Both Stack Overflow and Free Software need the experienced, trained eye. Mass of users is not enough.

Comment: Maybe SO has social responsibility to get programmers away from keyboards for some time and vote limit/review limit is the way to solve it :) More realistically I don't think amount of effort one can put into moderating SO somehow magically scales with number of questions posted - so while some increase in vote counts may be useful it is unlikely to have much impact.

Comment: I really like option 4. I'm reluctant to upvote currently because it takes away a possible downvote and i feel downvotes are more useful.

Comment: @KevinB - Yeah, I favor a combination of (3) and (4). Recognize separate duties, and then allocate a base amount for each category upvote, downvote, close vote, etc. Then, provide additional votes based on *Favorite Tags* as needed. I suspect it could also simplify the algorithm used by the site.

Comment: though... if it was implemented by simply splitting the number at 20/20, that'd.. not be cool.

Comment: I was specifically referring to the increase in experienced users as qualified by the parenthetical statement in my previous comment. What we notice when we look at the trends is that as the question rate increases, so do closures and downvotes, which shows that the number of experienced users viewing questions does grow with the question rate, though probably not as much as would be ideal.

Comment: Not to mention, how many people received said badge, and then never hit the limit again? (badge hunters for example.) I know there was a particular date where i did purposely cast a number of votes to gain that badge, a long time ago :p

Comment: @jww I ran a quick query and of the 26k users with more than 5k rep, only about 5k of them have the Vox Populi badge so your assumption that most experienced user (> 5k rep) have hit the voting limit is incorrect. Only about 20% have hit the voting limit.

Comment: @bluefeet And how many of them only did that to get the badge? I know I did!

Comment: @DavidG - *"how many of them only did that to get the badge?"* - Ideally all the players would be trustworthy, but there's always going to be some fraud and gaming going on. I don't know a way to estimate the numbers for dishonest members. Maybe there's a way to estimate the cheats in game theory. I never took the classes in college, so I can't offer something more.

Comment: @jww I did a bit more poking at the database and over the past year, we average only about 40 users a day who hit the voting cap...so, it's not that many people who are in fact using all their votes.  While I'm not saying no to the possibility of changing anything, not many people are impacted by it.

Comment: @Taryn Super late to the party (from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374152/regain-daily-number-of-close-votes-from-approved-question-closures?cb=1#comment630987_374152) but I do wonder how many people are simply aware of the vote limit and don't bother brushing up against it. They may end up using a larger amount if they know their daily pool is a larger amount. For example, I try to always keep a few CVs in reserve when I do the review queue, especially since I am a SOCVR member. If I had more CVs, or if the CVQ votes didn't count toward my daily limit, I would use more CVs for sure

Comment: @Taryn Just an example of how someone could never show up on that radar of 'voting cap daily hitters' but still be affected every day by it.