# Relax Review Limit for Reviews by Badge Holders?

Tags: feature-request

Should the limit of reviews be relaxed if a user has the highest available badge in the given review queue?

Specifically, the `Close Review` queue remains in thousands. Is there any reason to curtail the obsessiveness of reviewers who've already done more than a thousand reviews? There is little they could be gaming at that point. Complete removal doesn't seem good (fatigue and increase in failure rate being a probable thing), but doubling (or more?) the limit seems like you'd get high-quality work out of people who want to do it anyway.

Comment: Would this have to include an increase in the number of daily close votes or other votes for these people?

Comment: @Brad is there any way to limit that increase to the confines of the respective queue?

Comment: I'm specifically thinking of the limits on the review queues. Close votes are limited to 40, I think most others are limited to 20. The only queue that isn't consistently below 100 items is the Close Vote queue, though.

Comment: I think they should be "Bonus" close votes that only can be used in the queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver then isn't there risk of gaming the system? "I start by using all my normal closevotes, then I jump in the queue to get a much higher closevotes count"? Or do we simply give the EXTRA closevotes as bonus?

Comment: Here are a few meta posts I was able to dig up concerning the number of items in the CV queue (in chronological order): [Fuzzy the number of questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut), [Age out items in the queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions?rq=1) (<Mod post), [Are We losing the battle?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255270/are-we-losing-the-battle-against-the-close-vote-queue)

Comment: @NathanielFord the queues are limited to 20 unless there is over 1000 reviews in the queue then it increases to 40.

Comment: @Patrice I don't see a problem with it.  What should happen is that the "Bonus" votes get used up first when in the queue.  Then if they run out of "Bonus" but haven't hit the close limit then they can use there regular votes.  This was they can't get more than 40 reviews but they can spend their close votes on post the find naturally as well.  IDK about you but every time I review 40 CV's I'm pretty close to running out of close votes and that doesn't count what I see during the day.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh definitely, I don't end a lot of days with a lot of remaining CVs, and it's even worse when I have a chance to go through reviews. I guess it can help "turn the tide" so to speak so it might not be as big an issue as I originally thought.

Comment: Make sure you use/find arguments to convince [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes#comment152909_285486) ....

Comment: MSE Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254274/give-extra-close-votes-only-accessible-via-review/254325#254325