# Is it correct that close votes give nothing (not even badge progress) while flags do?

Tags: discussion

I was making my way toward the Marshal badge, when suddenly I got permission to do close votes.

The badge-hunter in me wants to flag posts even after I've close-voted them (but I don't actually do this).

The good-member in me just does close votes, and only occasionally uses "flag" when necessary.

My concern is that the badges are supposed to motivate good behavior, and in this case, it's not.

But I certainly don't think adding a badge for close votes makes any sense.

Comment: if you (wisely) use CVs in [close review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue), this will bring you a Steward badge. To continue hunt for Marshal, just regularly check [LQ queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) - it has plenty of flaggable posts, one can easily make 50-100 flags a day from it (just pick the posts to open outside of the queue and use skip to avoid bumping into review limit)

Comment: The warm feeling you get from closing questions and helping to clean up the site isn't enough for you? I'd take that any day over badges.

Comment: If it weren't, I would have stopped doing close votes long ago. But as I say, there's still the badge-hunter part in me. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are other flags you can raise other than close ones, so I wouldn't worry about your progress towards the flag badges stalling.

Just concentrate of using the tools you have appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Flags for closure for users who already have the privilege to vote to close are automatically converted to votes to close, not just flags.  All you're doing by using the "flag" menu is adding an extra click for yourself, the behavior isn't actually harmful to the site.

Comment: But I meant that I would flag it for something other than close, so that I could get the flag AND the close vote.

Comment: @Almo If there are problems with the post other than that it should be closed that are worth flagging, then there's no problem.  If the post doesn't meet the criteria for whatever other flag you're using, then the flag will be declined.  I'm still not seeing a problem here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. I think I have 4 declined and 4 disputed flags on 238, so I don't think I've abused it. :)