# Close and reopen votes are vanishing

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

For a while I've been suspicious and frustrated with the close & reopen queues. They don't seem to work properly for me -- sometimes I check back and the close or reopen votes are gone. I wondered if I was going mad, but now I've caught the vote loss happening. I definitely marked these three questions as duplicates a week ago. I trawled the close review history to find their review pages and I've been watching them ever since:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5599523
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5599527
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5599616

The close queue is so overloaded that they have only been reviewed once, but anyway, suddenly they all mysteriously say "This item is no longer reviewable". At the same time, the close votes (of which I know the questions had 2 each) completely disappeared from 2 of the 3. [This is what they look like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsAjP.png); unfortunately I didn't screenshot before the disappearance but the review pages are proof that they did get close votes. Help?

Comment: Well, this answers half of the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks for the link. But that system is outrageously imbecilic. The review queue showed those three questions to anyone only one time total. I marked other questions too and although I've been trawling the review history every day, for most of them I haven't seen them be reviewed at all, and now I see that for most of them their votes are gone too. How are old questions ever supposed to get dupe close votes if the votes get deleted and the review queue doesn't display them, and if it does display them they become "unreviewable" soon after? Am I not supposed to mark old dupes at all?

Comment: This is a better explanation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions?rq=1

Comment: The whole point remain the same: if every user that has the close vote privilege would handle 40 reviews on a regular basis the CVQ would be empty. One possible solution is to get some focussed attention around certain tags from more members that just you. I'm happy to facilitate that in the [SO Close Vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). A small group of users manage to clear the queue for certain tags.

Comment: @rene I've a lot of respect for those who can bear to do close vote review. It's so depressing and takes hours to do 40 of them. But I really don't understand the goal of that system you linked. So they tried to solve the problem of having so many questions to review... by just not bothering to review the questions?? And to add insult, they delete the votes so they can pretend the original close-voter never existed. But they still let people place that vote in the first place, so there's a placebo button to keep people busy with! What a trainwreck.

Comment: Before the current system the CVQ was [118K](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) which led to even more users moving away from the CVQ. As I said in my earlier comment, we need more people regularly using their votes and this trainwreck woud not exist. I'm in the [not on strike team](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208682/close-votes-review-im-not-going-on-a-strike) for the reason that [giving up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike) doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As I said, if we organize the effort CV-ing will be more effective and worth the effort. The addition of CV counts on the TAG info page, the instant filters on the review page are all steps to make CV-ing more do-able. Please don't give-up yet...

Comment: While I partly understand the motivation for aging out votes, I really wonder if there would be significant negative effects from just getting rid of the concept. It clearly doesn't work in this case. And if I vote to close a question, I will still feel the same way a month later, so I don't see a convincing reason why my vote should become invalid 4 days later.

Comment: It seems that reopen votes get removed too. I voted to reopen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implement-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference) some days ago and now there is no vote there, but if I try to vote again it says I already did. Absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: It is already very hard to get closed questions reopened. People who vote to close generally don't come back if the question is improved, and no-one new comes to the questions with "[closed]" in the title, so closed questions have vastly less visibility yet for some reason still require the same number of votes (5) to reopen as to close. I once spent *hours* waiting around for a question to be ropened so I could answer it: it didn't seem to turn up in the review queue, no mod handled the flag I put, and in the end I had to beg in the chat repeatedly to get people to reopen it.

Comment: So the reopen system already work badly when wanted urgently, and if the votes are being "expired", it's also worthless when wanted non-urgently.

Comment: @Boann Why do you want to reopen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implement-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference)? Is the duplicate wrong?

Comment: @rene No, they are really duplicates, but the other question is less comprehensive, and as the two commenters are complaining, that one has been closed as "not constructive"! I don't believe the question is non-constructive, so I think at least one of the two should be opened. The view count on the one closed as a duplicate is 150 thousand -- it's a major question, but its only answers are those lucky enough to have squeezed in during the 45-minute window 2 years ago before the question was unceremoniously closed. I put a flag on it so I'm sure it will be sorted out eventually.

Comment: Ah, OK, maybe merging is an option...

Comment: I am feeling that why should I bother voting to close or open anymore now? We don't want the votes, and we don't want the queue to grow because a smaller CV queue makes us feel better than one that contains valid CVs. I do truly find a lot of meta posts very confusing.

Comment: In my opinion the CV system is broken. The change awhile ago that makes the CVQ looks smaller than it really is is just palliative. All in all this situation has been like this for years. It is obvious that this part of the system is not working. Unfortunately, it seems that nobody knows what would work instead. I certainly don't.

Comment: And hoping that more people will start doing this is, in my opinion, naive - it is not happening, and there is no indication that it's ever going to happen - if the system does not change.