# I'm having communications problems with flags

Tags: support, flags

I'm having trouble with custom mod flags. I feel that the flags I put are often mishandled. I'm going to show examples, and I would like advice on if I was in the wrong on any of them.

Note: I'm cherry picking examples. In other cases I've used identical flags to these which *were* handled correctly.

---

1. I came across this question: [Adding a header to any webpage I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757857/adding-a-header-to-any-webpage-i-want), which was closed as "unclear". Not a fabulous question, but its comments and answers show that people understood what was being asked, so the closure as "unclear" wasn't warranted.

   I put a flag on it:

   > Closed as unclear, but it isn't.

   I got this mysterious response:

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

   Surely the fact the question received helpful responses is evidence enough?

---

2. I found this question: [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types). There was [an old comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGtgL.png) on the question talking about C#. (It turns out that the asker had originally asked the question about both Java and C# before realizing they were different in this aspect.) Anyway, the comment was now just confusing clutter, so I flagged it:

   > wrong language (C# vs Java)

   But the response was:

   > declined

   I pondered the response but couldn't figure out what else to do. Eight months later I decided to try again with an *identical flag*, and the response was: "helpful", and the comment was deleted. So it's resolved now. It's so trivial I wouldn't even bring it up, except that flagging things twice to get them fixed became a pattern...

---

3. I came across this highly viewed Java question: [Implements vs. Extends. When to use? What's the Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference). It was closed as a duplicate of [What's the difference between the implements & extends keywords in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494380/whats-the-difference-between-the-implements-extends-keywords-in-java).

   The new question technically was a duplicate. But the original question had poorer answers, and couldn't get any better answers because it had been inexplicably closed as "not constructive". The new question had become the far more major question in terms of viewcount and votes. I realized it should not be marked as a duplicate of the poorer question (and nor should that one be closed as "non-constructive"). As it was, the questions presented an untidy and confusing picture to the thousands of visitors finding them through web searches.

   I put reopen votes on both questions, but the system automatically deletes such votes after a short time. If a question cannot generate reopen votes organically at a fast enough rate to counteract the onslaught of the periodic vote deletion, casting reopen votes does nothing. The votes were indeed deleted. The system blocks the same person from casting new votes in this case, so I had to put a flag on it:

   > the question this is closed as a duplicate of is less comprehensive; this one should not be closed

   The flag sat there unhandled for a month, while the question sat there looking untidy. I didn't see why it should take so long, so in frustration, I flagged both [the two comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJYxr.png) on the question that were complaining about the mess, with:

   > Listen!

   Suddenly, all three flags were marked helpful. The better question was reopened, and the poorer question was marked as a duplicate of the better one. Persistence pays off, apparently!

---

4. I found this question: [Best way to copy from one array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537589/best-way-to-copy-from-one-array-to-another). It was closed as: "not a real question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

   The closure was demonstrably wrong because the question *had* received correct, useful answers. So I flagged it:

   > This question is in fact not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, *or* rhetorical, and it was in fact reasonably answered in its current form.

   This flag sat open for over a month, until...

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

   *What?!* The evidence is *on that page*.

   I put a flag on an old comment there that was complaining about the closure:

   > Listen!

   Response:

   > helpful

   And everything was immediately fixed. Once again, I couldn't figure out what was wrong with the original flag, but found that repeated flags are effective.

---

5. I came across this question: [Parse binary string as byte in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430694/parse-binary-string-as-byte-in-javascript). It was originally less clearly written, and someone wielding a gold tag badge dupehammer had marked it as a duplicate of an unrelated question.

   I put a reopen vote on it but that didn't work because the votes are just deleted by the system. I sighed and put a mod flag on it:

   > not a dupe

   Some weeks later the flag was marked as:

   > helpful

   but *without* the post being reopened. I was annoyed but assumed it was an innocent mistake. I put a second flag on it:

   > not a dupe; already flagged but flag marked helpful without the post being reopened

   which was bizarrely marked as:

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

   *Just where were you looking for evidence?!*

   I decided to try a different approach. Since the question was closed with the dupehammer, it could be reopened with the dupehammer. I tried to ping the closer about it in the question's comments: "@<Name> Not a dupe.", hoping he would correct it. This turned out to be even less effective than flagging for mod help, and I won't try to appeal to anyone in this way again. Although he was active on Stack Overflow he ignored the question. I wasn't sure if he would receive notification of this ping, so I tried pinging him in the comments of one of his *own* posts, but apparently this just annoyed him, because every time I did so, my comment was deleted soon after he was next online, so I guessed he was flagging them. (I did this 4 times in total. Mods seemed perfectly happy to handle *those* flags, but somehow without bothering to listen to what the comments said.) So that person refused to reopen the question, but did find time to throw a downvote and delete vote at it. As I said, I won't ever try that again.

   Suddenly, minitech ♦ appeared out of the blue and reopened it. I was very grateful, although I never figured out how/why he was there.

   Anyway, I truly don't understand why my original "not a dupe" flags were mishandled in this case. As a counterexample, the question [App not getting uninstalled through ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907339/app-not-getting-uninstalled-through-adb) was also marked as a duplicate incorrectly, also using the dupehammer, and when I put a mod flag with identical wording: "not a dupe", it was quickly handled, with the question reopened.

---

6. I found this interesting C++ question: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). I realized I could not vote it up, because for the past 3½ years it had been locked. The big banner saying it was locked did not say *why*. The comments and revision history suggested there was some dispute about the question in the past, but there was no reason for it to be locked now.

   I put a flag:

   > No reason for this to be locked. (?)

   The response was:

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

   As usual, the response was inexplicable and unhelpful. If it was supposed to be locked, some explanation would have been helpful. If the mod didn't know what I was talking about, some word to that effect would have been helpful. As it was I saw nothing to do but put a second flag:

   > I want to upvote this question but it won't let me!

   The response was:

   > helpful

   And it was fixed. Somehow it always seems to take multiple flags to get anything done.

---

7. I found two old comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389285/real-time-graphing-in-java):

   [image]
   which were talking about a typo that was fixed over five years ago:

   [image]
   I put an obsolete comment flag on the initial comment.

   > declined

   Of course. So I put exactly the same flag again.

   > helpful

   But although the first comment was deleted, the second one was not. Typical. It took a third 'obsolete' flag to get that removed. That does not make sense. In verifying that the first comment was obsolete, **it would have become obvious that both were obsolete**. To delete only one of the comments makes it seem like either the mod just robo-reviewed it, or whatever UI the mods have for handling comment flags is bad and doesn't provide them with the necessary context.

---

8. I come across this question: [PHP function is_nan() throws a warning for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377922/php-function-is-nan-throws-a-warning-for-strings). It was marked as a duplicate of another question two years earlier by a mod. It's not a duplicate though; [the "duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole) is about an error message containing a few of the same words; but the problem is unrelated.

   I put the reopen vote on it out of obligation, though I knew the vote would just be deleted (which it was), so I also put a mod flag on it:

   > Not a dupe.

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

   No of course they didn't find evidence the first time, they never do. The system temporarily flag-banned me due to this yet-another declined flag, so I had to wait a few days to be able to put the customary second flag on it:

   > Not a dupe!

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

   Trying to decipher the meaning of "no evidence", I became worried about the use of the word "dupe" as abbreviation for "duplicate". It seemed like the natural word to me, but perhaps it was actually completely obscure? Perhaps I made it up? I checked online dictionaries which suggested it should be understood. The word is also used on Stack Exchange [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dupe) and [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=dupe) without causing confusion.

   Nonetheless, I decided to err on the safe side and not abbreviate the word for the third flag:

   > Not. A. Duplicate.

   My understanding is that mods see the past flags on a post when handling flags, so surely, I think, they'll realize I'm bleating about *something*, as opposed to just bleating because I like the noise.

   > declined - If you keep casting completely useless flags like this, we'll only keep declining them.

   At this point I'm utterly mystified. I decided to be really explicit with the fourth flag, so there couldn't be any confusion:

   > This question is not a duplicate yet is erroneously marked as one. It needs to be reopened. I'm ♦ flagging it because there is no other [working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270282), reliable way to get such questions reopened.

   4 days pass...

   > helpful

   Ah, finally! Thank you so much! Then I check the question. It *wasn't reopened*. Did a mod mark it helpful without knowing what I was talking about, just to shut me up?! *Really?!*

   Perhaps it was just an innocent mistake, so I put another flag:

   > My flag was marked 'helpful' but was not handled...

   > declined - Three earlier flags were declined. Please stop flagging this post.

   I really don't understand why I'm getting these responses. **How does it take [five flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04JKL.png) to fail to get something simple fixed?** The question isn't a duplicate. The reopen review queue failed that question as it fails most questions. Mod flagging is the next step to get it fixed. But it's not working, and **most maddening to me is that the flag responses do not explain *why***.

   I've left that question alone for now.

---

Sorry this is so long. I'm not demanding a complete answer to all of it, but would appreciate any help at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, looking at the first example you didn't even bother to vote to reopen it. If you're not going to put some effort in, why should we?

Comment: Seems like a mod flag for reopening is a bit overkill, especially considering we have a reopen queue.

Comment: Honestly, on that last one I'd just let it go. After _the second flag_, usually.

Comment: @ChrisF [**Yes, I did vote to reopen it**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11A2j.png). The system [deletes such votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270282/close-and-reopen-votes-are-vanishing), so they don't work unless they arrive at a fast enough rate to overcome the automatic deletion.

Comment: tl;dr. The gist of the first 10 examples is: 1) Include more information in your flags if you want an action taken, so the mod knows why. 2) Learn where it's appropriate to use flags - duplicates and close votes are not among them, as those can be handled by users and don't require a mod. 3) Learn some patience - your flags are not the most high priority issue that mods deal with, and finally 4) stop posting (IMO) moronic duplicate flags like *Listen!*, because mods are going to get ticked off at such juvenile behavior and are going to start ignoring your flags together.

Comment: @KenWhite @1 I really thought I was giving enough information, but since many people don't think so, I'll try to be more clear in future (although that didn't work in example 8, flag 3). @2 These matters can't always be handled by users if the system keeps deleting the votes and the review queues don't work. Hence the need for mod intervention. @3 OK. @4 OK. The *Listen!* flags are proven effective, but I'll keep them as a last resort in future.

Comment: @Boann - OK. I take that comment back. However, it's still not the job of moderators to reopen stuff on behalf of other users. The thing to do is edit and encourage others through comments, chat and meta to vote with you.

Comment: @ChrisF "it's still not the job of moderators to reopen stuff on behalf of other users" What about example 8? It was ***closed by a mod***.

Comment: @Boann - if we come across a question that clearly needs action then we can take that action unilaterally. As others have pointed out closing or reopening duplicates often requires subject knowledge a moderator doesn't have. Often the flag will be left, but occasionally it will get declined or even marked as helpful but without the question state changing because while it was raised in good faith the moderator can see no reason to reopen or close the question.

Comment: @ChrisF "if we come across a question that clearly needs action then we can take that action unilaterally." Then you are able to reopen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377922/php-function-is-nan-throws-a-warning-for-strings).

Comment: @Boann - no, because I don't have the domain knowledge to be able to decide that. If it really isn't a duplicate then **edit it** to bring that out. This will put the question in the reopen review queue where people *with* the domain knowledge can check and vote accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisF I shouldn't have to muck around with the question just to compensate for the fact that a mod who ***doesn't have the domain knowledge*, having significantly less points in the php tag than *you do***, attacked the question in a drive-by duplicate tagging two years ago. But I will try it.

Comment: Do not edit out the duplicate link on questions closed as duplicates. That will be removed when the question is reopened. Editing it out is just removing the information that people need in order to decide if it was improperly closed or not.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Sorry about that. I'm glad you're here though. You have some experience in PHP. Will you reopen it, please?

Comment: I can see that it's not an exact duplicate, but I'm going to leave it up to the community for two reasons. 1. It's already in the reopen queue. 2. If you look on the sidebar of the linked questions, you'll note that a *ton* of "some_function() expects parameter 1 to be x, y given" questions are closed as duplicates. It might be better to find (or create) a better canonical example, but for now that's the one the community chose.

Comment: [I do feel you can never reopen a question by vote once it gets closed.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283699/is-there-a-way-to-improve-reopen-procedure)

Answer (score 25):

I'll try to go through as many of these as I can, but that's an awful lot of stuff in one post:

1. Did you vote to reopen this? You're asking us to unilaterally override five votes by members of the community. If it isn't immediately obvious to a moderator why we should do this, we tend to defer to the community.
2. I declined that flag in November of 2013. The comment was "Well in .NET they do work with primitive types (and value types) as well.", which to me seemed to be relevant because it was providing context for how C# did things. I saw no immediate need to delete that comment, but it was re-flagged and another moderator decided otherwise (probably because it isn't worth the effort to keep arguing with someone about a single comment flag).
3. Dealing with duplicates is a real pain for us, since we have to make a technical judgment and spend a while analyzing both questions. Therefore, we tend to put those off. It just happened that we were burning down flags in the queue at the same time you flagged those comments, so it was taken care of then.
4. That was a borderline question at the time you flagged it. One moderator disagreed that it needed to be reopened (see my comments above about overriding the community). Another decided the other way later on.
5. See my comments above about why dealing with duplicates is difficult for us. It's usually not self-evident why something needs to be reopened, and it can take subject matter experts to see why or why not.
6. The history on that question is a mess, so I think it was locked due to a merge or something. I don't know.
7. Sometimes it can be hard to judge if something marked "obsolete" actually was handled. The first moderator might have missed what made that comment obsolete, and since our only actions are to decline or delete, decided not to delete.
8. I can tell you that you really annoyed several moderators with these flags. Repeatedly flagging something without providing any more information in the subsequent flags is a surefire way to get us to keep declining them. Please don't do that again.

Despite the fact that some of your "Listen!" or repeated flags caused us to eventually take the action that you wanted, don't rely on that. You're more likely to annoy us to the point where we won't even look at subsequent flags of yours. If a flag was declined, but you still feel action is warranted, please make sure to provide a lot more information as to why we should take a particular action. If we still disagree, I suggest moving on.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. It's helpful. Although, @2, I'm not sure that's the same comment I flagged. @8 Can you tell that it really annoys me how those flags were handled? Repeatedly *declining* flags without providing any more information in the subsequent responses is a surefire way to get me to keep flagging them. If it still isn't handled but I'm still absolutely sure that the flag is appropriate, because no-one will give me any reason to think otherwise, I can only keep flagging it.

Comment: @Boann This site is designed to prevent anyone (other than moderators) from unilaterally doing things. If what you want conflicts with others, then it probably isn't going to happen. So if it doesn't happen the way you want it, just let it go. Also, there is a mechanism to prevent flag abusers from annoying moderators. With enough declined flags, you'll be hell-banned and all your flags will stop showing up in the moderator queue and get ignored.

Comment: @Mysticial [Hell-bans for flags are no more.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)

Comment: @ChrisHayes Oh, clearly that was so long ago that I forgot about it. :)

Comment: @Boann Flagging as not a dupe and having it declined is plenty of information. It says "I still believe this is a duplicate, and you have not convinced me otherwise". At this point, if you really wanted to flag again (which I don't think is the appropriate way to go anyway), *you need to give more information*. How is giving the exact same flag repeatedly and getting Louder! each time supposed to help? Regardless, this is a community problem and should be raised on meta to resolve, not through moderator action.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Given the rate of apparent mistakes I've had in flag handling, a random decline is not information at all. I accept what everyone is telling me here that I *need* to give more information, and I will do so in future, although I still don't see why I *should* have to, when the non-dupes are so patently obvious. And to your last point, are you suggesting people should make a meta thread about it whenever a question is inappropriately closed?

Comment: @Boann "Patently obvious" is only the case if you're active in that tag. Moderators generally try very hard to stay away from tasks that require domain knowledge - that's what we have a community of experts for. I wouldn't be surprised if some flags requiring domain knowledge are dismissed without looking at them. And yes, if you find a question that you really believe should be reopened and has value, bring it up on meta. Absolutely yes.

Answer (score 22):

Here are some key points to think about when *flagging for reopening*:

1. **Put some effort into proving why it should be reopened.** This can (and should) actually be done in two ways. Most importantly, be more detailed in your flag reasons. Just giving us a basic blurb of text that says "this is not a duplicate" or "this needs reopened" is not useful to us at all. If you're going to bring in a moderator of all people, at least give us a basic argument that supports your case.

   Secondly, try to help us out by improving the question. If it was closed as unclear, try identifying what's so unclear to other users and improving the question yourself. For duplicates, explain *why* it's not a duplicate, either in the comments or by editing the question to pinpoint a more exact problem.
2. **You're asking us to override other users.** As many moderators have stated before: when you flag for something to be reopened, our name gets put on it, yours doesn't. By the time we get to a point where you're *flagging* to have something reopened, it *should have* already gone through the Reopen Votes queue either due to an edit or an existing reopen vote. So you're not just asking us to override the up to five users who initially voted to close the question, but also the three that opted to leave it closed. We tend to only do that when it's a very clear-cut case, which you haven't exactly proven in any of your situations.
3. **Use other tools at your disposal.** I don't mean just casting a vote to reopen. There are other avenues you can take. There are chat rooms that you can join into and ask other users if they think a question is worthy of being reopened. You can also hop onto Meta and ask for help from the community at large. Maybe they could explain to you what's so unclear about a question you're not finding so unclear.
4. **Every moderator does things differently.** We're not robots that always operate under the same set of instructions for handling flags. We all have different workflows for how we like to handle flags and empty the queue, and sometimes that leads to confusing outcomes or mistakes happening on certain flags. This is especially true for comment flags.

Comment: @1 Anything I could say to point out how a question is not a duplicate seems superfluous to the questions themselves, which when compared, are not duplicates. @2 I really think that the particular questions I'm talking about, especially the ones that I flagged repeatedly, are clear-cut. @3 I have tried, in the past, begging in a chat room to get a question reopened. It did work! But it took a while, it was embarrassing and annoyed the users there. @4 These "mistakes" are happening very often.

Answer (score 8):

1. Having an answer doesn't mean it is a good question. A question needs to be able to stand on its own. Having answers doesn't make a question clearer. It just means that someone was good at guessing what was asked.
2. Why did you flag this requiring moderator attention? You can flag comments as either "Obsolete" or "Not constructive." Both seem relevant after an edit has eliminated the need for the comment.
3. If you need a question reopened, flag it for reopening. If you are failing to get votes to reopen the question, consider editing the question to make it clear that the question should be reopened or adding a comment explaining why you voted to reopen. Repeatedly flagging a moderator for something that you can help in handling will go poorly...
4. See the answer to #1.
5. Why is it not a duplicate? This seems to fall under the same answer as #3, with the additional note that five flags for the same post is excessive.

Comment: @1 In this particular case, it's not such a bad question, answers or not. @2 I used that flag to give more information about *why* the comment is obsolete. @3 In three of the examples I gave of questions needing reopening, people had already left comments asking for it to be reopened. It didn't do anything except add clutter and give me an extra target to flag. @5 It's **NOT** a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Without going into specifics into each and every point (others have covered that as well as I could), you have 1 very significant problem/misconception.

You do not feel like you need to explain **why**.

First, moderators expect **you** to do your homework.  Do your research.  If something was closed incorrectly, then you should research the issue an explain it to demonstrate that you understand why the question otherwise fits the scope.  This isn't pointless busywork or because the moderators are lazy, but with more than 8 million questions, and 100's of thousands of users with 200+ rep, moderators have enough to deal with.  Could you image what would happen if even half of those users decided each to flag 8 post multiple times?  Nothing would ever be done on the site, as moderators would be too busy to deal with real issues affecting the site.

Second, moderators are not subject matter experts.  You might be able to see why a question is valid or not a duplicate, but the moderator probably doesn't.  Since you know the material and you are a subject expert, you should explain why, in your expert opinion, then question deserves to be reopened.

If you stop assuming people will always agree without you and explain why you feel the way you do, then you will find flagging to be a lot simplier and more productive.

Answer (score 4):

1. Closing and re-opening are things the community can do (you have a vote there too).
   It might be neccessary to clarify the post a bit first, but that was the aim anyway.

   Thus, it's to be expected that calling a moderator in on that won't get you far.
2. The proper flag would have been "obsolete", though the custom flag should have worked the first time. At least I would have expected it to.
3. Just a month?
4. Just a month again?

   By the way, answers are not a guarantee that a question should be re-opened.
   At most, they are a very unreliable indicator.

Well, there are lots more, but your post is a bit too long.

Comment: A few times other I have used flags to reopen questions I've seen that were closed inappropriately, and it has worked perfectly, so I've been led to think it's okay. I do not see what else anyone can possibly do, since the reopen review queue never works -- it doesn't seem to show the posts to anyone.

Comment: Well, that's a queue I often visit. There are often a few posts deserving a re-open vote, many I cannot judge appropriately in acceptable time (skip), and unfortunately also many which I would vote to close any time. So, empirically, it shows at least some posts to some people... Maybe the criteria for removing a post un-opened should be harder to meet, though I don't have the data to even guess.