# Is there a way to improve reopen procedure?

Tags: discussion

At the moment, it looks to me like a badly written new question (especially if there is no answer) that attracts enough attention in the first few minutes (while it is still on the top page?) can get closed quite quickly (which is good).

After that period, a question can be very difficult to get closed as it's exposed to much fewer users, and the Close Votes queue is always jammed. [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802943/master-detail-relationship-between-datagrid-column-and-treeview); [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280994/p2p-app-chat-with-wcf)

But what I really can't understand is, it appears that it can be very very difficult for a closed question (no matter how much it gets improved) to be reopened again, it just takes forever to accumulate 5 reopen votes, although I think there are only a few in the reopen queue?

[My own example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814501/misplaced-datagrid-error-indicator). You can search *reopen* in meta see how many questions only get reopened via using meta effect.

Comment: So are you trying to get your own question reopened by shortcutting the reopen process, or is this a more general discussion about reopening questions in general? If it's about your question, you should reword your question to make that clear. If it isn't, linking to your question isn't really conducive to the broader issue.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, I don't know, I badly want to make my question reopened, obviously, but in the same time, I do feel there is a problem in general for the reopen process. I didn't include my question initially, but then I think, why not, why should I hide it? People will ask for example/evidence anyway so I add it in.

Answer (score 4):

A question is enqueued into the reopen review queue only *for the first edit after closure*.

Posts in the queue are usually handled within minutes, so if the question remains closed, most likely more reviewers voted to "keep closed" than to reopen. Afterwards, the post is removed from the queue. Anyone who voted to reopen during the review is counted as a reopen vote, visible below the post. Those votes remain even if the majority voted to keep closed.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to see how a review went, see [Finding the review results for a specific question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224229/finding-the-review-results-for-a-specific-question)

Any subsequent reopen votes after the post has left review will again requeue the post into the review queue. However this requires that someone happens to find the post, so this can take a long time if the post is no longer visible on the frontpage.

Subsequent edits will not cause the post to re-enter review. However edits will cause the post to reappear on the frontpage, so increase the chance that someone will vote for the post.

The other option to get new reopen votes is to post a link to the question in a chat room or here on meta and argue the case for the post. It is perfectly acceptable to open a new meta question for an individual closed question, and even if this does not lead to a reopening, it should result in some feedback about the post.

For the particular linked question, I am not sure if I would vote to reopen. It is not quite apparent to me at first glance what the question actually is. You describe a problem, but there does not appear to be a question about this problem, so right now the trivial answer appears to be "yup, that is how DataGrid behaves, you can open a bug report about it".

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, so you think my question is still in the queue, just didn't get enough votes?  PS: for me the reopen trigger is *Will you close such a question in the first place?*

Comment: I very much doubt it is still in the queue from the first edit. I do think this is something that should be improved, it is almost impossible to learn that a reopen review has failed.

Comment: ..... if this is true, then it can well explain why it is almost impossible to get 5 reopen votes, as other users need to click into the question first?? :(