# The Low Quality Posts review queue is growing... let's burn it down!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

A little over a year ago, we held the [memorable community burnination of the close-votes queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251489/465378). **This has little to do with that.** The close votes queue is so massive that it's practically a beast of its own. This is not a problem anywhere near the same scale.

That said, the Low Quality Posts queue has been growing steadily over the past few weeks. Fortunately, Stack Overflow kindly warns me by placing an indicator directly in my navigation bar.

> [image: 496 items!]

That's nearly 500 items, and honestly, that's becoming a little too much to ignore. Is it impending doom? Not really, but [I'll just let Shog speak for me on this point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230802/188673):

> If that number is high or growing, then there's a problem. I've heard this lament from many different sites over the past year: "I do all I can, but there aren't enough of us and it just doesn't seem to have any effect!"
>
> If this is happening on your site, if that number is getting bigger in spite of everything you do... Then it's time to raise a call for action. Don't wait for the cruft to clog the streets before getting folks organized to clean it up.

So that's precisely what I'd like to do: consider this a call to action to help out bring that number all the way to zero. Unlike with the close votes queue, that is very much within the realm of possibility.

So please, let's get this in the “Hot Meta Posts” list, get some extra eyeballs on the LQP queue, and reverse the slowly-moving upward trend. With a capacity of up to 20 review items per day, a handful of extra participants should easily manage to obliterate these lingering review items.

#### [And if you haven't exhausted your reviews for today yet, then what are you doing just sitting around? Get out there and review!](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)

Comment: With the amount of actual and utter crap in that queue, 20 votes go very fast. It's not hard to do your part! =D

Comment: @J.Steen Precisely. :)

Comment: No wonder the queue is growing when even Jon Skeet's answers end up in it.. https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7243036

Comment: I think someone (maybe not SE) is testing some question score algorithm and flagging a lot of posts as quite a few of the answers in there are old. Something like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/458741

Comment: I'm done for today. Will I get a cookie now?

Comment: Right that's my 20 done... please send M&Ms.

Comment: @Ben: I remember someone asking directly why old posts were appearing in LQP; Shog admitted to tweaking the heuristics feeding the queue.  (And so long as old posts are only queued when the queue approaches empty, I'm just fine with checking up on old posts.)

Comment: Only so much we can do with the limits in place. _Thank you for reviewing 20 low quality posts today; come back in 3 hours to continue reviewing._

Comment: I can't change the whole community, but I make sure (since I hit 2000) to do it :). send me cookies or stuff NAO! :D (thx for the call to action though, it was needed before it got out of hand)

Comment: Under 200, its going down! Note that your number likely isn't all LQP

Comment: I can do whatever I want!

Comment: Get me to 2k rep and I'll pitch in ;)

Comment: Cleaned out all 20. *Thank you for reviewing 20 low quality posts today; come back in 8 hours to continue reviewing*." I hope I do not require to come back again after 8 hours ;)

Comment: I'd like to help out, but I don't have the reputation... so please do let people who don't have enough rep know how they can help

Comment: Looks like its clear!  For now...

Answer (score 8):

...aand we're clear!

[image: 0 posts!]

Big thanks to everyone who pitched in! Hopefully this will keep the queue at bay for a while.

Hopefully.

Comment: For historical clarity, this queue rose back up to 300 within days after it was cleared and has been staying around 200-400 for almost a month now. Please do as many reviews as you can in this queue each day!

Comment: I believe at least the pending posts in close votes queue will probably remain the untamed beast for times to come.