# You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

If you're reviewing low quality posts, I'd like you to read this. All of it. Not skim it, not just vote up/down with everyone else. In exchange, I'll keep it short. Or if you are too busy, here you go:

> TL;DR: Review carefully. Don't delete everything. Deletion is for things that actually aren't answers, *not* for low-quality answers or "wrong" answers. Flag incorrect comments from review as "not constructive".

Recently there was [a movement to "burn down" the low quality posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287436/the-low-quality-posts-review-queue-is-growing-lets-burn-it-down). This is a fine proposition, the queue *is* big and it *does* need to be reviewed.

I've been reviewing low quality posts in earnest for several months now, and here's what I've noticed: **People tend to just delete everything**. Sure, most posts in the queue are crap. I get that. And reviewers have been doing a good job of executing justice on these junk answers...in the same way that courts would if they just sentenced everyone to 10 years in jail unless they could *really really prove* they were innocent and happened to have some good treats for the jury.

Everyone reviewing LQP needs to review [Shog9's awesome answer post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/215468). Right now. Go on, I'll wait.

I've shamelessly stolen Shog's image, and added some things to it. Specifically, what we should and shouldn't be deleting in review:

[image: six things that might be apples, but aren't entirely: a nice apple, an orange, a mostly-eaten apple, a sign with a picture of an apple pointing somewhere else, a half-gone worm-eaten apple, and a green apple among red ones]

What I'd like to focus on here is low quality and "wrong" answers. This is where I see the biggest issue.

- **Low quality answers**. Yes, I know the queue is named "low quality posts", but not every minor problem needs to be deleted. Consider first if you can edit - or leave a comment for the author asking for more details, a better explanation, etc. **Only if you can't plausibly imagine anyone putting in the work to fix the post should you opt to delete these kinds of answers.**

  For example, an answer might not have description for why the code works, but it still shouldn't be deleted; just leave a comment asking the author for an explanation, and move on.
- **"Wrong" answers**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14872753) is what really gets me:

  > [image: a review-deleted answer consisting of, "Is the code to delete the body missing a check to ensure the body hasn't already been destroyed? That shouldn't cause your game to crash the first time the body is destroyed but I could see hardware/OS platforms behaving that way after that first destruction."]

  This *does* attempt to answer the question. It may be *plain wrong* — but that's something for downvotes and comments to decide. Not deletion. This is why we have the voting system — if something is wrong, it should float to the bottom below all the other not-wrong things. This is the system working.

**How you can help**: I understand that it's fun to delete stuff. It's fun to feel like you're making a difference. But there's a better way:

There will always be people reviewing that do this. They leave auto comments from review on answers that don't really need them. When I review, I delete the things that need it — link-only answers and (real) non-answers. But more importantly, I click 'looks OK' on the things that *shouldn't* be deleted.

There's another problem here — that group of people that will always leave those comments there can't really be stopped. But we can remove them as we go:

[image: flag those comments as "no longer needed"]

I've [asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265284/should-we-flag-comments-made-from-the-low-quality-posts-queue-that-are-plain-wro) if this is what we should do. The answer then, and now, is a resounding yes. When you see a review comment that simple doesn't fit a post, please flag it for moderator attention with "not constructive." They're easy flags to review, and they make a difference in the site.

One possible solution to the incorrect review problem is to change the UX of the review interface - [ManishEarth sums up the proposal quite nicely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252217/215468).

Comment: Yes, the auto-comments are really annoying. I feel that people use them just to use them, not because they fit a particular purpose.

Comment: Great post. I was thinking exactly the same thing when reviewing LQP queue today - something like half of my votes (or even more) was "looks ok", which I find quite unusual for this queue.

Comment: You need to address the SO users that vote VLQ inappropriately.  That solves a lot more problems.

Comment: @HansPassant That'd be a much different post. We do have an issue with VLQ being used inappropriately on both questions & answers.  When mods see it that's when we try to step in to adjust the behavior of specific users.

Comment: Maybe the "Looks OK" button should be renamed, then? It's not intuitive that we should click "Looks OK" for bad posts that we want to downvote.

Comment: Related: [How to review low quality answers which are not crap but just incorrect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278436/how-to-review-low-quality-answers-which-are-not-crap-but-just-incorrect?lq=1)  Also related, based on the suggestion to downvote: [Allow voting from review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278127/allow-voting-from-review-queues)

Comment: See also: ["Should I be concerned about delete reviews on reasonable but brief answers?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers)

Comment: Eh, VLQ's should be deleted. How do you fix a post comment/edit/downvote-ing that is totally garbage?

Comment: @Braiam: Well, yes. But the problem here is with people's definition of VLQ.

Comment: You think link-only answers are delete-worthy but not unexplained code? That seems like a double standard, to me.

Comment: @TylerH: Link-only answers have no content whatsoever; they're essentially a waste of time for those who aren't willing to click on links for whatever reason, or once the links are broken. Unexplained code at least contains code that can be judged on its own should the reader be so charitable.

Comment: @BoltClock Link only answers contain content in the form of a link to an answer. It's bad, but so is unexplained code. Both are VLQ.

Comment: @ruakh Very nice observation about "Looks OK". Maybe the real name should be "Cannot be deleted (unfortunately)" or "An answer (albeit most probably not a good one)". :)

Comment: The fact that you couldn't find a single good example shows that how weak is your point. You're just confusing information with noise.

Comment: I'd like to focus on low quality image descriptions... ;^)

Comment: Read through. Thanks for the heads up. Definitely agree with @ruakh. Perhaps the button should be renamed to something along the lines of "Is an answer" or "Looks acceptable".

Comment: While I completely agree with the 'Looks OK' (after a comment and a downvote, I hope) for the review linked (the makefile question) from the LQ queue, for people in the field with expertise is it wrong to delete that (since it truly does not contribute anything useful to the question) once it's -3 or so and 20k or whatever users can cast direct delete votes?

Comment: Good tip on flagging inappropriate Deletion Reason comments

Comment: Related: [Improve help text for the low-quality-posts queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220794/255554)

Comment: You asked for a better example of a wrong answer than the one you showed us. [Here's one.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1867739/4284627)

Comment: Main issue is that that one hasn't undergone review, @Donald.

Comment: Let's say I reviewed an answer and found it in category number (Picture # ) 5 or 6 i.e. low quality answer or a wrong answer. Let's say I put some comment and downvote it. After that I have to go past that review item to do my next review. What should I do at this stage? If I click "Looks OK" then that's not the case as the post is still not ok. It will become ok after the answerer makes some changes based on comment. If I press "Skip" then I loose my review count even though I did put my efforts to review the item and give an appropriate feedback.

Comment: @RBT "Looks OK" means "it shouldn't be deleted right now". It's poor wording, mostly.

Comment: Even without the sixth image, the wrong answer would still fall into the "Answer" or at least "Partial answer" category.

Answer (score 81):

I agree with this in principle. If an answer is just flat-out *wrong*, that does not **in and of itself** qualify it for deletion. An incorrect answer does not make it low quality. There can be some very high-quality answers that are simply factually incorrect.

Plenty of answers exist in a grey area—answers that are low-quality but not blatantly irrelevant. All of the following should be deleted without question:

- New questions posted as an answer.
- Attempts to reply to existing answers.
- Answers that are *nothing* but links with no explanation.
- Answers that clearly have nothing at all to do with the question.

Nobody really disputes any of the above. The real problematic cases are the following:

- Answers that could really be better-suited as comments.

  These are often short one-liners that technically *attempt* to answer the question, but are really nowhere near enough to actually help anyone solve the problem at hand.
- Answers that might answer the question but don't have any explanation attached to them.

  Code-only answers are a common example of this, but they can also be answers that just say “do this thing” without explaining why or what that even means.

Let me address these one at a time.

---

#### Should answers that should be comments be deleted?

This might be somewhat controversial, but I'm of the opinion that **yes, these should not be allowed as “answers” to questions on Stack Overflow**.

Now, *obviously*, it's important to use your own judgement when considering answers like these. Sometimes, even though an answer could, theoretically, be a comment, it *does* answer the question, and that's okay. (Usually that's indicative of a poor question, but that does not usually warrant punishing the answer.)

See, [this is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28863019/465378):

> [image]

Is it a *good* answer? No. But it is an answer, and there's no reason to delete it.

On the other hand, [this can be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902861/465378):

> [image]

What's the difference? In the former, the answer directly addresses the problem posed by the asker of the question. It's a poor question, but that's irrelevant. In the latter, the asker actually included a relatively specific problem as well as some code that requires a much more substantive answer. That answer should be a comment.

I think in these cases, what qualifies as an answer actually *can* be context-sensitive. I'm perfectly willing to click-through to the question to take a look at what's actually being asked.

---

#### Should answers with no explanation be deleted?

This one is a little less clear-cut.

This [isn't helpful at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28903967/465378):

> [image]

- There is absolutely no explanation about what that code does, how it addresses the problem, or why it's the correct solution. It's not even really clear why that code is at all *relevant* to the question.
- Furthermore, there already exist other answers that are *far superior* to that one, those that actually answer the question. Keeping that poor answer around isn't going to help anyone.

On the other hand, [this one's actually okay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28904592/465378):

> [image]

Is this a stellar answer? No. Very much no. But it explains why the code posted is an answer to the question. Just by saying “try the null coalescing operator”, the answer is given enough context so that a **specific piece of information** can be extracted from the code snipped and applied elsewhere.

In the previous, poor-quality answer, there was no indicator how that answer could be used any where else because it wasn't clear what was the solution and what was just boilerplate code.

Similarly, [this sucks, but it's still an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28904558/465378):

> [image]

Again, it's clear what's changed, and it's clear what the hell the answerer is actually attempting to convey.

---

Oh, and this is important...

## Learn to love “No Comment Needed”.

> [image]

See that? You can vote to delete questions without leaving comments! Especially if something should not blatantly be deleted, don't pollute the world by clicking one of the comment reasons just because you can.

Those comment reasons let you leave comments without having to think about typing out comments. They're tempting. But with great power comes great responsibility—please don't abuse the feature.

---

One more thing—that image Shog posted a while back? That was about **Not An Answer flags**. “Very Low Quality” and “Not An Answer” flags are two very different things. Just because something's *technically* an answer doesn't mean it should be kept around.

That said, the point you made in your question is quite sound, and I agree—more discretion is needed in the Low Quality Posts queue. I just don't believe that the absolute you proposed in your question is wholly accurate.

Comment: You might want to add answers which don't attempt to answer the question but instead offer lots of advice on side-issues (no reation to "XY-problem" or "Don't do it"). Or is that something you avoided on purpose?

Comment: @Deduplicator I personally find that those tend to fall into the "should be comments" group of answers. It's rare to find a well-written answer of that sort, and when I do, it's usually because the question was unclear to begin with.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out the text of the very low quality flag: `This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.` Basically absolute and total garbage. Personally I'm surprised we have the flag at all. None of the posts mentioned in this answer nor in the question above deserve that flag, so I feel it is rather a mute point..

Comment: @Seth That heavily depends on your definition of "severe" and "salvageable." I agree the description is pretty bad, but I think the flag is valuable for what it's currently used as.

Comment: @AlexisKing Which is?

Comment: @Seth Mostly, [all of these](http://i.imgur.com/CAlzlRO.png). Answers that serve *no value* don't need to be kept around.

Comment: @AlexisKing Every single one of those qualifies as NAA..

Comment: @Seth In theory, yes. In practice, no. The VLQ has always been a little “squishier” in what's permitted as opposed to the NAA flag, mostly because there's a review queue for it. One could argue about how the flags are defined and their overlap extensively, but that's a conversation for another meta post.

Comment: @AlexisKing Both VLQ and NAA flags send posts to the same review queue, the Low Quality review. As a reviewer, one doesn't even get told which flag was raised.

Comment: Re "no comment needed": for a long time I _always_ left a comment because "You can't flag/vote to close without a reason, so surely I have to choose a reason when recommending deletion!"  I have chosen "no comment" a few times now, but I always feel like if I can't fit it in one of the existing comments, I shouldn't be choosing to delete -- I feel I'm substituting my judgement about what deserves deletion for the community's.

Comment: @Jeffrey But as a matter of fact, delete votes are not categorized by reason - only close votes are. The comment templates are just that - some comments you may wish to add to the post. And the option 'no comment' is there on purpose.

Comment: ... as is the option to add your own free-form comment, and *then* choosing delete and none needed, or keep.

Answer (score 31):

The [guidance you refer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/215468) is helpful and authoritative, but please note that there is **another guidance**, no less helpful and no less authoritative that suggests a different approach, to [dive deep, check thoroughly and cut mercilessly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773):

> ...answers that are strong candidates for deletion:
>
> - belong to low rep or anon users with no real commitment to the community
> - are *provably* duplicate, that is, were added well after (30+ mins later) other answers that contained the same exact information
> - are short in length
> - do not explain much of anything

"But wait!" - I hear you saying - "these two seem to contradict each other, which one I pick?"

Not really. These simply complement each other and are meant to be used in different context.

- Guidance you refer lays out approach to evaluate delete-worthy posts *quickly and safely* and ensure that mistakes in doing this are minimized. If you are (are you?) a diamond moderator acting on one of (hundreds!) routine flags you get every day, you better stick with this guidance as firmly as you can - because if you don't, there is a real risk of accidentally deleting valuable content.
- Another guidance is for the cases when one can (should) invest *substantial* effort into studying and curating reviewed content. If, again, you are a diamond moderator, this guidance applies to rare, "special cases" where you are expected to go beyond routine quick evaluation.

You see, guidance for diamonds moderators is essentially to act depending on how much time and effort they are expected to put into content review. I think that a regular user reviewing LQ posts can follow this approach as well.

---

Worth noting that at 20 LQ reviews a day limit, [one has plenty time to do more thorough check of reviewed posts...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251155/165773) Not to mention that [there is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601) if it feels too much work.

Comment: ...I personally prefer approach covered by _quick and safe_ guidance - because, well, I prefer to spend less time on review (guess that makes me skip over many "known good" audits). But I can totally relate to those who prefer _thoroughly curating content_, especially in their favorite tags

Comment: The Jeff Atwood’s post you quote starts with: *I think there are a general set of guidelines for question maintenance that should apply to any extremely popular question: …* This shifts the meaning. I would certainly refrain from applying this advice on posts with one or two answers, where even a very incomplete answer can be useful.

Comment: @Palec this guidance was originally written for diamond moderators; they can give so much attention only to _extremely_ limited amount of posts. This was long before [LQ queue was introduced](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251175/839601) for tens thousands 2K users

Answer (score 20):

I agree with this. One thing I want to add: When I come across a code-only answer in the queue, what I do is leave a comment like this (using [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)), and click "Looks OK":

> Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

This actually works. I have had numerous people who have then gone and edited their answer to include an explanation of the code!

Answer (score -8):

I'll say for myself why I am (ab)using the "low quality" queue instead of votes. Because downvotes take a toll on my reputation while the flags are "free".

The rationale is: my hard-earned rep doesn't deserve to suffer because someone posted crap. That's because, by Pareto principle, there's orders of magnitude more crap than good stuff, so I cannot possibly downvote everything that deserves it and retain a positive score.

I'm not saying this is the right thing to do. I'm saying that I'm working around a flaw in the system that would otherwise rip me off.

I can only speak for myself. But I do imply that most probably, I'm far from being the only one, and the situation that led to the current topic is a direct result. Remember that the vast majority of users with the privilege do not have so many rep points and steady income that they no longer care about a few (dozen).

Comment: This might deserve to have its own question - but it doesn't really belong in an answer here.

Comment: You cannot downvote everything deserving it either way, there's a vote-limit. And just because an answer deserves a downvote doesn't mean deleting it is a good idea, people can learn trying to figure out *why* it is bad, which might even be spelled out in the comments. Anyway, that presupposes that your judgement is sound in every single case, which I doubt: Mine sure isn't. As undo already commented, removing the investment on downvoting is a different question and should be its own feature-request (probably a dupe, but not sure).

Comment: I wonder how many others are avoiding downvotes for this reason.

Comment: @Undo sure it does. But since this directly relates to the sutiation in the VLQ queue, this belongs here as well.

Comment: @KevinB I can only speak for myself. But I do imply that most probably, I'm far from being the only one.

Comment: @Deduplicator we're talking about dynamics here. Since one is voting on stuff as they see it.

Comment: reputation is meant to be spent. Um, well, one can spend it. Or you can get kicks out of looking at a number. But you can't buy cheeseburgers with it. Show decide what they are for, for you.

Comment: @Drew but I can buy "rep points" in the eyes of an employer, for example (and I did it once already). Of all things, rep is a testament of time and effort and some level of expertize and passion in the field.

Comment: Flags aren't "free", either. You have a limited number of them per day, and if they are misused, you can be banned from flagging. For example, using "very low quality" flags for things that should simply be downvoted and that don't require immediate deletion will most likely lead to those flags being declined. If enough of them are declined, you'll be banned from flagging. I recommend only using the right tools for the job.

Comment: I think [This link to you](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:648265+[python]) is all you need. Those are probably some pretty good answers. And ya know what happens to 2/3 or more of downvote points lost? You get em back the next day when the atrocity was deleted. But no. Few downvote. Go figure. The community is left plodding through stuff that shouldn't be here.

Comment: @Drew "when the atrocity was deleted". So why not work towards deleting it in the first place rather than lose points and hope for the best?

Comment: I do both as people in that effort are aware. But I only get 40 a day in one effort, and 50 in another. Or whatever the numbers are. And I spend an hour a day in the queue now to make up for the neglect of not doing it in the past

Comment: And I am not "hoping for the best" even if it is not deleted. I do that for what I consider absolutely horrible Answers that need a message left. Why, because someone may waste a good deal of time going down that route. Why, cuz I feel like it and think when I do it is fair and balanced.

Comment: @BradLarson don't worry, I'm not so stupid as to vote on risky stuff so much as to incur the wrath of moderators (for the record, I never hit the daily limit). There apparently are enough people who think like me since only a fraction of my flags get declined (and since this topic was created in the first place).

Comment: @Drew "reputation is meant to be spent" - oh, really? I thought is was meant to be accumulated to measure my contribution to the site and earn me privileges as acknowledgement for it. If my downvote makes the site _better_ - why should I _lose_ reputation for it?

Comment: Because you get it back, and it is your investment in the site. An investment, a funny term for something with no tangible value. Think how wildly awful it would be without a (-1). Did you ever play that out in your head, Ivan?

Comment: @Drew 1) how do I get it back? Earn for other things? That's not getting it back, that's earning it anew. 2) Investment? Maybe the site wins from this, but I lose. The fact is, the system as well as ppl don't give a f**k about such things. All they see and judge by is the net number. So I strive to maintain it to further my goals while staying true to my values (which are "no cheap rep").

Comment: keep on trunkin. Good luck. Keep up the good answers on the stack. Over and out.

Comment: Just use downvoting as a motivation for posting good answers. If you post a good answer for every downvote you make everyone's winning.

Comment: @nico I consider this a good answer and downvotes as upvotes because it's _designed_ to incur repulse, being so negative, soaked with opportunism and universal distrust. That's because that's what I feel: everything and everyone is against me, I'm all alone, no help is forthcoming, so I have to cheat, deceive, eel my way around this, survive in any way possible - since the system's designers knowingly made it hopeless for me the normal way. And the post's intention is to convey these feelings as strongly as possible.

Comment: @nico I cannot imagine myself upvoting it, for instance. I'd probably do neither or downvote, considering this "the next best thing" to upvoting.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev "the site wins from this, but I lose." Why would you need reputation in the first place then? This site revolves around rep, but if the site doesn't "benefit", there is no rep at all! And it's only a -1 rep. It's not like it's -Infinity reputation for downvoting or something.

Comment: @MasterBob I already answered both questions in the post and comments. Read carefully.

Comment: It helps the site, remember? What if you posted a question and you got no good answers? Shamelessly quoting nico: "Just use downvoting as a motivation for posting good answers." Maybe downvoting helps - oh wait, it does.