# Better incentivize review queues to encourage more participation

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Yes, this is another "the close votes queue is getting too large"-related question.

So, how do we cut down on this queue? There's already an auto-prune after X days mechanic; considering the rate at which the queue is growing, how long before "days" becomes "hours" and then "minutes"?

A far better solution is to get more people voting to close, and the obvious way to achieve this is to incentivize participation in voting. The simplest mechanic to achieve this is to award +rep for tending the close vote queue.

To quote from the help center, "Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about." In my mind, if you've successfully curated a certain amount of the site's content, you definitely know what you're talking about.

So how would this work?

- only users who are dedicated reviewers - i.e. those with the Steward badge - should get +rep for close votes
- +rep should be awarded based on the size of the queue being worked, and the number of votes cast by a user per day. A queue that never has more than 1,000 entries doesn't award any rep, and you can only get +rep if you use all of your votes for that queue in a day.
- +rep should be rewarded at a very low rate, i.e. +5 per 40 votes (or even more slowly)

There are some aspects of this that need to be addressed - most obviously, queue bots - but I'm sure we can come up with something.

/flame suit on

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment?

Comment: there are ~20,000 users eligible to vote close; if all of them would use 40 votes, that would be enough to close or drop everything off the queue in just a day. We better be careful in unleashing such a closing power

Answer (score 11):

No, handing out reputation points for a moderation-related action like reviewing close votes would be a terrible idea. It would be completely open to abuse and would lead to snap judgments on important matters.

We already have huge problems with review abuse caused by the badges, thus the relatively frequent audits. Without those audits, even adding meaningless badges led to a nightmare. I'm still cleaning up spam that not only made it through review but was upvoted multiple times from the brief period after badges were added, but before audits.

If you think that this won't be abused by high-reputation users, I should state that I recently had to deal with three 20k+ users who have been banned from review over 30 times for approving spam, vandalism, and other trash. We've had to start threatening some of these experts with account suspension to get them to stop this abuse.

It also would cheapen the meaning of these points. Right now, they are an indication of how much the community trusts you, and are the result of voting on posts or voting on your suggested edits (and even that has been a source of problems). This would remove any community judgment of your contributions and be only a measure of how well you could work the system.

Comment: Unfortunately there will always be people who abuse the system, but isn't that what mods and admins are there for? Saying "we don't want to do this thing because 0.01% of users may abuse it" is an exceptionally poor reason for not doing something. Rather punish abusers as necessary, instead of preemptively punishing everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than the incentive of reputation, which is unlikely to happen, it would be more effective if the community bulletin featured a regular "Help burn the Close Votes queue" item, to draw attention to the queue, which has [proved effective in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue).

A previous [suggestion of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221648/can-so-publicise-a-bombing-run-on-the-close-votes-queue) could be used to promote regular "Bombing Runs" to reduce it's size.