# Let questions with just one close vote appear in the close vote queue for certain tags, if there is nothing else to review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

> There are no items for you to review, matching the filter *"[matlab] [simulink]"*

Is something no reviewer should see, when it comes to close votes.

[Some time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) the number of close votes a question needs to appear in the close vote review queue was increased.

But what does that mean for small tags like [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab)?

Well I'm hardly able to reach 20 close votes a day (in the [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag, the only one I'm reviewing), as there are not enough questions in the queue, but a looot more out there with just one or two(?) close votes, which sometimes never reach the queue.

On the other hand we have an extraordinary high number of low quality question, as Matlab is regarded as an "*easy*" programming language, a lot of new programmers use.

Subsequently we have a very high unanswered question rate.

> Last 7 Days    50% unanswered
>
> Last 30 Days 45.2% unanswered
>
> All Time     24.2% unanswered

Not because we don't answer enough, but because we can't manage to close all the low quality questions, as they don't reach the queue. Is there something we could do about that?

---

**To make it clear**: the feature I'm requesting is, that **if the close vote queue for a certain tag** (which I guess contains just questions with 3 or more close votes/flags by default) **runs out of questions**, **also questions with just one or two close votes should appear in the queue.**

Comment: Did you consider using sede to find [posts with a close flag/vote](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/296549/matlab-questions-with-a-close-flag-vote)? I'm not sure how many regulars in the [SO close vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) are comfortable with matlab but we are open for `cv-pls` requests to help out in low-traffic tags.

Comment: @rene that would may give more questions to review for me. But how would it solve the general problem? It's not just me getting into an empty queue.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what your "feature" would be that you request here. I review often in low traffic tags and regularly see questions in there with only one close vote (although I don't know how many close flags there are on the question).

Comment: @ArtjomB. The feature I'm requesting is, that if the close vote queue for a certain tag (which I guess contains just questions with 3 or more close votes/flags by default) runs out of questions, also questions with just one or two close votes appear in the queue.

Comment: The filtering for questions that get in the queue is more complex than that and it tops of around 10K. If you have enough close voters that can handle the load in a specific tag I see no harm done in getting the filter that let questions in the queue to be adjusted for specific tags.

Comment: @rene I didn't know that! So if there are less than 10k questions in the queue the filter lets more questions pass? That would explain other weird things I discovered. It's a good solution how it is regarding the total close vote queue, but low traffic tags suffer under these circumstances.

Comment: Yeah, for the close vote event in the chatroom I use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/236526/tags-that-can-be-cleared-of-votes) to select the tags to focus on. The count is the actual number of questions with close votes/flags. If there are 4 of us in an event we clear a tag in one day. Roughly 20% of actual load gets in and fresh votes let questions/reivews rise to the top. With the new close vote ageing the dynamics changed somewhat  but not dramatically as far as I can tell now.