# Am I asking the wrong way? Is there something wrong with my posts?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Recently I have been asking more questions on Stack Overflow. In fact, way more than before, when I was way more inexperienced. However, the feedback is underwhelming.

I am not getting a lot of answers/questions/comments/upvotes/downvotes, nothing really at all. I am not quite sure why.

In the post [Annotation Processor appears to break Java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097430/annotation-processor-appears-to-break-java-generics) I got 2 upvotes with 2 comments. After replying to said comments, I got no answer back.

In the post [Avoiding cast in generic factory based MVP framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082791/avoiding-cast-in-generic-factory-based-mvp-framework) I got a "possible answer" as a comment, on which I asked for elaboration but got no response back.

These posts are not very old, but the post [Integrating Spring into an existing Guice project and take beans from Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231351/integrating-spring-into-an-existing-guice-project-and-take-beans-from-guice) was edited, but never got replied to.

In fact, most of my questions are treated like this. I asked 13 questions in total. Only 4 got an answer at all, and all of those I answered by myself. I expected at least a comment saying, "this is not clear enough", or, "this question is way to complicated, can you post more code?". I would have even welcomed a comment like, "This is a really bad question because xyz", combined with a downvote.

I clearly must be doing something wrong. To clarify: I am *not* complaining. I want to know what I am doing wrong, to make my next questions right. I would have already done it if I got a response to that of some kind.

I am so sorry to bother you, but this has started to bother me quite a bit now. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Are my questions to specific/complicated? Is there something like asking to complicated questions which results in no/very few views/answers/comments?

Comment: It may just be that your questions aren't getting many views. Of the 5 questions you've asked this year, 3 have a positive score, none have down votes, and none are closed. There may be something you should be doing to make them more interesting but you don't seem to have anything *seriously* wrong with them.

Comment: How can i make them more interresting? I also have a question, that is 2 years and 3 months old, that got ~ 600 views and yet got no answer.. I am just confused about what is going on.

Comment: I think you're going to need help with someone active in those tags. Meta is pretty quiet on weekends. I would try chat (and during the week if possible, things seem pretty quiet there now too).

Comment: Thanks, i will wait till monday (or later). Thank you

Comment: Those questions all have a very software engineering *smell* (like roses, not poo) to them, more then a programming *smell*. Could it be that those questions are also on-topic on [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where they find similar experts but ones that are both interested and equipped to answer those questions?

Comment: I thought about that, but aren't the problems (which by all means result from the software design) of a programming nature?

Comment: I already feel some kind of anxiety, when posting a question here.
As professional as this site is made, i believe only people that are perfect are welcome here. But i'm no Borg.

Comment: To be honest, those questions all look like they're right up my alley and I'll probably come back and write an answer for at least one of them. But I never saw any of your questions in my browsing (I don't write very much Java anymore, so I'm not visiting Java-related questions much these days). I wish the site had more questions like these! But I also wish that when there are questions like these, they could be easier to find.

Comment: This thread should be turned into a pie-in-the-sky feature request for automagically bumping `the high quality so many users clamor for` to the top of question searches in some way. Maybe create some sort of scoring heuristic for quality (much like google search does) and add a new sorting criteria for questions that uses that heuristic. Start in alpha by simply evaluating the heuristic on existing questions to determine whether it's effective or not.

Comment: regarding your editd but not answered question - sometimes I also feel that people are more keen on editing ( even faux-editing ) questions than answering them...

Comment: Just a (not very related) note, in reply to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082791/avoiding-cast-in-generic-factory-based-mvp-framework#comment91116604_52082791): (1) If you edit a comment to add a `@somebody` they will be notified, and (2) If you're the OP, comment on the question and there is only 1 other commenter they get notified automatically.

Comment: "Is there something wrong with my posts?" Almost certainly. Most posts have a problem of some kind. The question is not whether it has a problem. The question is how severe are its problems?

Comment: A bonus can do wonders, especially if it's more than 50 points. Not so much because experts are desperate for imaginary internet points, but because of the exposure a bonus question gets.

Comment: Also, those questions you link to all have 4 tags, and tags create exposure to an additional audience. You have 1 left, use it wisely! (Obviously, the tags should be relevant, otherwise you're tag-spamming.)

Comment: The question that i was waiting... You asked it..

Comment: You could try to post a bounty on the questions...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I thought about that, but i could not do that until recently. And i could have done that only once.

Comment: Maybe join Reddit's "javahelp" sub and link to a question there.  Just start with one though.  I've done this sort of thing and not only have gotten more valuable feedback, but also the Announcer badge

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong, you would have been downvoted if so. The lack of true answers comes from the complexity of your questions combined to the lack of experts in these area.

Comment: new Code of Conduct scared the experts away

Comment: *I expected at least a comment saying ...* you need more realistic expectations.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I added a feature request based on your comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378013/forgotten-gems-review-queue

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You are not doing this the wrong way.

In my opinion, the real problem here is that there are not enough experts answering questions. This has always been a bit of problem (I remember a co-worker saying that he was giving up on Stack Overflow because his deep questions never got a decent answer. That was in about 2011 or 2012 ...). It got better as Stack Overflow grew, but it seems that it is now going in the opposite direction.

An alternative explanation is that the (reducing?) population of real experts are missing a lot of worthwhile questions because they are lost in the deluge of poor quality stuff:

- "please tutor me",
- "please do my homework",
- "please give me something to copy-and-paste",
- questions that are incoherent, unintelligible and / or plainly duplicative.

What can you do about it?

- "Polishing" your questions won't help if the problem is that there are no experts reading them.
- Complaining here probably won't help. We (the community / moderators) can't do things that will keep the experts here and answering questions.

Solving these problems is really down to Stack Exchange management... and they seem to be more interested in keeping new users (== advertising revenue) and adding new features that can be monetized.

You may want to look at [What does our long term community need? What does our long term community need to feel valued?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158) to see other opinions on the "keeping the experts" issue.

Comment: But isn't this a bit contradictory? If they want to keep new users, shouldn't they try to keep users, that are starting to ask questions by providing more feedback to their questions? I sometimes (or even "most of the times") feel like i should rather not ask anything and try to figure out the solution by myself (in tedious, long programming sessions, that only focuse on that one error), than to risk my question getting lost within Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is a different problem.  The problem I am talking about here is keeping the experts.  But yes, you probably **should** debug problems for yourself rather than relying on the good graces of a **free** expert to diagnose / debug your code for you.  'Cos most experts get fed up with people who exploit them like that ... and find something more rewarding to do with their spare time.

Comment: To clarify, i did not mean to ask every thing that comes up to my mind on Stack Overflow! This would be horrible... But sometimes i have problems, that i can't answer myself and i waste hours on hand, trying to fix those without any result. It is at that time, i am to scard (i gues this is the right wording) to ask Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Thorben "risk my question getting lost within Stack Overflow. " - What's the "risk"? If you don't get an answer, you're not worse off than before...

Comment: And if you really, really need an answer, you should *pay* someone to get the answer for you.

Comment: @npostavs there is no objective answer to that. It just feels so bad. I know of some people that left Stack Overflow because of that feeling you get of that, you could call it "beeing left alone".

Comment: @StephenC i wanted to point out the contradiction in the reasoning. If "they seem to be more interested in keeping new users", they should help them feel welcome. Else i totally agree with you :)

Comment: They (StackExchange management) **say** that attrition of new users is a problem.  Whether their strategies for addressing the problem are appropriate, effective, consistent with their previously stated goals, etc is ... a different topic.

Comment: I understand that completely and i understand that this is not your point. It was nothing against you/your statement

Comment: I agree with the first half of this answer but disagree with the second half. Polishing questions not only makes them better but also bumps them to the front page, which means more attention. Asking about a question on Meta also tends to invite the well-known Meta Effect, which in the case of a good question usually means lots of votes and answers/activity.

Comment: Also what does it mean to give up on SO because there aren't a lot of "deep" experts? I mean does it make sense to ask what is the meaning of life for example and expect answers? One must not give up on a source of possible answers when the question by design is not going to have many answers.

Comment: "What we can do about it" surely includes answering more of the easy questions ourselves to relieve the experts of that responsibility. That's how Stack Overflow works. You can go get more reputation by answering questions and then you can put bounties on your own questions to attract the experts. I think a bigger problem is the culture of people being stingy with upvotes, and "hit and run" questions where answers are never read or marked as correct. There needs to be more incentive to give out that reputation rather than just incentive to get it.

Comment: Why not reward quality questions and quality answers with deeper value than regular questions? Seems like we already have people who have answered lots of questions in a particular tech could vote for questions being "high quality" questions.

Comment: @JeffDavis - quality has been of no concern for a long time, they removed it from the charter statement like 6 years ago in preference for quantity.

Comment: *"Also what does it mean to give up on SO because there aren't a lot of "deep" experts?"* - It means that he stopped asking questions because he didn't get any *useful* answers.  Note I am talking about someone with many years programming experience who was trying to use a framework that he wan't familiar with in "interesting" ways.

Answer (score 34):

You aren't doing anything wrong. Those questions look good to me, they look like the high quality so many users clamor for, and they are undeniably on topic. Over time, it is probable your questions will receive answers, and with a bounty it is almost guaranteed.

That said, complex questions here don't get many answers; despite how many users clamor for "higher quality", answers per question are worse off today than they have ever been in the history of the site.

[image]
<sup>[source: data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/760472/average-answers-per-question-by-month#graph)</sup>

There are many factors involved in that, and it is hard to pinpoint the exactness of why. It has been discussed a lot, here is [a discussion of the turning point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320234/1026459).

Overall, in my opinion what you are experiencing comes down to a problem that the site has with topicality. The on-topic set of close reasons (including the standard set), of which there have only ever been two, defines what questions can be open at Stack Overflow. There are some areas in there which are rather open to interpretation, and some areas which are vague as the result of combining too many things into one reason.

It is highly possible, and at this point, highly *probable*, that high quality questions are being discouraged by the current set of close reasons. As a result, the users who attempt to keep the site on topic feel a burden of closing when other users feel questions should be allowed. There is a clear and tangible friction that exists in that space.

A simple example of interpretation versus definition is the too broad close reason. Answers are allowed to have 30,000 characters (yes, it is a ridiculous amount). Yet, the too broad definition actively prevents questions which would easily be answered in 30,000 characters. Now, this isn't to say we should suddenly start accepting all forms of questions asking for crazy tutorials; it is only to point out there is *interpretation* involved in where the line exists between crazy tutorial and solution.

So, why am I saying all of this? Well, your questions fall into a gray area of interpretation. As a result, they weren't closed or downvoted, but they weren't really received as a question of priority either. Personally, I would like to see that type of question get more answers because I think it benefits future users.

In conclusion, I think that we need to strongly consider refining the topicality of the site in order to reduce community friction as well as increase quality. Altering the topicality will allow for two very important things that the community needs: it will allow us to close without interpretation, thus making question closing easier and quicker; it will allow us to better distinguish between questions that should be encouraged versus questions which are clearly using loopholes to exist, thus sending a clearer signal of which questions should be answered.

Comment: TL;DR people who could answer these questions have stopped answering questions.

Comment: @Travis: "*Well, your questions fall into a gray area of interpretation.*" I fail to see how. The third one seems rather Software Engineering like, but the first two seem pretty on-topic for SO. So I don't see how "topicality" is the issue here. If what you're saying is true, then some of those questions would have close votes, but they do not. I also don't see how our current close reasons discourage high-quality questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas - In the time since posting this answer, of the 3 posts linked by the OP, 3 have been downvoted and 2 have been closed. In addition, you can clearly see an example of the "interpretation" [posted in an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373520/1026459) just below mine. Our current close reasons give rise to a type of mentality that is more aimed at simply answering or refactoring "how to compare strings in Java" versus how to structure a framework implementation.

Comment: @TravisJ: That has nothing to do with our current close reasons. It has more to do with a separation of concerns. "How to structure a framework implementation" is a design question, which belongs over on SE.SE.

Comment: @NicolBolas - It does have to do with close reasons. Just because it requires analysis and some code doesn't make it overtly broad or off topic. These issues with implementation are code based, with code shown for context. ["explaining, writing or debugging code" is off topic at SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Or, more directly: [Stack Overflow is the place for code](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7864/42934). Shutting down the production of code at Stack Overflow is a dangerous thing. We are collectively falling behind as a result.

Answer (score 17):

Some of your questions are too broad, some are edge case advanced technique duplicates that most people will not take the time to hunt down and mark them as such and then do not answer because they will get down voted when someone does take the time to find and mark them and rightly so.

The majority I see are *could be on topic* if someone were to take the time to read them for comprehension, but as they are just giant walls of text and code with no very clear `TL;DR` problem statement, nobody is going to do that. They are instant **ignore** without getting read questions. You should be glad that these are not drawing `downvotes` which after the `meta-effect` they probably will.

I am in disagreement that these are all `the high quality questions` people are looking for. Maybe in theory the actual underlying question is what people want to answer, but in the end, the presentation is **not** what people are looking for.

[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) specifically says *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*  If you question is a huge wall of text/code it is just the same problem. `TL;DR`

Most veteran contributors that could answer these questions (minority of the site) could answer or close as duplicates 50 straight forward "How to compare strings in Java?" type questions in the time it takes to read one half of one of your questions. Then it is going to have be read a few more times to make sure it is fully comprehended. Big nope.

#### For example:

There is not anything inheritenly *off-topic* with
[Positioning of a dragging “Card” in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034537/positioning-of-a-dragging-card-in-javafx) but I would not expect it to get answered immediately, if ever because it is has no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and nobody is going to take the time and tremendous effort to replicate *your* problem, research and debug it just to answer it for *you* free. You might get an answer one day ( maybe months/years from now ) when a [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/) comes along and sees it and can answer it without any new research, which is highly unlikely. Also it very likely that a step debugger can answer some of them as well, people just ignore those now instead of commenting on them because of the current social climate on everyone new is a delicate flower to be stomped on by the veteran contributors. So they just *vote and move on* which is actually always been the correct thing to do.

> Think about your questions after your write them. Would you take the
> time to re-create, research and debug the same question if it was
> someone else's?

Comment: "Most veteran contributors that could answer these questions (minority of the site) could answer or close as duplicates 50 straight forward "How to compare strings in Java?" type questions in the time it takes to read one half of one of your questions." IMO that's one of the problems with the [research effort obsession](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4975230), do answerers **really want** questions that are research paper level and take many days to answer? I kinda doubt it... IMO SE is good for quick questions and quick answers...

Comment: ... though it seems like some posters do want this kind of post, and some don't, so I guess you get downvoted for showing your research, and downvoted for not showing it?

Comment: @jrh - you left off the *Big nope.* at the end of what you quoted.

Answer (score 8):

## My Findings

I wanted to answer my own question and share my findings.

> What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

The answer to that question sadly is, that I did not post on meta. After posting to meta, the questions I asked got attention (mostly positive and mostly constructive). But this can't be the answer to the low feedback problem!

> Are my questions to specific/complicated? Is there something like asking to complicated questions which results in no/very few views/answers/comments?

As was pointed out in one answer, I would think they are. However, the majority said that there is nothing wrong with them. Also the majority felt like, there are not enough experts on this site, who could answer said questions.

## Everybody starts as an amateur

I have to strongly agree with Roman, who stated in the comments:

> I already feel some kind of anxiety, when posting a question here. As professional as this site is made, I believe only people that are perfect are welcome here. But I'm no Borg.

Even when asking this question, I felt a strong kind of anxiety. A friend of mine, basically got to talk me into this.

Stack Overflow has a problem. I cannot describe it in detail, but I believe that [this blog post](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) points out some of the problems (and the comments on this blog post speak for themselves). Stack Exchange wants to focus on getting new users (as pointed out in one answer), while the long term community wants to feel valued (see the linked question). There is nothing inherently flawed about getting both things to work, yet they seem to work against each other.

Anyone can rise to become an expert in a topic. Sometimes we need help, and sometimes we want to help. But to really become an expert, we need feedback. Every single one of us.

If you want to increase the quality of questions, then provide some feedback. Why is this question bad? What can you do, to make it better? Do not make them feel like delicate little flowers, but do not make them feel like they are not worth your time and should go into a corner and shame themselves either. If a question is badly worded, why not recommend to make its wording better? If a question seems like a duplicate, why not ask them if the question has already been answered before?

Coming down as the judge and the executioner without saying anything makes people feel worthless. The quality of the questions will not increase of said person; they will go away from asking any more questions. But you will also feel bad, because there is yet another bad question.

Maybe some tools will help. For example:

#### Upvoting high-quality questions

This would give a reference to new users, what is good and what is not. Even though, up- and downvotes have a specific meaning (on answers: "This answer is useful" / "This answer is not useful" and on questions: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" / "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful"), from what I see, they have succumb to "like" / "dislike". Without a reason, this is fast and easy to do, way faster than to flag an answer/question.

It could contain a check-list (or a text-field) to require the "quality-downvoters" to specify their problem with this question. Since this is not a feature request, I don't want to go into detail, but the result may just be what everybody wants. Over time, we get better questions/answers and build up a good climate for everyone.

If this is not your bread, how about forcing voters to say **why** they up-/downvoted the way they did? This would allow the one getting downvoted to see why he was downvoted and help him better himself.

#### Conclusion

As I started here, my first questions were bad (I believe). One question got downvoted three times. But till this day, I do not know why. It appears that this question was not answered before. I do not know that. Sure, I do not need to know that now, but how should I improve my next question after that, if I do not know what was bad about this question?

Since then I (apparently) improved my question, yet I still don't know why. I got lucky and found nice people that still tried to help me. But others have no such luck.

Some people will always spread hate. On that note: I have to disagree with [Jay Hanlon in his blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) (on some points). It has nothing to do with specific groups of people hating other specific groups of people. It is all of us. The long term community is getting frustrated and new people don't want to stay. This helps no one.

In this manner, thank you for your time and have a nice day.

Comment: The requirement for anonymous feedback when you downvote has been suggested in the past. But SO are more concerned about the *resistance* to voting this might cause. Personally, I think it's a great idea. But it won't happen.

Comment: I think this answer has some good points, but it may attract some disagreement (downvotes on meta are different) because it suggests requiring comments with downvotes. I didn't downvote, just wanted to make sure you were aware of this.

Comment: *Coming down as the judge and the executioner without saying anything makes people feel worthless.* this is why no one comments, people perpetuating that it is somehow *mean* to down vote or close a question, like you do here, is just **confirmation bias** to those people that think this way, stop it. It isn't, if you feel some personal attack because someone clicks an arrow or link on a website anonymously with no comment, that is **is on you**, it is your problem that you are internalizing something that is not there, **only you can fix that**.

Comment: *The quality of the questions will not increase of said person, they will go away from asking any more questions.* and if they do then the quality of the site, improves or at least does not drop anymore because of this person refusing to do the work and put in the effort to be a positive contributor. Same end result either way. Entropy is staved off for a moment.

Comment: *But you will also feel bad, because there is yet another bad question.* nope, not in the least, slowing entropy is a win regardless how it is achieved, but thanks for trying to tell others how we should *feel*.

Comment: *If you want to increase the quality of questions, then provide some feedback*, that is **exactly what down votes and close votes do**, they provide a **uniform anonymous judgement free feedback** that is how the system is designed and works. If the OP refuses to do any work to learn how to do better given all the tools they have at their disposal that is on them.

Comment: *"you will also feel bad"* you typed that, pretty clear no interpretation needed.

Comment: Do you want me to change it to _you might also feel bad_?

Comment: Why do you insist that someone should feel **anything**, there is nothing to *feel*, you are perpetuating something that is toxic to the community, that feelings have anything to do with anything. Why should I *feel* any emotion about any of this. To insist that is just toxic.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome I do not insist that someone **should** feel anything. But most humans do that. It is a bad habbit, but extremely hard to get rid off. Not everyone feels that way, I understand that, that is why it can be helpful to hear this. If I can't change the text to fit you, I am sorry about that. But taking this five words and stomping on them over and over again, does not help. If this is a bad answer in your oppinion, okay. I accept that. I do not take it personally.

Comment: it is important, because posts like yours are just used to beat people over the head with as **confirmation biased** *evidence* to those that just want to dump on the community as a whole and power insulting blog posts that you yourself posted a link to. Part of the problem or part of the solution is your choice.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome I stated that i disagree with it. You did read that, right? I want to improve the community for everyone. This is my only goal. I fail to see how i am not, by trying to find a common ground between new users and veteran users (like you). However, this is getting nowhere. I am sorry that i offended you.

Comment: Of course humans have feelings, but expressing feelings is usually considered inappropriate in a professional setting, unless we are in the entertainment industry (which I hope SO is not).

Comment: @artem Yes, of course. I would not want anyone to express this or that feeling. I tried to shed a light on what may be the problem and therefor expressed my feelings. I am sorry, I belive I failed in that. There is a reason why people are leaving SO, even if it is not your or my oppinion. I would not want to see SO die. If no new user wants to stay and the veteran users leave or do not ask/answer any more, it sooner or later will.

Comment: Posting on Meta specifically for the purpose of triggering a Meta effect is a clear abuse of the site.

Comment: If the only way to make the site work as intended is to "abuse" it, something is really off

Comment: @artem That a question doesn't get much attention or any answers does not mean the site is not working as intended. It means the question is not particularly useful. I suspect something like 99.9% of all questions on the site are not particularly useful or even interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Your questions vary from finely tuned with a limited scope to too broad (asking for best practice) however, they may just might be on topics where there isn't a lot of activity or expertise.

Please don't forget that time doesn't matter on Stack Exchange.  There is no due date for posts.  It might be important to you, but as far as the site is concerned, it doesn't matter if your question is answered today or 2 years from now.  You have gotten upvotes and hopefully users with expertise in the topics that you have posted will answer.

You can share the post over Twitter, Facebook, and whatever other mechanism to try and get more eyes on or even add a bounty to your question to make it featured.

Comment: [It does happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573550/atmel-arduino-isrtimer0-ovf-vect-wont-compile-first-defined-in-vector/48779546#48779546), and there is even [a badge for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68258#68258) (*Necromancer*). Google juice is an advantage.