# Forgotten Gems - Review Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

After reading through the comments of [Am I asking the wrong way? Is there something wrong with my posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373499/am-i-asking-the-wrong-way-is-there-something-wrong-with-my-posts?noredirect=1&lq=1) I found this comment by [Patrick Roberts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts):

[image: comment].

and thought about it for a while. The likelyhood that someone develops a practiable heuristic that can reliably differenciate between high quality and trash might be almost zero.

Instead, I'd like to propose a new Review Queue that should be able to solve part of the problem of high quality content disappearing into oblivion:

1. Grab a bunch of random posts with no answers older than 100 days and display them to reviewers with above 3k rep
2. Give reviewers the capability of classifying them as quality content or trash
3. When 5 reviewers classified the question as quality content, add a 200 Rep bounty and bump it to the top
4. When 5 reviewers classified the question as trash, remove it from possible questions to end up in the queue until it is edited by the author (probably never)
5. ????
6. Profit

Comment: Other than your alleged thought process, I don't see why my comment is at all relevant to this proposal. This is nothing like my suggestion on that thread, and I certainly don't think that magic bounties is the right way to go about reviving old questions, that seems to have potential for systematic abuse for reputation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the relevance of your comment is that it points out the need of tackling disappearing quality content and that it is one of various possible approaches to do this. I get your point about the abuse but imho this can easily be solved by review bans and a sufficient minimum rep for the queue

Comment: _"Grab a bunch of random posts with no answers older than 100 days"_ I'm pretty skeptical that there's a substantial number of posts in this basket that will _ever_ get good answers. If you're serious about this proposal, you should use the Data Explorer to investigate.

Comment: The solution to tackling disappearing quality content is to allow less junk in.  Viola, better signal to noise ratio instantly.

Comment: This feature already existed, past tense, the [new-nav] feature was supposed to give such questions higher exposure.  Implemented in 2015 as a response to the universal quality complaints.  But it was a project failure, they could not get it reliable enough and walked away from it.  Promises were made to bring it back some day, we're still waiting.  But the likely way they'll make it work again.

Comment: Automagically making bounties that are 4 times what a normal bounty is feels like it's.... a good way to make sure 50 points bounties are pointless and never used again :/.

Comment: Free Bounty for few upvote on a ton of post.. Sock pupets like your idea.. It just have to wait for the Bounty queue to hit 10k+ avaidable Bounty and get all the rep. Even if 80% get caught we now have 20% of user with rep > 125.. Thats 75 free downvotes for each sock account. I trully love the idea, we will have downvote outscaling upvote by 1 or é order of magnetude.. Fun!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The whole idea of bounties is that they draw lots of attention to the bounties posts *because there isn't very many of them*.  Suddenly flooding the featured tab with what I expect would amount to *thousands* of questions a day is going to result in them just languishing in the featured tab, and essentially making it pointless for anyone to ever put up a bounty with their own rep, as it will get little to no added attention.  You're going to need to have some pretty radical steps to limit the number of questions per day getting a bounty via this method to avoid these problems.

Next, the incentives are honestly backwards here.  Reviewers are incentivized to put bounties on real easy questions with readily accessible answers because *they'll know the answer to such questions* and can post an answer in an attempt to get a bounty.  They're far *less* likely to want to put a bounty on a question that's very complex and not easily solved with researched because *they're way less likely to be able to answer such a question*.

Comment: Regarding your first point, wouldn't it help to just limit the amount of questions allocated an active bounty by this feature to a reasonable amount, like 30 and just replenish it from the "high quality index" once a bounty was rewarded?

Comment: @TomM Then either 99.99% of the reviews in the queue will be accomplishing nothing, or the queue won't have any items for reviewers to review 99.99% of the time.  30 reviews a week is going to get chewed through in like 20 minutes, leaving the entire rest of the week with no more bounties left to offer.

Comment: No, the reviews themselves can be done until there are no more unreviewed questions. What should be limited/delayed is the amount of active bounties applied by the system. If the questions provided with a bounty are selected randomly from the stack of accepted high quality questions, the enticement to vote on easy questions should cease to apply since you have no way to vote and immediately answer these questions.

Comment: @TomM Then that means that 99.99% of the reviews are pointless, as they'll never result in a bounty being put on the post, even if it's marked as a "good question", because *thousands* a day will be marked as good, and only 30 a week will actually get a bounty.

Comment: Unless the bounties are awarded before the 7 day countdown expires. Anyways, this will at least accelarate the process of minimizing unanswered questions to some degree.

Comment: @TomM But there is no one person putting the bounty on the post who will be able to award it.  It will be a system provided bounty, so there's no way for it to be awarded early.  And it wouldn't limit unanswered questions at all.  It's simply moving attention from certain questions to others, so even *if it manages to succeed at doing its job* then it just means a few higher quality questions see answers instead of lower quality questions.  And of course if people mark mediocre or poor questions of deserving of the bounty (which I strongly expect they would) it won't even do that much.