# How are users expected to triage 262+ items in a queue with 21 total flags?

Tags: discussion

Pretty much just the title. How is it possible to wade through a queue of a multiple hundreds of Triage records with less than two dozen flags to apply to those records?

Does this not seem to be completely counterproductive to anyone else here?

Maybe this is too rhetorical. But I am also genuinely interested. The site asks for help from the users, as literal red flags pop up in the menu asking for assistance, but also limits them so they are incapable of providing the necessary help.

Comment: the key here is the second `s` in `users`.

Comment: I'm not following. What exactly gives you the impression that we want you to look at *every single one*? That's just how many are available, and we'd like you to help with what tools you have available. We actively *don't want* a single user reviewing the entire queue.

Comment: If the answer is that SO wants to limit users then put that as an answer and I will mark as accepted. Again, to me it seems counterproductive to limit people who are willing to help, but if that's the site policy, so be it.

Comment: You are concerned about the Triage queue? You have not yet seen the [Close vote queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) ...

Comment: @rene we all know you love that queue really...

Comment: @rene At 3k are you still limited to 20 flags? If so, I'm not surprised at all that the queue is unmanageable.

Comment: You get 40 if the queue size is above 1000 items and we have had an experiment with 60 votes per day. That didn't help either.

Comment: It is not about what a single voter can do. We just need enough voters. They are there, they just don't use their votes. That's why some users with moderation privileges hangout in a chatroom, to not get too much demotivated.

Comment: @rene it's almost as if trying to force the vast majority of the people who *don't* want to help to contribute and *limiting* the very small number of people who do, results in a lot of work not getting done. Because this thread right here could be the definition of demotivating.

Comment: I understand it might feel that way but that doesn't scale enough. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need to flag this as a duplicate if it's already been duplicated. Great example right there of how much time seems to be wasted by people who want to help with moderation.

Comment: @rene I find it ironic that in the thread you linked, there's a post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319392/7948962 created by the original person who made the suggestion. This is far more telling than any of the other information in that thread or what has been posted here. "After I run out I see no point in slogging through the muck looking for the occasional gem if I can't help clean up the muck. I really believe in StackOverflow as a resource and I'm not here for the rep. The vote limits are contribution limits." Again if this is the intent, as seems by the implication, then so be it.

Answer (score 9):

You're not the only person triaging questions.  Given that you aren't *expected* to triage every single question yourself, it's not a problem that you aren't *able* to triage them all yourself.  You can't even triage any *one* question yourself (you just cast one of several votes needed to handle the post), let alone every single one of them.