# Why did questions stop getting edited after closing in 2013?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

When a question is [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) but not [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5045/370758), the OP is able to edit the question (for potential re-opening later).

At one point, close to half of closed questions were edited.

What happened at the beginning of **2013** to change that?

I assume this is something that we want to encourage, or are we better off to just delete and re-post?

[image: Chart: monthly comparison of % of questions edited after close]
<sup>(Source data: grouped [**monthly**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882170/what-of-closed-questions-are-later-edited-monthly) and [**yearly**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882086/what-of-closed-questions-are-later-edited))</sup>

For reference, this chart compares number of questions asked, number of questions closed, monthly:

[image: Chart: monthly comparison of counts of questions asked vs closed]

Comment: I see you haven't considered bulk edits, like the http->https edit by Community. You could try and adjust your query to only edits by existing users, however, this might disadvantage old questions since old user accounts are more likely to be deleted.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The community user has a user ID, so it (presumably) shouldn't be too hard to filter those out without excluding accounts that no longer exist.

Comment: Rather a lot was going on back then, it was the start of the SO's Eternal September.  The steep incline in closed questions was probably a side-effect of the first [welcoming] campaign (aka "summer of love").  The editing drop is harder to explain, beyond the sheer number of questions requiring editing, *maybe* the review queue limit imposed in Oct 2012 played a role.

Comment: I've excluded posts where the last editor was community in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882183/what-of-closed-questions-are-later-edited-monthly), which leads to pretty different results. However, this query really needs to be adjusted to use PostsWithDeleted (since bad unedited posts likely have a larger chance to get deleted over time skewing the results), account for time passed since closure (more time = more chance for edits), and count posts that have been edited by another user and by community. There's little to say based on these numbers.

Comment: A percentage drop combined with a sharp rise in closed posts is more likely due to the rise in closed posts. The same *number* of posts are still being edited, we just closed more posts. It could be that how posts are closed changed around that time, for example. And the feedback from Erik is also significant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But we also had more questions being asked and so more users to ask the questions. I would think that with that increase, the % of posts being edited would remain the same...

Comment: I present [a rabbit hole](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251489/4639281). Have fun, and make sure to follow all the links. :)

Comment: I'm kind of curious about the jump in closed/edited around 2010.

Comment: What graphing utility did you use?

Comment: @TylerH: looking again the rise preceded the percentage drop; the percentage drop itself saw stable (perhaps a little lower) question close rates.

Comment: Thanks @ErikvonAsmuth, that sheds a lot of llght

Answer (score 83):

Before 2013, each time a question was closed as a duplicate, the Community user edited the question to insert a "possible duplicate" link at the top like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718751/revisions). Those edits were made right after the question was closed, so every question closed as a duplicate before 2013 would show up as edited after being closed in your query. After 2013 though, the duplicate link is inserted automatically in a banner above the question and not in the question itself, so duplicates were no longer automatically edited after being closed.

[This version of your query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882183/what-of-closed-questions-are-later-edited-monthly) filters out edits by the Community user (thanks to [Erik von Asmuth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth) for editing the query). If you use that query instead, you get the following graph:

[image]

On this graph, there isn't that drop in the percentage of questions that were edited after closure, which seems to prove that the drop on your graph is due to the Community user editing fewer questions. The drop in your graph occurred at approximately the same time as the Community user stopped editing duplicate links into duplicate questions, so that's probably the reason.

Comment: You deserve a "Sherlock Holmes" badge!

Comment: I wonder why it started out so high? I can think of a few reasons -- the smaller, tighter-knit community actually being able to encourage people to fix things, for example -- but I'm curious as to what the actual cause is.

Comment: Sherlock Holmes nah. You deserve an Ace Attorney badge! Way more epic.

Comment: [1/2]As noted in my initial comment, that query has many shortcomings. I've written up a different query that only analyzes the first year of history of a post to limit time-based effects, includes posts that have been edited by a user but the last edit was community, and includes posts that have been deleted after that year. This makes the query a bit unreliable for the last two years (those numbers are still subject to change if people edit), but produces very, very different results.

Comment: [2/2] Your explanation with duplicates may still explain the initial drop, since those posts might've gotten edited to include/remove duplicate links. The query: [Edits after closure, within 1 year, posts not deleted in that year](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/883416/)