# Why was this community nominated for a "Webby" award, and why am I compelled to care?

Tags: discussion

I honestly feel like the title says everything here...

1. What is this "Webby" award?
2. Why am I compelled to care through a banner on the site?

---

Right, so...my usual laconic style of question asking doesn't *quite* seem to be getting the answers I want, so I'll try a slightly different approach.

To be frank - I've never heard of this Webby site in the years that I've participated on the Internet, and as such, I've never considered that it had any material bearing on Stack Overflow as a community.  It's not a site that I would find myself on by accident or happenstance; there's no circumstance where the Venn diagram of my usage or participation on Stack Overflow has any overlap with what Webby is.

I'm suddenly being compelled to care about this overlap, though, through the use of a banner.  While I could just dismiss the banner, I strongly, strongly question why it's in the banner at all.  [Nothing about this kind of engagement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/08/q2-community-roadmap/) is even called out on the roadmap, so I'm incredibly put off about it being brought to my attention in this fashion.

The question I'm asking is, *why*?  Why is this appearing in my community if I can't demonstrate that it has any bearing on my community?

Comment: ad 1) a ) The Webby Awards is the leading international award honoring excellence on the Internet.  b) The Internet's highest honor.ad 2) ignore it like evry body else, they only want to **grab subscribes**

Comment: @nbk so, it's like the Oscars? I'm ignoring those, too, so perhaps I'll also ignore this. On the other hand, I didn't even know about Webby until now (well, I think I had heard of it but that's it), so...perhaps, I'll just elect to change nothing.

Comment: its more like the old european song contest  where everybody is allowed to vote and promote his community/ Land,  or maybe like rotten tomatoes, Oscar is mor, somelese makes a choice and you must see it or not

Comment: I question the fairness of asking every stackoverflow user to vote for stackoverflow? Presumably smaller websites would not be able to compete?

Comment: You missed the bold, blue "vote here" part? That's clearly what you are supposed to do. Makes sense that you missed it, though, as it's not very high contrast against the black background. I have no idea what "Webby" awards are, either.

Comment: Nominated for "Websites - General Websites - Community". Going against Crafted, Twitch (the _new_ Twitch), Girlsclub Asia, and Canteen Connect. I don't even know how people are supposed to compare them. Do you vote for who you like best? Or do you vote for who does "community" the best? And do I want to know how Stack Overflow got nominated? I'm guessing it wasn't because some official looked at Stack Overflow and said, "You know what? Stack Overflow treats their community right."

Comment: Wait. *New* twitch? What did I miss?

Comment: You have to register and pay to be enter the contest. There are 2 kind of entry the normal one and the ad-campaign entry. Now the number are fun: ~120 categories = ~120 winners. there are 600 "nominees"+ 1100 "honorees" for 10,000 entries. It's cheaper than a lot of pay to win contest.

Comment: Doesn't this question just further the attention to the ad?

Comment: @TravisJ:  That's kind of the point.  As is the wont of the banner itself, it's entirely up to people who actually *want* to click through it and vote to do so; I'm not encouraging it, I'm just questioning why it's in my face at all.

Comment: Definitely not because money.

Comment: Saw your edit.  The "why" isn't that hard to figure out.  My foot doctor gave me the hard-court press to give her a vote for our local community's "Best Of."  Why?  Because it brings her more business.  I wouldn't have given it a second thought, except that she managed to fix my feet which were really bad, and I genuinely like her as a person.  She works hard for her clients and is miles better than our previous foot doctor.  So I gave her the vote.  But you can't give someone a vote unless you know about the vote.

Comment: It is a huge time-waster: signing up (by email), required for voting, doesn't actually work. Nothing is received for the confirmation email (required for the vote to count). It seems to be low quality overall - there is even a typo in the JavaScript code for *"My Account"* → *"Resend Confirmation Email"*: `javascripy:void(0);`. One wonder if they are only interested in harvesting emails for later use in spamming. Why didn't Stack Exchange check this first before they recommended it in the banner????

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If I were in the market for a foot doctor who could come across as reputable, or someone could vouch for their experience in a specific kind of foot care, or some were expert surgeons, then *that* would be a reasonable cause-and-effect to have your doctor ask you to provide references.  Stack Overflow as a platform isn't in any market; it *is* the market.  There's no question that every time I've Googled a technical question that this site's come up. In light of that, it makes the "why" perspective you're offering quite questionable.

Comment: I doubt that Stack Exchange is confused about why they did it.

Comment: Webby vote page is broken in google chrome

Comment: The only reason this isn’t closed as a rant is because most people here are still annoyed with the company.

Comment: The other reason, @BSMP, is that we kinda allow rants on Meta, as long as they're rants about Stack Overflow.

Comment: related: [Can we reserve the top bar announcements for actual site news?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338766/165773) at MSE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Jon has already kindly explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397072/4548692), the [Webbies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webby_Award) are an award given out to websites, much like [Grammys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammy_Award) are for Music and [Clios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clio_Awards) for advertising. In this case, *two* awards are given out, one from industry professionals and one that's more like the [People's Choice Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Choice_Awards), voted on by anyone willing to give them an email address. Though I can't personally say that I'm aware of them to the same degree as I am of the [Oscars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Awards), they seem to be a pretty big deal for the internet. So, for a site to be nominated, it can be a big deal to the site.

I think, rather than *why you should care*, what you're trying to understand is how this impacts you as a user - and that's a fair question to ask. We use these banners infrequently so there's a heightened sense of urgency and attention any time we do use them - so I can imagine that tickles your mind to think "this must be a big deal that I need to know about and act on"... and, well, it's not. This is something that's exciting in the same way it's exciting for a musician to be nominated for a Grammy and it's something you want to share with the people who are interested in you. The fact that the users here can participate in voting for the public awards means that you can influence the outcome, too.

Being nominated in the Community category is recognition for what y'all have done with the platform - making it a place people can come to get excellent answers to questions about coding - this is a service that programmers and enthusiasts around the world take advantage of frequently, if not daily. We are and have always been proud of that work. Yes, the last couple of years have been rocky to say the least - there's a lot of issues with how the platform sets expectations for new users and trains them to participate effectively. This has caused some friction between people who are frustrated at work and trying to get an answer to their problem and people trying to help them get that answer by writing one or pointing them to a similar one. I think there have been a lot of changes recently that are improving that experience and we're continuing to do work to reduce that friction as much as we can.

There's also a signal that being nominated (and winning) the Community category could send to people looking for an internal Q&A platform like Teams - if our community is recognized for being great, that's something that might encourage them to give Teams a try for their internal community, too, and having more people using (and paying for) the platform gives us more to work with to improve it.

We chose to add the banner for a short period of time for all of the reasons I've outlined above - it was put up late on Wednesday and taken down on Friday. This is a tool we don't use often and, as I noted earlier, that means it can be interpreted as rather urgent, particularly considering that we should remember that SO is a place where people come while they're at work and we should be careful about distracting them unnecessarily. We were excited about the votes we got from having this banner up and visible to millions of users even in the short period of time it was up. We also need to make sure that we're thinking holistically about whether something's best served in a banner, blog post, meta announcement, or on one of our social media accounts so that it gets to our community in a contextual way that doesn't impact their workflow.

Answer (score 30):

I'd raise another concern that might be worth more than posting in a comment. Is it ethical to unleash spam from the entire population of Stack Overflow (one of the largest if not the largest tech communities) on such a public vote? Would it not be a steamroller overwhelming any kind of useful signal from the vote?

This is of course assuming that the vast traffic that Stack Overflow sees each day will be directed toward votes for Stack Overflow. Some users might not do so, but the average user being happy to use their vote somewhere will most certainly comply when a big friendly banner instructs them to go vote. I find this sketchy at best.

Comment: Ethical considerations never prevented any corporation from advertising in any way they see fit, short of outright fraud or misrepresentation.  The real question is why Webby matters at all, or why corporations generally seem to think their customers are idiots.

Comment: I don't get how encouraging participation in popularity contest is "unethical" behavior toward that popularity content...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov or in any way *not* the intention of the contest, for that matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Webby matters because everything matters that can be used to justify a price tag on the company. Nobody wants to buy the controversial company with a toxic community. But look, even independent awards say we <3 people who code! So community! All the values!

Comment: Well, who else is supposed to vote for Stack Overflow other than people who use Stack Overflow? I would be more concerned if people voted for sites they have never used, now that would be wrong. (FYI I am not signing up to vote for anything)

Comment: @musefan Why is that wrong?

Comment: @Scratte: Because if you have never used a site, then how can you qualify to judge the quality and experience of that site's community?

Comment: @musefan You're arguing that I should vote based on the merits of the site, not whether or not I [lost my keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397). What if the sun is not shining today?

Comment: @Scratte: The sun shines everyday, you will know if it ever stops.

Answer (score 30):

> Why is this appearing in my community if I can't demonstrate that it has any bearing on my community?

Because SO's marketing has solidified control of the UX on SO, and they're determined to demonstrate their power by promoting an anachronism, even if it results in banner blindness and hurts future efforts to alert folks to information which is actually relevant.

...But, that's obvious, right?

I recommend not engaging with it at all - not even to dismiss. Use an ad blocker if it's in your way.

Or, as The Simpsons put it years ago...
[image: Just Don't Look]

Comment: Hey! I was here with the Simpsons reference first. (On this question, [if not this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue).)

Comment: Well, this is the very special brand of snarky yet penetrating insight I've been missing all these months!

Comment: Yes, but where is your huge, obnoxious, irrelevant image @Jon? Where?? This is an ads thread, get with the theme!

Comment: @Shog9: I guess I was [so preoccupied with whether or not I should, I didn't stop to think if I could](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nazm3_OXac).

Comment: _marketing has solidified control of the UX_ ...hmmm this brings an interesting angle to the old story about [removal of hot meta posts from SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387555/839601)

Answer (score 24):

From a marketing point of view, recent "troubles" in the community could be offset by an award, especially one awarded by "votes from a community". A nomination and banner can make sure this happens.

It's effective as a smokescreen, and it's effective as a counter-argument to anybody who argues about community being neglected and glossed over. It's also effective to show that "something's been done" if community votes us up and we win by a landslide. The last point allows to pat oneself on the back and rest on laurels, if one is so inclined.

From a marketing point of view, these are all excellent reasons to compel you to care, vote and spread the word. I wouldn't be surprised if there would be a badge for it.

Comment: Only a fool would think the award represents quality of the community, it only reflects quantity of site users. Unfortunately there are more fools on the internet than not. And just because I have to explain what every comment I type means on SO: I am not calling you a fool.

Answer (score 18):

> 1. What is this "Webby" award?

Never heard...

> 2. Why am I compelled to care through a banner on the site?

### Because nobody nukes community the way Stack Overflow does...

I am not sure that deserves an upvote, though... luckily for SO, there aren't any downvotes there...

Comment: You rival [TechLead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODaq-JEiIKg&lc=UgyNuHu1LzJ3u2BRsVh4AaABAg) in sarcasm (that is a compliment, if in doubt)

Comment: [voting for a competing site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397079/839601) could probably work the same as downvote over there

Comment: @gnat I was thinking about that, but you cannot vote without logging in...

Answer (score 17):

As it happens, I've seen Webby awards, the physical object, at one of my previous jobs. When I was a subcontractor with Jet Propulsion Laboratory (JPL), the conference room on my floor had several on display. The designers of many JPL websites were also subcontractors whose cubicles were near my own. The lab has won or been nominated for [many Webbys](https://www.webbyawards.com/winners/?search=true&keyword=Jet+Propulsion+Laboratory&pagenumber=1&filter=winners&sort=date) over the years. In terms of how valuable they are, I'd compare them to [Grammys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoFJkNhr8XQ). There are tons of categories, so there are lots of sites that get honored.

I'm personally [easily annoyed by notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109667/i-get-it-theres-a-new-blog-post). I think using them too much [destroys their value](https://jlericson.com/2019/04/24/crack_overflow.html). (I'm also a huge hypocrite. The site I manage currently has [4 obnoxious notifications](https://talk.collegeconfidential.com/parent-cafe/2185198-please-test-the-forum-index-page.htm). In my defense, it's also impossible to find anything via browsing, so the notifications are somewhat helpful for our users to know what's going on in this time of crisis.) Unfortunately, Stack Overflow has certainly relied on the topbar banner a little too much. I didn't even notice what was being advertised until I saw this post.

Part of me is outraged that Stack Overflow is organizing targeted voting to win an award. It kinda feels opposed to a value I have as a user of the site for voting to be reflective of the usefulness of the content rather than some group's organization skills. "What about the **integrity of the award**?!" this part of my brain is thinking. Then I looked at what the category looks like:

[image: Websites - General Websites - Community]

Other than Twitch (for which I have slightly negative feelings) I don't know anything about the competition. And really, who could? The best community is, by default, whatever community I happen to be a part of. It's pure tribalism. As a professional community manager, I sometimes look with envy at other communities that seem to have everything together. But that's because I'm not involved with them. I can't see their hidden secrets, but only the image they display to the world.

So I don't know. Maybe turning this into a "which community is biggest" contest is not the worst thing. Marketing's job is to make the community look its best and if that means telling users to vote for Stack Overflow rather than, say [Girlsclub Asia](https://girlsclub.asia/), that's not something to get outraged about. It's not like they aren't doing exactly the same thing:

[image: Girlsclub Asia is nominated for a Webby Award! Help our community win by voting for us here.]

Comment: I think you'd only be a hypocrite here if you were somehow defending your own site's use of obnoxious banners... This is more like "a cautionary tale"

Comment: There's nothing to suggest you can't vote for Girlsclub Asia just because you clicked on the banner from here ;)

Comment: @Scratte: True. But I don't want to [give the Webbys my email](https://twitter.com/jlericson/status/1255587460337164288).

Comment: @JonEricson Just use temp mail. I just did that and it worked. (And unfortunately SO has 83%).

Comment: First impression: One of those five websites looks like a leftover from the nineties. Oh wait a minute ...

Answer (score 7):

I think it was very brave of the company to invite us to vote in this contest. Thing is, this looks we are given an opportunity to provide not only positive, but also *negative* feedback.

I mean, folks who feel unhappy about this banner and invitation can choose to vote for a competing site instead of Stack Overflow.

Hard to tell if this was intended to work this way but I for one am going to give it a serious thought, learn more about competitors (as probably any serious voter is expected to do anyway) and decide which site to vote for.

Comment: I wouldn't waste your time. You can't expect a user-voted award to be anything other than a popularity contest. People like you will be the very few and your vote will not matter. The vast majority of people will vote for the site they use regardless of how good the competition may be. If fact, I think SO might be at a disadvantage given the fact all the users are programmers and we generally are too logical to waste our time signing up to such awards. This question is proof enough that we would rather argue about the ethics of the banner on meta than to just click on it and vote.

Comment: @musefan In no uncertain terms, the .015% of the Stack Overflow community that is on Meta does not speak on behalf of the entire community.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Yeah, and the other 99.985% just want "teh codez" so aren't going to be interested in voting for anything

Comment: @musefan have you seen how some mod elections go? Teh codez seekers are more than happy to "contribute" whenever they are prompted to do so, with or without reading up on anything first (as usual).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well that's because you get a badge for it :) Also, no need to sign up if you're already a user. I am not saying a few won't vote on that Webby thingy, I am just saying the results mean squat.